# Manipulate requires two evaluations after revision

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, gui-construction, scheduling

This `Manipulate` program below allows the user to enter points on a `LocatorPane` and then draws a line through the points.

[image]

The `Manipulate` has an `Initialization`, where the programmer can define initial values for the points. The initial values are the variable `ipts` in the code below. What I observe is that the first time I evaluate the cell, the Manipulate works as expected.  But, if I change the initial points and then evaluate the cell, the Manipulate shows the previous values.  After evaluating the cells with the Manipulate definition a second time, the plots shows the revised values.

This thread seems to discuss the same issue,[How to eliminate the need to double evaluate a manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/685/how-to-eliminate-the-need-to-double-evaluate-a-manipulate-so-that-a-module-in-it) , but applying those answers to this question isn't clear to me.

Suspect that I am misunderstanding some fundamental concept about how initialization works. Could someone point out how to revise the code and/or a discussion of what is going on here?

```
myTest2 = Manipulate[
   (*User points*)
   posSorted = Sort[pos];
    xMin = Min[posSorted[[All, 1]] ];
   xMax = Max[posSorted[[All, 1]] ];
   gvfuncUser = Interpolation[posSorted, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
    myPlot = Plot[gvfuncUser[x], {x, xMin, xMax}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400];
   Grid[{
     {LocatorPane[Dynamic@pos, myPlot, LocatorAutoCreate -> True, 
       ContinuousAction -> False] }
     }]
   ,
   (*list of controls*)
   {{pos, ipts}, ControlType -> None}
   (*Initialization*)
   , TrackedSymbols :> {pos, ipts}
   , Initialization :> (
     ipts = {{0.15, 0.35}, {0.25, 0.15}, {0.50, 0.17}, {0.75,0.18}, {1, 1}};
     posSorted = {}; (*do this so that posSorted is local to this Manipulate (?) *)
     gvfuncUser = {};
     )
   , SynchronousUpdating -> False
   ];
  myTest2
```

In summary, to reproduce the question

1. Evaluate the cells
2. Change the values of ipts, for example, change the first point to {0.15, 0.05}
3. Evaluate the cells, (the displayed points will not change to the revised values)
4. valuate the cells, (the displayed points will change to the revised values)

Comment: As I remember, the initialization works at creation of the dynamic object. If you run the `Manipulate[..]` again but keeping the dynamic content alive, the initialization will not be evaluated.
The reset of the data can be done by trivial addition of the `ipts={...}` before the `Manipulate` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Manipulate[body, spec, opts]`

While body of `Manipulate` waits for `Initialization`, it is not the case with variables spec part, at least not in the same way. The problem in judgement here is that Manipulate is a big black box and not every aspect is documented.

But here is my guess: The first time you run it it passes symbolic `ipts` as an initial value for `pos` and somwhere during creation it gets values set in `Initialization`.

The second time you run it, with different values, it is no longer the case because `ipts` already have previous values so they are used. So from now one the initial value will be the one from previous setting.

Unless you put `ips = {...}` inside the body for example.

Another quick fix is to abandon `ipts`:

```
Manipulate[
  ...
  {pos, ControlType -> None}
  ...
, Initialization :> (pos = {{0.1, 0.35}, ...} )
, ...
]
```

Comment: ok.  dropping ipts will be fine.