# Struct equivalent in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, data-structures, coding-style, data-types, design-patterns

I really miss having something like a [`struct`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29) in Mathematica. I know of (and regularly use) a couple of programming techniques which feel like a `struct` (e.g., using [downvalues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html)), but are ultimately unsatisfactory (perhaps I'm using downvalues incorrectly). What programming approaches are available which provide similar functionality to a `struct`?

Here's an abbreviated (and hopefully not too obtuse) example of how I use downvalues to emulate a struct. In this case, I'm distinguishing between TLC and TEC (these are sets of parameters for two different phases of a Moon mission, trans-lunar cruise and trans-earth cruise):

```
deadBandWidth[X][TLC] ^= 10. °;
deadBandWidth[Y][TLC] ^= 10. °;
deadBandWidth[Z][TLC] ^= 20. °;
sunSearchAngle[Z][TLC] ^= 230. °;
sunSearchRate[Z][TLC] ^= 1. °/Second;
sunSearchAngle[X][TLC] ^= 75. °;
sunSearchRate[X][TLC] ^= 1. °/Second;
safingSpinRate[TLC] ^= (360. °)/Day;
sunVector[TLC] ^= {-Cos[45. °], 0., Sin[45. °]};
safingSpinAxis[TLC] ^= sunVector[TLC];

deadBandWidth[X][TEC] ^= 20. °;
deadBandWidth[Y][TEC] ^= 20. °;
deadBandWidth[Z][TEC] ^= 20. °;
sunSearchAngle[Z][TEC] ^= 230. °;
sunSearchRate[Z][TEC] ^= 1. °/Second;
sunSearchAngle[X][TEC] ^= 75. °;
sunSearchRate[X][TEC] ^= 1. °/Second;
safingSpinRate[TEC] ^= (360. °)/Hour;
sunVector[TEC] ^= {0., 0., +1.};
safingSpinAxis[TEC] ^= sunVector[TEC];

?TLC
Global`TLC
safingSpinAxis[TLC]^={-0.707107,0.,0.707107}
safingSpinRate[TLC]^=6.28319/Day
sunVector[TLC]^={-0.707107,0.,0.707107}
deadBandWidth[X][TLC]^=0.174533
deadBandWidth[Y][TLC]^=0.174533
deadBandWidth[Z][TLC]^=0.349066
sunSearchAngle[X][TLC]^=1.309
sunSearchAngle[Z][TLC]^=4.01426
sunSearchRate[X][TLC]^=0.0174533/Second
sunSearchRate[Z][TLC]^=0.0174533/Second
```

Comment: I could search around for what a `struct` is, but it'd be nice if you can link to a description of it... :)

Comment: Good suggestion. Is it acceptable to provide a link?

Comment: An example of how you currently emulate `struct` would also be nice.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with this "struct"?  Instead of pointing to a C feature, please explain what kind of things you want to *do* with this object.  I know C, but I'm still not sure what feature of `struct`s you are looking for in Mathematica.  Also note that Mathematica shines when using immutable structures while I have the impression that you are looking for something mutable here.

Comment: Your example contains many **UpValues**, not DownValues.  Also, it could you explain *why* you are using these assignments, why do you think they're advantageous?  Again, the question is: what is the advantage of `struct`s for you for this application?  Then we can think about how to reproduce this advantage in Mathematica.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Most of the work I do involves constructing mathematical models and then testing various scenarios against those models. I'd like to be able to populate a particular scenario and then pass that scenario to a model. I'd also like to be able to copy that scenario, modify one or more parameters, and then pass the new scenario to the model. I definitely need something mutable.

Comment: Also consider datatype[field1, field2, ...]. More MMA style, easier to manipulate, you can check for data type as _datatype, etc. You can always define a couple of constants if you want to access the fields like instance[[field1]]. Anyway, tere are many approaches, each with its advantages and disadvantages I guess

Comment: LOL, sorry about that upvalues/downvalues error. That'll teach me to ask questions prior to consuming some caffeine.

Comment: @Cassini So you just need something like a structured parameter list? That does not need to be a mutable variable.  How about a list of rules, like `tlc = {deadBandWidth -> {10,10,20}, sunSearchAngle -> 230}`?  If you just need to *pass data around*, then it is best not do make any definitions at all.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I may be able to structure my work (no pun intended) to avoid mutable variables, in which case your rule list suggestion seems elegant (and embarrassing that it didn't occur to me).

Comment: @Cassini I updated my answer with a way to easily change single parameter values (from the whole list).  Is this why you needed mutability?  Admittedly, the disadvantage of my method is that we need to take time to implement all the helper functions, taking away attention from the main task (your model).  Mathematica is a big and complex system, and often even old timers won't see the easy way (that seems to obvious after we learn about it :)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Wow, that really helps! I'm perfectly okay with the little helper functions.

Comment: Perhaps the following is worth noting: "Expressions are represented internally using struct and union in the C programming language." From the linked article at [this wolfram library archive page](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4683/), called Mathematica Internals by David Withoff.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

**Update:**  Mathematica 10 has introduced [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html), which can be used as a close equivalent of `struct`s.

```
params = <| "par1" -> 1, "par2" -> 2 |>

params["par1"]
(* ==> 1 *)
```

In version 10 pure functions can have named arguments, and can be effectively used as expression templates where the slots can be populated from an association.  This is similar to the technique I describe in the original version of this post (below the line).

```
#par1 + #par2 & [params]
```

will evaluate to `1 + 2` then to `3`.

That said, my personal workflow still fits better with the approach described below the line (`withRules`).  The reason for this is that I tend to build up calculations interactively and *incrementally*.  This means that I do not start by writing the equivalent of an expression template (which would require thinking ahead...).  Instead I start with all the values explicitly written out, and later I replace them with a global variable.  This global variable can be simply `Unset`, and given a local value using `withRules`, then eventually changed into a function argument.

---

Quoting the OP's comment:

> Most of the work I do involves constructing mathematical models and
>   then testing various scenarios against those models. I'd like to be
>   able to populate a particular scenario and then pass that scenario to
>   a model. I'd also like to be able to copy that scenario, modify one or
>   more parameters, and then pass the new scenario to the model.

The requirement, as I understand, is to be able to pass many parameter values around in a structured way.  Lists of rules are convenient for this:

```
params = {par1 -> 1, par2 -> 2, par3 -> {x,y,z}}
```

They can be extracted like this:

```
par1 /. params

(* ==> 1 *)
```

[Once I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8617773/695132) a function for substituting such parameter lists into bigger pieces of code:

```
ClearAll[withRules]
SetAttributes[withRules, HoldAll]
withRules[rules_, expr_] :=
  First@PreemptProtect@Internal`InheritedBlock[
    {Rule, RuleDelayed},
    SetAttributes[{Rule, RuleDelayed}, HoldFirst];
    Hold[expr] /. rules
]
```

It can be used like this:

```
withRules[params,
  par1 + par2
]

(* ==> 3 *)
```

`withRules` can contain complex code inside, and all occurrences of `par1`, `par2`, etc. will be substituted with the values from the parameter list.

We can also write a function for easily modifying only a single parameter (from the whole list), and returning a new parameter list.  Here's a simple implementation:

```
setParam[paramList_, newRules_] :=
 DeleteDuplicates[Join[newRules, paramList], 
  First[#1] === First[#2] &]
```

Example usage:

```
setParam[params, {par2 -> 10}]

(* ==> {par2 -> 10, par1 -> 1, par3 -> {x, y, z}} *)
```

Another list which has a different value for `par2` is returned.

---

If needed, this could be extended to support more complex, structured lists such as `{ par1 -> 1, group1 -> {par2x -> 10, par2y -> 20}}`, much [how like the built-in option-handling works](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetOptions.html).

---

**Addendum by celtschk:**  It's possible to extract a value from a list of rules using `OptionValue` as well: `OptionValue[params, par1]`.

Comment: I think as soon as you start thinking about modifying a single element (`setParam`), your approach looses expressiveness, because within it this operation is not natural. If you go further down that road (I was actually doing this too, for a while), you end up with another emulation of mutable structures, and not the best one, because you are copying stuff (e.g. you have copy - internally - and traverse the entire parameter list to modify a single element - so your assignemnt is strictly speaking not constant time).

Comment: @Leonid, well, but these lists tend to be rather small, so performance is not an issue.  At least not for the things I was using them for.  This does not become slow if we have a large parameter value, only if  we have a large number of parameters.  It's like `Append`.

Comment: @Leonid I actually use something similar in practice, so if you have a better (more convenient) solution for this particular problem (not for emulating structs, but actually for this problem), I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Sure, I understand that (although, once you start using that in huge quantities, this will become an issue even for a not very large number of parameters). I just think it is conceptually inelegant to use immutable structures to emulate mutability, for cases which don't warrant that. Which these cases are is debatable. For example, for configuring options, I take essentially the same approach with my option configurator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192599/create-functions-to-flexibly-define-chart-options-lists-in-mathematica/7197903#7197903,  - emulate the mutable state ...

Comment: ...with immutable expressions, and in that case I think it is well-justified. To summarize - I think, if the nature of your problem demands *lots* of mutable state (e.g. you write something like a virtual file system), I don't think emulating it with immutable constructs is appropriate. I'd rather isolate that module to make sure that all mutations happen in a well-defined place. But for just a few mutable variables, I think that's ok and may even be good. I certainly consider it good for options.

Comment: As to this particular problem (I find the title of the question misleading), I'd also use rules, but rather than modifying the parameters as you suggest, I'd just use the option / rule application mechanism which would automatically override older values when newer ones (rules) are inserted first - it is both simpler and faster. Basically, I'd use a mechanism described in the post on option configuration manager I linked to, perhaps with a variant of your `WithRules` function to apply them (I actually did similar stuff a few times in the past).

Comment: In other words, IMO, your `setParam` is unnecessary altogether. If I were to use this way, and have say rules `{par1-> val1, par2 ->val2}`, and would now want to redefine `par1` to `val11`, I'd just prepend this rule to the list, getting `{par1-> val11,par1 -> val1, par2 ->val2}`. If you use rules, why not use their native mechanisms? You could also use `Dispatch` if you make too many redefinitions (which is unlikely).

Comment: @Leonid Yes, strictly, it's unnecessary, but it's cleaner to get rid of the mess.  The quick and dirty solution I used to use looks like `params = {par1 -> 1, par2 -> 2}; Table[
 withRules[Join[{par2 -> x}, params],
  par1 + par2
  ],
 {x, 0, 5}
 ]` (or similar)  As the OP says, it is indeed useful sometimes to be able to modify just a small part of those param lists.

Comment: I don't think it should be called "quick and dirty". I think this is the best solution here. It has an added advantage that you can just add new rules modifying your parameters in a batch, and rule-application mechanism will take care of the rest. You can, if you wish, factor this into a separate function. But what I'd do within this approach, instead, is to define *configurations*. The key to expressiveness is composition. Here is what I'd do: `config[newrules__]@config[rules__] := config[newrules, rules];`. It's really that simple, and we can assign these to variables and get ...

Comment: ...composition. Now, add another def to your `WithRules`: `withRules[config[rules___], expr_] := withRules[{rules}, expr]`. And here is a typical code: `old = config[par1 -> val1, par2 -> val2];
new  = config[par1 -> val3, par2 -> val4]; 
total = new@old`. You can now use this with `WithRules`, and you get composition, because you can combine the configurations in any order you wish. It is also expressive: you can write `WithRules[Evaluate[new@old], expr]`, and it is pretty clear what is done. There may be many patches in the chain. Think what'd be needed to replicate this with `setParam`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the full essence of the part of  the method you describe that I agree with (perhaps, apart from `withRules`, which I also like), plus my suggestion, was described concisely by @Sakra in the very first link from my answer.

Comment: Just one observation (which doesn't seem to have been made above): With the definition of `params` as list of rules you also can extract (but not set) a specific value using `OptionValue[params, par1]`.

Comment: @celtschk Very good point, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: This answer is basically what I also do, when working with models in different situations. However, I am often facing one problem: Some values may depend on other values (for example `lambda->512, k->2 Pi/lambda`). As they may not ALWAYS depend on those values, I cannot integrate them into the model. Until now I just cascade lists of rules, but that is not very convenient. Any ideas?

Comment: @mcandril: I've just now seen your comment. In case it's still relevant for you: I think simply using `//.` instead of `/.` would solve that issue. For example, `{a,b} /. { a->1, b->x+a }` gives `{1, a + x}`, but `{a,b} //. { a->1, b->x+a }` gives `{1, 1 + x}`.

Answer (score 55):

This answer may be unacceptable right from the outset because it uses undocumented functions. However, it has advantages over some of the approaches suggested so far which might be redeeming enough in certain scenarios to recommend it in practice. In particular, it provides totally encapsulated state (unlike, e.g., `DownValues` or `Temporary` symbols) and O(1) access and updates (unlike, e.g., a list of rules).

I would suggest a `` System`Utilities`HashTable `` object, which exists in at least *Mathematica* 7 and 8 (but not in 5.2, and I didn't check 6). This is manipulated using a relatively small number of simple functions:

- `` System`Utilities`HashTable[] ``: creates a new hash table.
- `` System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[ht, key, val] ``: adds a key-value pair {*key*, *val*} to the hash table *ht*.
- `` System`Utilities`HashTableGet[ht, key] ``: given a hash table *ht* and a key *key*, retrieves the value corresponding to *key*.
- `` System`Utilities`HashTableRemove[ht, key] ``: given a hash table *ht* and a key *key*, removes *key* from *ht*.
- `` System`Utilities`HashTableContainsQ[ht, key] ``: given a hash table *ht* and a key *key* which may or may not exist in *ht*, determines whether or not *key* does in fact exist in *ht*. (This is useful since adding a key that already exists or querying/removing a nonexistent key produces an ugly message.)

I trust that this is all quite self-explanatory, but the following is a brief usage example for reference:

```
h = System`Utilities`HashTable[]
 (* -> System`Utilities`HashTable[<0>] *)

(* Setting properties for an "account" *)
System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[h, accountID, 47];
System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[h, balance, 1632.40];

(* Querying a property *)
accid = System`Utilities`HashTableGet[h, accountID]
 (* -> 47 *)

(* Updating a property *)
bal = System`Utilities`HashTableGet[h, balance];
System`Utilities`HashTableRemove[h, balance];
System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[h, balance, bal + 506.31];

System`Utilities`HashTableGet[h, balance]
 (* -> 2138.71 *)
```

If you aren't completely put off by the fact that all of this is undocumented, the `` System`Utilities`HashTable `` looks it could offer a passable alternative to a `struct` for many applications.

Comment: It's not the CDF format or plugin that forbids the use of these functions, it is just the check of the demonstrations site. You could very well use these functions (unsupported as they probably are...) in a CDF document, it it will be running in the CDF Player as well as the Player Pro.

Comment: Nice answer! Hash tables are not quite structs, but this is a valuable piece of information. And great that you joined. +1.

Comment: Is it possible to update a value without removing it first?

Comment: @Ajasja no, I don't think so. Why not, I'm not sure (probably internal implementation detail).

Comment: How did you find this feature?

Comment: @Max: I think I used ``Information["*`*Hash*"]``, but can't quite remember. Searching for functions with likely-looking names quite often turns up something interesting.

Comment: The functions still exist in Mathematica 9

Comment: @Ajasja This is possible with the [new HashTable data structure](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/datastructure/HashTable.html).

Answer (score 37):

There were several attempts to emulate structs in Mathematica. Emphasis on *emulate*, since AFAIK there is no built - in support for it yet. One reason for that may be that structs are inherently mutable, while idiomatic Mathematica gravitates towards immutability. You may  find these discussions interesting:

[Struct-data-type-in-mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453006/struct-data-type-in-mathematica)

[Object-oriented-mathematica-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363253/object-oriented-mathematica-programming)

[Question-on-setting-up-a-struct-in-mathematica-safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356691/question-on-setting-up-a-struct-in-mathematica-safely)

[Mathematica-oo-system-or-alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446297/mathematica-oo-system-or-alternatives)

My own take on it is in this answer:

[Tree-data-structure-in-mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097071/tree-data-structure-in-mathematica/6097444#6097444)

where I describe one possible emulation of structs, which I use every now and then when I need something like a struct (this is, of course, a personal preference. There are many ways to do this). It looks to be somewhat similar to your method. For a recent use case where I put similar approach to heavy use and where it *really pays off* (because structs are not the bottleneck there), see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36/file-backed-lists-variables-for-handling-large-data/209#209), where I use this as an encapsulation mechanism for file-backed lists.

That said, a built-in support for mutable structures would be, I think, very desirable. Three major reasons I could think of, why various emulation approaches did not really take off:

- Performance. Structs are the work-horse of data structures, and their performance is critical. OTOH, all emulations which are to be general, are bound to use the top-level code, and that is slow.
- Garbage collection. The available ways to create encapsulated mutable state almost always involve creating definitions for symbols, and those definitions are frequently not automatically amenable to garbage collection
- (The lack of) standardization. If there were a single emulation which would accumulate a significant code base, tools and practices of using it, that may have been different.

Comment: I've read about mutable and immutable several times on your posts and I get it only half of the way. I didn't study computer science, but googling tells me that mutable is when it can be changed after its creation, which Part can do it seems. On the other hand, you can change a downvalue without changing the others if you consider the pack of that symbols' definitoins as your structure. Also, wouldn't something like a tree built with node[left, data, right] with HoldAll be mutable?

Comment: I guess it's all about knowing when MMA does an internal copy of the expressions, which I don't know, nor know how to check... This reminds me that I've been confused with this issue also in the context of reading that Bags were so special because they could emulate a pointer, and a few things about linked lists (these I understand a little bit more than half of the way)

Comment: @Rojo What I mean is that if I have, say in C, a struct like `typedef struct{ int x, int y} mystruct;`, then, if `s` is of this type,  I can say `s.x = 10`. If I have an expression like `node[left, data, right]`, and it is stored in some variable (say `expr`), then I also *can* say `expr[[1]] = 10`, but I can not nest this deeper. For example, if `left` is also a `node`, I can not say `left = expr[[1]]; left[[1]] = 10` and expect this change to also affect the original `left` node inside `expr` - it only affects a copy. Basically, it boils down to the fact that we lack here pointer semantics.

Comment: My guess is that Part on the lhs is the only way to change only part of an expression without making a copy. Also, that MMA only makes a copy of the data whe it has no other choice in its built-in functions that modify an expression. But how to know if, e.g, h=ReplacePart[h, 2->8] does a full copy or if its smart enough? (h being unpacked array)

Comment: @Rojo my point is that even `Part` is not enough, because elements of an expression are expressions, not pointers. When you extract them, their copy is made. When you assign these parts to variables and modify those, that assigned copy is modified, not the original part within a larger expression. As for `ReplacePart`, it sure does make a copy, as most other functions returning expressions.

Comment: The careful handling of mutability, structure-sharing, and software transactional memory in Clojure might be the most sophisticated available in the world today (http://goo.gl/dG3g3). If I were to go whole-hog in Mathematica with a data-structure library, I would learn from Clojure.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin I am going to do that, in fact. Clojure stands high on my to do list. Thanks for the suggestion, anyway!

Comment: @Leonid -- I have done some at-scale, production-level systems in Clojure and highly recommend it :)

Comment: @Reb.Cabin All right, then I know whom to bombard with stupid questions when I finally get my hands on it :)

Comment: Thanks for collecting these pieces. [But I specifically need the structure to be mutable.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/195064/1155) That's the whole point. Then what?

Answer (score 33):

**Edit:** The ideas below have led to a package called MTools. Instructions on how to install and use it are here: [MTools tutorial](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/880686).

### Using symbols to store data and object-like functions

Here are interesting functions to use symbols like objects. (I originally posted these thoughts in [What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6245166/884752)).

The post has grown quite big over time as I used it to record ideas.

It's divided into three parts, one describing the function Keys, another one where properties and functions are stored in a symbol created inside a Module, thus mimicking objects in object oriented programming and a last one where objects have the form ObjectHead[object].

**Introduction**

It is already well known that you can [store data in symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) and quickly access them using DownValues.

```
(*Write/Update*)
mysymbol["property"]=2;
(*Access*)
mysymbol["property"]
(*Delete*)
Unset[mysymbol["property"]]
```

It is similar to a hashtable, new rules are added for each property to DownValues[mysymbol]. But internally, from what I understood, rules of a symbol are stored as a hashtable so that Mathematica can quickly find which one to use. The key ("property" in the example) doesn't need to be a string, it can be any expression (which can be used to cache expressions, as also shown in the post quoted above).

**Keys**

You can access the list of keys (or properties) of a symbol using these functions based on what dreeves once [submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154704/884752) (I was quite lucky to have found his post early in my Mathematica learning curve, because it allowed me to work on functions working with lots of different arguments, as you can pass the symbol containing the stored properties to a function and see which keys this symbol contains using Keys):

```
SetAttributes[RemoveHead, {HoldAll}];
RemoveHead[h_[args___]] := {args};
NKeys[_[symbol_Symbol]]:=NKeys[symbol]; (*for the head[object] case*)
NKeys[symbol_] := RemoveHead @@@ DownValues[symbol(*,Sort->False*)][[All,1]];
Keys[symbol_] := Replace[NKeys[symbol], {x_} :> x, {1}];
```

Usage example of Keys

```
a["b"]=2;
a["d"]=3;
Keys[a]

(*getting the values associated with the keys of the a symbol*)
a /@ Keys[a]
```

If you use multiple keys for indexing a value

```
b["b",1]=2;
b["d",2]=3;
Keys[b]

(*getting the values associated with the keys of the b symbol*)
b @@@ Keys[b]
```

**PrintSymbol**

I use this function a lot to display all infos contained in the DownValues of a symbol (which uses one key per value):

```
PrintSymbol[symbol_] :=
  Module[{symbolKeys=Keys[symbol]},
    TableForm@Transpose[{symbolKeys, symbol /@ symbolKeys}]
  ];

PrintSymbol[a]
```

**Replacing a part of a list stored in a symbol**

The following would produce an error

```
mysymbol["x"]={1,2};
mysymbol["x"][[1]]=2
```

One way to do this would be either to introduce a temporary variable for the list stored in mysymbol["x"], modify it and put it back in mysymbol["x"] or, if possible, use a syntax like

```
mysymbol["x"] = ReplacePart[mysymbol["x"], 1 -> 2]
```

Interestingly some answers to this post [How to Set parts of indexed lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7214/66) deal with this issue in a O(1) way (compared to the O(n) complexity of ReplacePart where a new list is created to modify it afterwards).

**Creation of objects with integrated functions**

Finally here is a simple way to create a symbol that behaves like an object in object oriented programming, different function syntaxes are shown :

```
Options[NewObject]={y->2};
NewObject[OptionsPattern[]]:=
  Module[{newObject,aPrivate = 0,privateFunction},
    (*Stored in DownValues[newObject]*)
    newObject["y"]=OptionValue[y];
    newObject["list"] = {3, 2, 1};

    (*Private function*)
    privateFunction[x_]:=newObject["y"]+x;

    (*Stored in UpValues[newObject]*)
    function[newObject,x_] ^:= privateFunction[x];
    newObject /: newObject.function2[x_] := 2 newObject["y"]+x;

    (* "Redefining the LessEqual operator" *)
    LessEqual[newObject,object2_]^:=newObject["y"]<=object2["y"];

    (* "Redefining the Part operator" *)
    Part[newObject, part__] ^:= newObject["list"][[part]];

    (*Syntax stored in DownValues[newObject], could cause problems by 
      being considered as a property with Keys*)
    newObject@function3[x_] := 3 newObject["y"]+x;

    (*function accessing a "private" variable*)
    functionPrivate[newObject] ^:= aPrivate++;

    (* "Redefining the [ ] operator" *)
    newObject[x_] := x newObject["list"];

    (*Format*)
    Format[newObject,StandardForm]:="newObject with value y = "~~ToString[newObject["y"]];

    newObject
  ];
```

Properties are stored as DownValues and methods as delayed Upvalues (except for the [ ] redefinition also stored as DownValues) in the symbol created by Module that is returned. I found the syntax for function2 that is the usual OO-syntax for functions in [Tree data structure in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097071/tree-data-structure-in-mathematica/6097444#6097444).

**Private variable**

The variables aPrivate can be seen as a private variable as it is only seen by the functions of each newObject (you wouldn't see it using Keys). Such a function could be used to frequently update a list and avoid the issue of the previous paragraph (Replacing a part of a list stored in a symbol).

If you wanted to DumpSave newObject you could know which aPrivate$xxx variable to also save by using the depends function of Leonid Shifrin described in the post [Automatically generating a dependency graph of an arbitrary Mathematica function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4343/66).

```
depends[NewObject[]]
```

Note that xxx  is equal to $ModuleNumber - 1 when this expression is evaluted inside Module so this information could be stored in newObject for later use.

Similarly the function privateFunction can be seen as an internal function that cannot be called explicitely by the user.

**Other way for storing functions in a different symbol**

You could also store the function definition not in newObject but in a type symbol, so if NewObject returned type[newObject] instead of newObject you could define function and function2 like this 
outside of NewObject (and not inside) and have the same usage as before. See the second part of the post below for more on this.

```
(*Stored in UpValues[type]*)
function[type[object_], x_] ^:= object["y"] + x;
type /: type[object_].function2[x_] := 2 object["y"]+x;

(*Stored in SubValues[type]*)
type[object_]@function3[x_] := 3 object["y"]+x;
```

**Usage example**

```
x = NewObject[y -> 3]
x // FullForm

x["y"]=4
x@"y"

function[x, 4]
x.function2[5]
x@function3[6]

(*LessEqual redefinition test with Sort*)
z = NewObject[]
{x["y"],z["y"]}
l = Sort[{x,z}, LessEqual]
{l[[1]]["y"],l[[2]]["y"]}

(*Part redefinition test*)
x[[3]]

(*function accessing a "private" variable*)
functionPrivate[x]

(*[ ] redefinition test*)
x[4]
```

**Reference/Extension**

For a list of existing types of values each symbol has, see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html and http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_4.html.

You can go further if you want to emulate object inheritance by using a package called InheritRules available here
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/671/

### Further ideas when storing functions in a head symbol

This second part of the post uses some ideas exposed previously but is independent, we redevelop equivalent ideas in a slightly different framework.

The idea is to use DownValues for storing properties in different symbols corresponding to objects and UpValues for storing methods in a unique head symbol (MyObject in the example below). We then use expressions of the form MyObject[object].

Here is a summary of what I currently use.

**Constructor**

```
Options[MyObject]={y->2};
MyObject[OptionsPattern[]]:=
   Module[{newObject,aPrivate = 0},
      newObject["y"]=OptionValue[y];
      newObject["list"] = {3, 2, 1};

      (*Private function*)
      privateFunction[newObject]^:=aPrivate++;

      MyObject[newObject]
   ];
```

MyObject is used as "constructor" and as head of the returned object (for example MyObject[newObject$23]). This can be useful
for writing functions that take into account the head of an object. For example

```
f[x_MyObject] := ...
```

Properties (like the value corresponding to the key "y") are stored as DownValues in a newObject symbol created by Module whereas functions will be stored in the MyObject symbol as UpValues.

**Private variable**

```
(*function accessing a "private" variable*)
functionPrivate[MyObject[newObject_]] ^:= privateFunction[newObject];
```

In order to have a function accessing a private variable of newObject, aPrivate, a function stored as UpValues of newObject, privateFunction, is defined at the creation of newObject, and another function stored as UpValues of MyObject, functionPrivate, calls privateFunction.

**Some methods stored as UpValues in MyObject (different syntaxes are shown)**

```
(*Stored in UpValues[MyObject]*)
function[MyObject[object_], x_] ^:= object["y"] + x;
MyObject/: MyObject[object_].function2[x_] := 2 object["y"]+x;

(*Another cool syntax*)
o_MyObject.function4[x_] ^:= o.function2[x];

(* "Redefining the LessEqual operator" *)
LessEqual[MyObject[object1_],MyObject[object2_]]^:=object1["y"]<=object2["y"];

(* "Redefining the Part operator" *)
Part[MyObject[object_], part__] ^:= object["list"][[part]];

myGet[MyObject[object_], key_] ^:= object[key];
mySet[MyObject[object_], key_, value_] ^:= (object[key]=value);  
(*or*) 
MyObject/: MyObject[object_].mySet[key_, value_] := (object[key]=value);
```

Note: the function4 syntax stores a rule in both MyObject and function4. The syntax is nonetheless convenient, and works well when several different classes have different function4 definitions.

**Methods stored as SubValues in MyObject**

A method stored to easily access the properties of an object. We restrict here key to be a string in order not to interfere with other functions defined as SubValues.

```
MyObject[object_Symbol][key_String] := object[key];
```

Another function stored in SubValues[MyObject]

```
MyObject[object_]@function3[x_] := 3 object["y"]+x;
```

Redefinition of the [ ] operator

```
MyObject[object_][x_] := x object["list"];
```

**"Static" variable**

Similarly to what is used for a private variable, a variable can be shared among all the objects of a similar class using a following definition for the function that accesses it.
(Such variables use the keyword static in C++-like languages)

```
Module[{staticVariable=0},
   staticFunction[MyObject[object_]]^:=(staticVariable+=object["y"]);
]
```

**Using methods from another class**

Let's say that Class1 and Class2 share a common method named function. If we have an object Class1[class1Object] and want to use the function version of Class2 we can do this using something like

```
Class2[class1Object].function[]
```

**Format**

You can format the way the object is displayed with something like this:

```
Format[MyObject[object_Symbol],StandardForm]:="MyObject with value y = "~~ToString[object["y"]];
```

**Creating an object**

```
x = MyObject[y->3]
```

**Test of the different functions**

```
x // FullForm

function[x, 2]
x.function2[3]
x.function4[3]
x@function3[4]

x["y"]
x@"y"

(*LessEqual redefinition test with Sort*)
z = MyObject[]
{x["y"],z["y"]}
l = Sort[{x,z}, LessEqual]
{l[[1]]["y"],l[[2]]["y"]}

(*Part redefinition test*)
x[[3]]

(*function accessing a "private" variable*)
functionPrivate[x]

(*[ ] redefinition test*)
x[4]

(*static function example*)
staticFunction[x]
staticFunction[z]
```

**Update properties**

*Using ObjectSet*

To update the "y" property of z you can use this (or use a setter function like mySet defined above)

```
ObjectSet[(_[symbol_Symbol]|symbol_),key_,value_]:=symbol[key]=value;
ObjectSet[z,"y",3]
```

If an object is of the kind MyObject[object] then value will be assigned to object[key] (DownValues of object) instead of being assigned to MyObject[object][key] (SubValues of MyObject whereas I want functions to be in general stored as UpValues of MyObject and properties as DownValues of object).

*Using object in MyObject[object] directly*

Another way that doesn't involve another function is to do

```
z[[1]]["y"] = 4
```

*Using mySet (defined above)*

```
z.mySet["y",5]
```

*Using Set*

You can automate ObjectSet by overloading Set in a dynamic environment for example. See this post for more details [Alternative to overloading Set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/alternative-to-overloading-set)

```
ClearAll[withCustomSet];
SetAttributes[withCustomSet, HoldAll];
withCustomSet[code_] :=
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{Set},
        Unprotect[Set];
        Set[symbol_[key_],value_]:=
           Block[{$inObjectSet=True},
          ObjectSet[symbol,key,value]
    ]/;!TrueQ[$inObjectSet];
        Protect[Set];

        code
    ];
```

So that you can do

```
withCustomSet[
   z["y"] = 6
]
function[z, 2]
```

This syntax works also for sub-objects

```
withCustomSet[
   z["u"]=MyObject[];
   z["u"]["i"]=2
]

PrintSymbol[z["u"]]
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you migrate the info from your toolbag answer here, as the toolbag question has been closed and its not likely to be re-opened. So, eventually the info will be deleted.

Comment: @Faysal Please, for the sake of salvation of all souls who will be lost after reading this part, *don't overload Set*!

Comment: @Leonid I've warned people that it can be dangerous. I don't have any side effect using this though. Someone who wants to avoid any pitfall if they choose to use the ideas I shared can use other possibilities for setting values of such objects. It's a matter of free will ...

Comment: @Faysal The problem is, at least in my view, that we, as advanced users, have increased responsibility towards less experienced ones, and community as a whole. The technique you described is dangerous, and not only to those who decide to use it. As soon as more user-contributed code (by us say) becomes widely used, this may become a real problem. People may start using this stuff in packages, and this may lead to all sorts of problems. Also, what I first saw was the code, and I saw your warning only upon the second read. Adding rules to `Set` is a very appealing idea, but IMO it is just wrong.

Comment: @Faysal One way to make this more bearable is through local *environments*, the approach I am pushing forward in many of my answers. You could create dynamic environments (say, with ``Iternal`InheritedBlock `` localizing `Set`), or, better yet, lexical environments. There are many problems with overloading `Set` via `DownValues`, but the major one IMO is that it is a *non-local*, system- wide change for something *very* frequently used. Environments help localize changes, and are a great tool for that.

Comment: @Leonid, OK I understand your concern. I'll ask a question so that you or someone else can further develop the ideas of your last comment.

Comment: Faysal you are a compulsive editor! :-)

Answer (score 24):

The answers already posted show that built-in *Mathematica* functionality can be used to get the meaningful functionality provided by a C struct.  If you want your code to be readable by other *Mathematica* users, I suggest using a list of rules as already advised above.

However, if you **really want** struct-style syntax I'll offer an implementation that I've found useful.

Features of a struct that are slightly different than a list of rules:

1. Limited ordered data set.  All instances of a particular struct type contain exactly the set of fields specified in the struct type declaration.  It is impossible to add fields that aren't part of the struct declaration, or to be missing fields that are.
2. Minimal storage.  Each instance of a struct contains only the struct type name and the field values.  It does not contain the list of field names - those names are stored only once and associated with the struct type name.

### Example usage

Declare a structure type named "toad" that contains three fields.  Two fields must match a pattern, the third is unrestrictied.  The declaration is associated with the symbol "toad".

```
In[]:= DeclareStruct[toad, {{legLength, _Real}, {legColor, _RGBColor}, otherData}]
```

Define one instance of the "toad" struct with initial values for each field, given as a list of rules.

```
In[]:= myReptile = DefineStruct[toad,
  {otherData -> "Ted the frog", legLength -> 4.5, legColor -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0]}]
Out[]= Struct[toad,
  {legLength -> 4.5, legColor -> RGBColor[0, 1, 0], otherData -> "Ted the frog"}]
```

The actual storage for one instance of the struct does not include the field names.  The per-instance storage includes only the field values and the struct name.  The relationship between field names and field positions is associated with the struct name, not embedded in each instance of the struct.

```
In[]:= FullForm[myReptile]
Out[]= Struct[toad, List[4.5`, RGBColor[0, 1, 0], "Ted the frog"]]
```

To get values from the struct, use the `LongRightArrow` operator -- an operator which has no built-in meaning in Mathematica.  `LongRightArrow` can be entered with <kbd>Esc</kbd>`-->`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

```
In[]:= myReptile-->legColor
Out[]= RGBColor[0, 1, 0]
```

Field values can also be set with the `LongRightArrow` operator.  Set is overloaded with an UpValue for `LongRightArrow`.

```
In[]:= myReptile-->legColor = RGBColor[0.5, 1, 0]
Out[]= RGBColor[0.5, 1, 0]
```

The implementation won't allow you to get or set a field that was not declared as a member of the struct, or set a field value to something that does not match the declared pattern.

```
In[]:= myReptile-->headSize = 6.0;
LongRightArrow::member: Field headSize is not a member of struct toad >>
```

### Notes

- Implementation handles nested structs.
- Implementation does not handle assignment to parts of a field with `mystruct->field[[n]]=val`, though this could be added.  Currently you must get the existing field value, modify part of it with `ReplacePart`, and assign the new value into the field.
- Implementation avoids making local copies of objects by always modifying top-level symbols by part.
- Cost to get a part is similar to a simple list of rules.  Costs one rule replace to find the index, then some O(1) extra work for error checking and the part access by index.

### Implementation

```
ClearAll[Struct]
Struct::usage = 
  "Struct objects contain a limited set of elements with minimal \
   storage overhead.  Struct types are declared with DeclareStruct and \
   struct objects are created with DefineStruct.";
Format[Struct[sy_, dt_]] := 
  "Struct"[ToString[sy], 
    If[ListQ[sy[Names]] && Length[sy[Names]] === Length[dt], 
      MapThread[Rule, {sy[Names], dt}], dt]]

ClearAll[DeclareStruct]
DeclareStruct::usage = 
  "DeclareStruct[structname, {fieldname..}] declares a structure \
   datatype named structname with the given field names.  Each field \
   name is a symbol or a list {symbol, pattern}";
DeclareStruct::error = 
  "DeclareStruct internal error.  Failed to handle argument error.";
DeclareStruct::argb = 
  "DeclareStruct called with argument count of `1`; 2 arguments are \
   expected.";
DeclareStruct::structname = "Struct name `1` must be a Symbol.";
DeclareStruct::fieldnames = 
  "Each field name in `1` must be a symbol or {symbol, pattern}.";
DeclareStruct[sy_Symbol, fld : {(_Symbol | {_Symbol, _}) ..}] := 
 Module[{fields = Replace[fld, a_Symbol :> {a, _}, {1}]},
  ClearAll[sy];
  sy[Names] = First /@ fields;
  sy[Pattern] = Last /@ fields;
  sy[Order] = MapIndexed[#1 -> First[#2] &, sy[Names]];]
DeclareStruct[] := Null /; Message[DeclareStruct::argb, 0]
DeclareStruct[sy_, ar___] := 
 Module[{ll}, 
  Null /; Which[ll = 1 + Length[{ar}]; ll =!= 2, 
    Message[DeclareStruct::argb, ll], Head[sy] =!= Symbol, 
    Message[DeclareStruct::structname, sy],
    !MatchQ[ar, {(_Symbol | {_Symbol, _}) ..}], 
    Message[DeclareStruct::fieldnames, ar],
    True, Message[DeclareStruct::error]]]

ClearAll[DefineStruct]
DefineStruct::usage = 
  "DefineStruct[structname, {fieldvaluerules}] returns an instance of \
   a structname struct, previously declared with DeclareStruct.";
DefineStruct::error = 
  "DefineStruct internal error.  Failed to handle argument error.";
DefineStruct::argb = 
  "DefineStruct called with argument count of `1`; 2 arguments are \
expected.";
DefineStruct::structname = "Struct name `1` must be a Symbol.";
DefineStruct::fieldrules = 
  "Field value rules `1` must be a list of rules giving values for \
   field symbols.";
DefineStruct::undef = 
  "Struct name `1` has not yet been declared with DeclareStruct.";
DefineStruct::setmatch = 
  "Set of field names `1` does not match the field names of declared \
   struct `2`";
DefineStruct::pattern = 
  "Value(s) in the field rules `1` don't match the pattern(s) `2` \
   provided to DeclareStruct for struct `3`";
DefineStruct[sy_Symbol, rl : {(_Symbol -> _) ..}] := 
 Module[{vl}, 
  Struct[sy, vl] /; 
   ListQ[sy[Names]] && (Sort[First /@ rl] === 
      Sort[sy[Names]]) && (vl = Replace[sy[Names], rl, {1}]; 
     MatchQ[vl, sy[Pattern]])]
DefineStruct[] := Null /; Message[DefineStruct::argb, 0]
DefineStruct[sy_, ar___] := 
 Module[{ll}, 
  Null /; Which[ll = 1 + Length[{ar}]; ll =!= 2, 
    Message[DefineStruct::argb, ll], Head[sy] =!= Symbol, 
    Message[DefineStruct::structname, sy],
    !MatchQ[ar, {(_Symbol -> _) ..}], 
    Message[DefineStruct::fieldrules, ar], ! ListQ[sy[Names]], 
    Message[DefineStruct::undef, sy], ll = First /@ ar; 
    Sort[ll] =!= Sort[sy[Names]], 
    Message[DefineStruct::setmatch, ll, sy], 
    ll = Replace[sy[Names], ar, {1}]; ! MatchQ[ll, sy[Pattern]], 
    ll = Transpose[
      Select[Transpose[{ll, sy[Pattern]}], ! 
         MatchQ[First[#1], Last[#1]] &]]; 
    Message[DefineStruct::pattern, First[ll], Last[ll], sy], True, 
    Message[DefineStruct::error]]]

ClearAll[LongRightArrow]
LongRightArrow::usage = 
  LongRightArrow::usage <> 
   "  struct\[RightArrow]field returns the value of field in struct.  \
    struct\[RightArrow]field=v sets the value of field in struct to v.";
LongRightArrow::member = "Field `1` is not a member of struct `2`";
LongRightArrow::pattern = 
  "Value `1` does not match pattern `2` for field `3` in struct `4`";
LongRightArrow[st_Struct, fl__Symbol] := 
 Module[{sy, ii, id = {}}, st[[Sequence @@ id]] /; (
    Scan[
     (sy = Part[st, Sequence @@ id, 1];
       ii = Replace[#1, sy[Order]];
       If[ii === #1, Message[LongRightArrow::member, #1, sy]; 
        Return[]];
       id = Join[id, {2, ii}]) &, {fl}];
    Length[id] === 2 Length[{fl}])]
LongRightArrow /: Set[LongRightArrow[st_Symbol, fl__Symbol], vl_] := 
 Module[{sy, ii, id = {}}, (
    Scan[
     (sy = Part[st, Sequence @@ id, 1];
       ii = Replace[#1, sy[Order]];
       If[ii === #1, Message[LongRightArrow::member, #1, sy]; 
        Return[]];
       id = Join[id, {2, ii}]) &, {fl}];
    Which[Length[id] =!= 2 Length[{fl}], vl,
     !MatchQ[vl, sy[Pattern][[ii]]], 
     Message[LongRightArrow::pattern, vl, sy[Pattern][[ii]], fl, sy]; 
     vl,
     True, With[{ij = Sequence @@ id}, st[[ij]] = vl]]) /;
   Head[st] === Struct]
```

Comment: Actually a struct in C or C++ also doesn't contain the type name, only the members. You cannot find out which type is stored there by just looking at the contents (except if you can guess the type from the contents). Only true class instances contain information about their type (in C++ via the virtual table pointer; C of course doesn't have them).

Comment: BTW, I like the use of LongRightArrow — that's an operator I wasn't previously aware of and which fits perfectly here (I wonder why Wolfram didn't use that for Java method calls instead of messing with the semantics — including associativity! — of `@`)

Comment: celtschk has a good point - that a C struct does not contain the type name.  The Mma Struct needs it to get the transformation rules from field name to field position during evaluation of struct-->field.  But this brings up what we could do with Compile.  With a promise that we would not change a Struct declaration after compiling an expression, Compile could do the name->position transformation immediately, so at evaluation of the compiled expression the field would be accessed directly by index.

Comment: Actually you could provide the struct name at access time. Then the struct type definition would be just a list of rules mapping member names to list indices. The struct instance would just be a list, and struct access would be like `toad[[legColor/.myReptile]]`.

Comment: Absolutely.  Your solution minimizes storage **and** is standard Mma (though I think you meant myReptile[[legColor/.toad]], relative to my example).  But the (gratuitous) goal of this exercise was to mimic C struct syntax, which doesn't provide the type at access time.

Comment: Ah yes, I mixed up struct definition and struct instance in your example, probably because I naturally assumed that the more general word (reptile) refers to the struct, while the more specific word (toad) refers to the instance (well, actually, a toad isn't a reptile, but let's ignore that).

Comment: True - my choice of example class/member/instance names was less-than-inspired.

Comment: The access mechanism we're both using here is `instance[[member/.classrules]]`.  Whether used explicitly or in a syntactic wrapper like my `Struct`, a core characteristic is that one classrules is shared by many instances.  So it makes sense to spend storage or cycles to optimize the application of classrules.  I applied Mma's `Dispatch` to the classrules in my `Struct` implementation, and it gave the expected benefit on an example constructed to maximize that signal.

Comment: `Part` having higher precedence restricts members to contains List. If I declare `{legLength, _List}` and try to access them as `myReptile-->legLength[[1]]` Part catches first

Answer (score 21):

I arrived very late to this party and I'm very much afraid that nobody comes here anymore. Still I'm posting this in hope that an occasional visitor may find it a practical approach to implementing data structures with named fields within *Mathematica*.

#### The concept

The idea is to use protected symbols to name a structure and its fields. The symbol that names the structure is also made orderless, so the fields are automatically maintained in canonical order. Protection is required to prevent both classes of symbols from being bound to a value; they must remain value-free for the approach described here to work.

Here is a semi-formal definition of a structure. Note that the fields are implemented as a sequence of rules. `Replace` will be used to both get and set the values of fields.

---

```
 structure ::= structName[field.1, ..., field.n]
 structName ::= "protected, orderless symbol"
 field.k ::= fieldName.k -> value.k
 fieldName.k ::= "protected symbol"
```

---

In my own work, I follow the convention that field names take the form `structName$name`. I find adhering to it makes programs more readable and easier to debug, but rejecting it will in no way jeopardize the general concept.

As with any implementation of data structures, this approach has both costs and benefits. The benefits are mostly realized during application development and maintenance; the costs are mostly incurred at run-time and paid in the coin of execution time and memory usage. For many applications I think the benefits gained outweigh the costs incurred.

#### Declaring structures

Setting the necessary attributes manually for each new structure type can get tedious very quickly. `declare` makes this job easier.

```
 declare[structName_Symbol, fieldNames : (_Symbol) ..] :=
    (SetAttributes[structName, {Orderless, Protected}];
     Protect[fieldNames];)
```

#### Examples of structures

```
 declare[data, data$x, data$y, data$z];
 declare[person, person$firstName, person$lastName];
 d = data[data$x -> 1, data$y -> 2, data$z -> 3];
 p = person[person$firstName -> "Brian", person$lastName -> "Smith"];
```

Since both data ans person are orderless, writing the fields in a different order does no harm.

```
 u = data[data$y -> 2, data$x -> 1, data$z -> 3];
 v = person[person$lastName -> "Smith", person$firstName -> "Brian"];
 {d == u, p == v}  (* ==> {True, True} *)
```

#### Functions for accessing and modifying fields

Access

`get` returns the value associated with the field named in the 2nd argument of the structure passed in as the 1st argument.

```
get[struct_, fieldName_Symbol] := fieldName /. List @@ struct
```

Quite often a subset or even all of the values in a structure are wanted. It shouldn't be necessary to write multiple get expressions to do this. `get` can be extended to accept a list of field names or the token `All` and return a list of the requested values.

```
get[struct_, fieldNames : {_Symbol ..}] := fieldNames /. List @@ struct

get[struct_, All] := With[{rules = List @@ struct},
                        ((First@#)& /@ rules) /. rules]
```

Modification

*Mathematica* essentially refuses to mutate objects, so `set` provides the illusion of modifying the field specified by its 2nd argument to have the value passed in as its 3rd argument. It's an illusion because the structure `set` returns is newly minted and not the structure passed in as its 1st argument.

```
set[struct_, fieldName_Symbol, val_] :=
   struct /. (fieldName -> _) -> fieldName -> val
```

`assign` works like `set` except the 1st argument passed to `assign` must be a symbol bound to a structure. `set` returns the value passed in as its 3rd argument. `assign` is provided to make it unnecessary to write code such as

```
d = set[d, data$x, 42]
```

because it makes the assignment within its code body.

```
 SetAttributes[assign, HoldFirst]
 assign[structName_Symbol, fieldName_Symbol, val_] :=
    (Unevaluated[structName] =
       structName /. (fieldName -> _) -> (fieldName -> val);
    val)
```

#### Factory functions

Although structure instances can be created by typing out the full expression for the instance, this can be tedious and error-prone, especially for structures that have many fields. In most cases it is better to provide one or more factory functions. My convention is to name all such function create and make them distinguishable to *Mathematica* by varying their argument patterns. Factory functions for different structure types are distinguishable because a structure name token is invariably passed as the 1st argument.

Factory functions can also be useful for modifying structures. When several fields in a structure instance require modification, successive applications of set or assign will create multiple copies of the instance, all of which are garbage. A factory function used for the same purpose will create just one garbage instance. But don't be too quick to reject set and assign. You must write each and every factory function you use; set and assign are universal and are always available.

Here is a completely trivial example of a factory function:

```
 create[person, first_String, last_String] :=
    person[person$firstName -> first, person$lastName -> last]
```

Here is one that is not so trivial:

```
 With[{pattern = Repeated[_String, {2}]},
    create[data, xName : pattern, yName : pattern, zName : pattern] :=
       data[data$x -> create[person, xName ],
            data$y -> create[person, yName ],
            data$z -> create[person, zName ]]]
```

#### Application

Anyone who has read this far would probably like to see a non-trivial example of structures with named fields. I think a Mathematica implementation of the famous X Window program `xeyes` will do.

According to the X Window System `man` page, `xeyes` was initially written by Jeremy Huxtable and shown at SIGGRAPH in 1988. It was ported to X11 by Keith Packard. It has been immensely popular ever since.

*Irises and pupils*

The iris and pupil of an eye will combined into a single structure called iris.

---

```
 iris[iris$center->center, iris$color->color, iris$radius->radius]
 center ::= {x, y}
 x ::= Real
 y ::= Real
 color ::= RGBColor[red, green, blue]
 radius ::= Real "radius of the iris"
```

---

```
declare[iris, iris$center, iris$color, iris$radius]
```

`shape` creates a graphics descriptor that can be supplied to a `Graphics` expressions to draw an iris. The pupil is drawn at half the diameter of the iris.

```
 shape[iris, i_iris] :=
    Module[{color, center, r},
       {center, color, r} = get[i, All];
       {{color, Disk[center, r]}, Disk[center, 0.5 r]}]
```

The iris factory function is intended to be called from within the eye factory function. An iris is created with a radius 0.3 of the radius of its containing eye and is initially placed at the eye's center.

---

```
 eyeXY ::= {eyeX, eyeY} "eye's center"
 eyeX ::= Real
 eyeY ::= Real
 eyeR ::= Real "radius of the eye"
 color ::= RGBColor[red, green, blue]
 Returns :: iris[...] "newly minted iris"
```

---

```
create[iris, eyeXY : {_Real, _Real}, eyeR_Real, color_RGBColor] :=
   iris[iris$center -> XY, iris$radius -> 0.3 eyeR, iris$color -> color]
```

*Eyes*

---

```
 eye[eye$center->center, eye$inR->r, eye$iris->i, eye$outR->R]
 center ::= {x, y}
 x ::= Real
 y ::= Real
 r ::= Real "radius of the circle on which the iris tracks"
 i ::= iris[...]
 R ::= Real "radius of the eye"
```

---

```
declare[eye, eye$center, eye$inR, eye$iris, eye$outR]
```

`shape` creates a graphics descriptor that can be supplied to `Graphics` expressions to draw an eye.

```
 shape[eye, e_eye] :=
    Module[{center, i, R},
      {center, i, R} = get[e, {eye$center, eye$iris, eye$outR}];
      {{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], Disk[center, R]},
           shape[iris, i]}]
```

The eye factory function.

---

```
 center ::= {x, y}
 x ::= Real
 y ::= Real
 R ::= Real "radius of the eye"
 r :: = Real "radius of the circle on which the iris tracks"
 color ::= RGBColor[red, green, blue] "iris color"
 Returns :: eye[...] "newly minted eye"
```

---

```
create[eye, center : {_Real, _Real}, R_Real, r_Real, color_RGBColor] :=
   Module[{i = create[iris, center, R, color]},
      eye[eye$center -> center, eye$inR -> r, eye$iris -> i, eye$outR -> R]]
```

Function for moving an eye's iris along its tracking circle.

---

```
 e ::= eye[...]
 theta ::= radians "angle iris center is to make with eye center
                    after iris is placed on tracking circle"
 Returns :: eye[...] "copy of e with iris placed on tracking circle"
```

---

```
 placeIrisAt[e_eye, theta_Real] :=
    Module[{center, r, i},
       {center, r, i} = get[e, {eye$center, eye$inR, eye$iris}];
       assign[i, iris$center, center + r {Cos[theta], Sin[theta]}];
       set[e, eye$iris, i]]
```

Function that makes an eye appear to be looking at the specified point.

---

```
 e ::= eye[...]
 pt ::= {x, y}
 x ::= Real
 y ::= Real
 Returns :: eye[...] "copy of e in which the iris is placed at the
                      intersection of the tracking circle and the
                      line through the eye center and pt"
```

---

```
lookAt[e_eye, pt : {_, _}] :=
   placeIrisAt[e, ArcTan @@ (pt - get[e, eye$center ])]
```

*Mathematica Eyes*

Create a pair of eyes having a given spacing and with the pair center at `{x, y}`. Place the eyes in a square containing a red dot. Make the eyes follow the dot as it is dragged around the square by the mouse. The **Reset** button will return the dot to its initial position.

```
 With[{box = {{-4., 4.}, {-4., 4.}}, spacing = 0.3, x = 2., y = 3.,
       R = 0.75, r = 0.45, color = RGBColor[0., 0.5, 1.],
       dotHome = {-2., -2.}},
    DynamicModule[{lf, rt, dot, dotXY = dotHome},
       dot = Locator[Dynamic@dotXY,
               Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[dotXY]}]];
       lf = create[eye, {-(R + 0.5 spacing) + x, y}, R, r, color];
       rt = create[eye, {(R + 0.5 spacing) + x, y}, R, r, color];
       Dynamic@Refresh[lf = lookAt[lf, dotXY]; rt = lookAt[rt, dotXY];
          Column[{Framed@Graphics[{shape[eye, lf], shape[eye, rt], dot},
                            PlotRange -> box, ImageSize -> {400, 400}],
             Button["Reset", dotXY = dotHome, ImageSize -> 60]},
             Center],
          TrackedSymbols -> {dotXY}]]]
```

[image: xeyes implemented in Mathematica]

Comment: Interesting ideas, but what is the ::= notation ? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @FaysalAberkane. Look up Backus-Naur form on, say, Wikipedia.

Comment: Ok I looked at the code to quickly ::= is not meant to be executed, thanks.

Comment: @FaysalAberkane. No, that stuff is documentation. In my original _Mathematica_ notebook these cells are of a special, non-evaluatable type. Perhaps there is a better way to show them here. I'm new to this markdown stuff and couldn't figure out what was better.

Comment: @m_goldberg Regarding the "::=" notation which was confusion since it was in a Mathematica code-block, have you seen that you can use a different code-block language? Maybe marking it differently would have helped. [Have you seen this?](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/213/187)

Comment: @halirutan. Thanks for the comment and the links. I didn't know about language hints. I have added `<!-- language: none -->` to the BNF blocks. It differentiates them from the _Mathematica_ code and, I hope, reduces the confusion.

Answer (score 17):

So the naive way to set up a data structure like `struct` is, as the OP suggested, to simply used `DownValues` and/or `SubValues`. In the below, I use `SubValues`.

Copying the [Wikipedia C language `struct` example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29)

```
struct account {
   int account_number;
   char *first_name;
   char *last_name;
   float balance;
};

struct account s; // Create new account labelled s
s.account_number // access the account number
```

In Mathematica, we can talk about an "instance" of `account` as

```
account["s"]
```

set and access its properties using `SubValues`

```
account["s"]["account_number"] = 12345

account["s"]["account_number"]
(* Returns: 12345 *)
```

To make this a bit more robust, you should probably have a gentleman's agreement with your code to only access the "objects" using type checked instantiation and setting methods. Also, code for deletion of "objects" is easy to write by using `DeleteCases` on the `SubValues` of `account`. That said, I've written largish applications *for my own use* that do not bother with such niceties.

Comment: This comes up too often. If yo insist on using struct,  program in C. If you decide to use Mathematica, read relevant portions of the documentation and you will see how the language is intended to be used. Then you should use it as Wolfram intended. You are like a Chinese person trying to use a knife and fork the same way they would use chop sticks.