# Does Mathematica have advanced indexing?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, filtering

I have two $M \times K$ arrays $L, T$ where I would like to set all the elements in $L$ to zero whenever the corresponding element of $T$ is greater than 15.  The `Select[]` function is close but not quite what I need since it returns elements rather than indexes.
In addition, even presuming I can get that list of indexes $i,j$ where $T_{ij}>15$ I do not know how to efficiently use them to set the corresponding elements $L_{ij} \rightarrow 0$.

What facilities, if any, does Mathematica have for this kind of advanced indexing?  I come from the world of R, Matlab and Numpy where it is commonly used, as in

```
  L[T>15]=0
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Using a little Mathematica pattern matching, I think you can get similar performance as @Szabolcs's answer while having nice Matlab-style syntax:

```
replaceWhere[cond_, selectTrue_, selectFalse_] := 
   With[{evaluatedCondition = evaluateTensorCondition[cond]},
        selectTrue*evaluatedCondition + selectFalse*(1 - evaluatedCondition)]

replaceWhere[cond_, selectTrue_] := replaceWhere[cond, selectTrue, 0]

evaluateTensorCondition[a_ > b_] := UnitStep[a - b]    

evaluateTensorCondition[a_ < b_] := UnitStep[b - a]

evaluateTensorCondition[a_ && b_] := 
    evaluateTensorCondition[a]*evaluateTensorCondition[b]

evaluateTensorCondition[a_ || b_] := 
    UnitStep[evaluateTensorCondition[a]+evaluateTensorCondition[b]-1]
```

(implementing more comparison and logical operators should be straightforward)

Usage:

```
replaceWhere[T > 15, L, 0]
```

returns a new list, where every index that is greater than 15 in `T` is set to 0 , the other elements are the same as `L`. And it should have similar performance as @Szabolcs's answer, because all the conditions are just transformed into vectorizable tensor operations. (I haven't timed it, though.)

Note that this works for arbitrarily complex expressions, and the last two parameters can be tensors or scalars:

```
replaceWhere[(T > 5 && T < 15) || Sin[L]<Cos[T], L, L*2]
```

If you evaluate this expression symbolically:

```
Clear[T, L]
replaceWhere[(T > 5 && T < 15) || Sin[L] < Cos[T], L, 0]
```

you get one long tensor expression composed of `UnitStep`'s

```
Out = L UnitStep[-1 + UnitStep[15 - T] UnitStep[-5 + T] + UnitStep[Cos[T] - Sin[L]]]
```

So "under the hood" Mathematica will do the same operations as in @Szabolcs's answer. You just get a more readable syntax.

---

If you don't want to do all those fancy syntax manipulations, you can always use `MapThread` to combine higher dimensional arrays in any way you'd like. For your question, this would be:

```
MapThread[If[#1 > 15, 0, #2] &, {T, L}, 2]
```

This takes the 2d-Tensors (last argument `2`) `T` and `L` (second argument `{T, L}`), passes the corresponding elements in the two tensors to a function (first argument `If[#1 > 15, 0, #2] &`) and returns a new tensor containing the return value of that function. This is slower than @Szabolic's answer, but it is also a lot more flexible.

Comment: You seem to be doing it properly, so you could add the third numerical argument like `evaluateTensorCondition[cond]*(data - replaceWith) + replaceWith` for the special case when it's not zero

Comment: I think it would be valuable if you edited back the original `MapThread` approach you posted.  It was one of the reasons I voted for this post.  While a complex custom function is interesting, I think it is important to mention `MapThread` here as an important way to combine higher dimensional arrays.  Don't forget that the OP is new to Mathematica.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I thought the answer was getting too long... But I can add the `MapThread` version at the end, for completeness

Comment: Switched my acceptance to this answer, as it appears to be a very useful generalization.

Comment: @nikie: you are implicitly assuming that the elements of `evaluatedCondition` are either 0 or 1. This is not always the case (see the code for the `||` part). I guess the code should be modified slightly not to produce strange result in the case that the condition invokes an `Or` statement.

Comment: @Fabian: You're right, that's the implicit assumption. Each `evaluatedTensorCondition` returns `UnitStep` or a product of `evaluatedTensorCondition` tensors - I can't see how the result could contain anything but 0 and 1.

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote?

Comment: @nikie Don't be put off by it.  It not so uncommon when the question gets popular.  It might even be a mistake (mistap touchscreen device?)

Answer (score 63):

**Update:** [This is now available as the BoolEval package.](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/BoolEval)

---

I recommend using

```
L UnitStep[15 - T]
```

for good performance.

---

To answer your question about boolean indexing:

When you write `L[T > 15] = 0` in MATLAB, `T > 15` evaluates to a boolean matrix of 0s and 1s, which can be used as a special selector index in assignments, as you showed (I am writing this for those Mathematica users who don't know this feature of MATLAB).

This feature is not available directly in Mathematica.

However, it is important to know that Mathematica is usually most effective when using it a functional way, i.e. using operations that do not have side effects.  Code using heavy assignments is typically not the best/fastest way to approach a problem.

There is a function, `Pick`, which is similar (but not identical) to this MATLAB feature.  `Pick[a, b]` will return those elements of `a` for which the corresponding element of `b` is `True`.  `Pick[a, b, 1]` allows using `1` instead of `True`.  `a` and `b` can be arbitrary dimensional tensors or even ragged lists.

That said, there is no direct equivalent of `L[T > 15] = 0`.  However, anything that can be accomplished with this syntax in MATLAB should be doable using arithmetic operations between tensors (as in my example). This will buy you the performance advantage of vectorization, but it'll still be a bit slower than direct assignment.

---

**Update:**

This is a set of functions to help working in this paradigm:

```
greatereq[a_, b_] := UnitStep[a - b]
lesseq[a_, b_] := UnitStep[b - a]
greater[a_, b_] := 1 - lesseq[a, b]
less[a_, b_] := 1 - greatereq[a, b]
unequal[a_, b_] := Unitize[a - b]
equal[a_, b_] := 1 - unequal[a, b]

equal[a_, b_, c__] := equal[a, b] equal[b, c]
less[a_, b_, c__] := less[a, b] less[b, c]
greater[a_, b_, c__] := greater[a, b] greater[b, c]
lesseq[a_, b_, c__] := lesseq[a, b] lesseq[b, c]
greatereq[a_, b_, c__] := greatereq[a, b] greatereq[b, c]

unequal[a__] := Times @@ (unequal @@@ Subsets[{a}, {2}])

ClearAll[booleval]
booleval[condition_] := 
 Unevaluated[condition] /. {arr_?ArrayQ :> arr, Less -> less, Greater -> greater, 
   LessEqual -> lesseq, Equal -> equal, Unequal -> unequal, 
   GreaterEqual -> greatereq, Or -> Composition[Unitize, Plus], 
   And -> Times, Not -> (1 - # &), True -> 1, False -> 0}

ClearAll[pick]
pick[array_, condition_] :=
 Pick[array,
  booleval[condition],
  1]
```

`booleval` will take a set of (in)equalities over arrays and will evaluate them to obtain an array of Boolean values (0 or 1) while making use of vectorization and keeping packed arrays packed.  `pick` will extract the part of an array corresponding to 1s.  This will work similarly to MATLAB.

Example:

```
a = Range[10];
pick[a, a > 5 || a^2 <= 10]

(* ==> {1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

The advantage is the convenience of using standard notation for inequalities instead of a cryptic `UnitStep`.

The OP's example would be written as `L booleval[T <= 15]`.

Comment: Have you considered using `Subtract` for [performance](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40927/121) in the package code?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Good point, thank you!

Comment: By the way this may be relevant to you: [(1922)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1922/121)

Comment: There are some condition where `Select` works better than `UnitStep` based solution. Notice that `Select` based solution can utilize the fact that `True || a series of stuffs` will always be `True` and `False && a series of stuffs` will always be `False`. so there's no need for evaluation of "a series of stuffs". While `UnitStep` based solution cannot easily use this fact. so when tests are significantly more than elements in list, performance can reverse.

Comment: Test code:
`cond1 = Evaluate[And @@ ConstantArray[# > 1, 1*^4]] &; 
dat = RandomReal[1, 1*^4];
Select[dat, cond1] // AbsoluteTiming`
returns **{11.7397, {}}**

while
`cond = And @@ ConstantArray[dat > 1, 1*^5];
dat = RandomReal[1, 1*^4];
pick[dat, cond] // AbsoluteTiming`
returns **{79.1119, {}}**

Comment: I suppose it's quite hard to solve this problem using `UnitStep` based solution, it's a cost of vectorization I suppose?

Comment: @Wjx There are serious limitations that make this hard to implement well, e.g. `Greater` taking a long time to "evaluate" when it doesn't in fact evaluate at all.  Things change with M versions too.  Please check if it's better with the BoolEval package.  I don't have time to look into this now.

Comment: @Wjx Vectorization is always fast, but the code is hard to read and write (in Mathematica, not e.g. in MATLAB). With this code, and later with BoolEval, I tried to make it easy to read/write as well. Sadly, some bugs prevent me from doing this. Try e.g. `arr = RandomReal[1, 100]; On["Packing"]`, then evaluate `arr > 0.5`. It unpacks.  Why does it do that? I don't know. It doesn't even evaluate!  Maybe it's a bug. Last time I complained to WRI, the support person did not understand my point and kept saying that `arr < 0.5` is not correct syntax. I know, but that's no excuse for unpacking.

Comment: Yeah, Just a reminder that the selection of `Select` and `UnitStep` based solution still depends on one's application~ even in this case where `Select` "saved" 10000 times of calculation, it's only less than 10 times faster, so it's really inefficient in most cases.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yeah, I see. Truely wierd phenomenon. This will lead to a performance drop I suppose?

Answer (score 41):

```
L=ReplacePart[L, Position[T, i_/;i>15]->0]
```

Go with @Szabolcs answer whenever you can

Comment: This will work for more complex tests, where the `UnitStep` approach may not apply.

Comment: I like the UnitStep, ReplacePart solutions a lot. Some of the other solutions are very complicated and sure to turn off people who are new to Mathematica.  .... I think I finally figured out how and when to 'Add Comment' in this forum :)

Answer (score 20):

Szabolcs's answer using `UnitStep` is the right one for your specific case. It is also the most efficient by far: see the timing results below. Explicit `Map` operations and size comparisons do seem to be particularly slow.

However there is a `Boole` function that replicates the Matlab approach of returning 1 and 0 instead of `True` and `False`, which might be useful for other specific cases.

The other two examples I show here are roundabout ways  of getting the same answer that Szabolcs did using `UnitStep` (once you multiply by `ll`), but can be adapted to cases where the `UnitStep` version does not work for whatever reason.

```
In[2]:= ll = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {20, 20}];
tt = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {20, 20}];  


In[19]:= Do[Boole[Map[# < 15 &, tt, {2}]];, {1000}] // Timing
```

> `Out[19]= {0.375, Null}`

```
In[20]:= Do[UnitStep[15 - tt];, {1000}] // Timing
```

> `Out[20]= {0.016, Null}`

```
In[25]:= Do[Boole[Positive[15 - tt]];, {1000}] // Timing
```

> `Out[25]= {0.11, Null}`

Answer (score 13):

I'm actually writing a simple package similar to the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package in Mathematica right now. I've not made it to be efficient at all, but maybe I should try putting it up on github if anyone is interested.

You can redefine the `Part` expression for a custom data structure. Here I have defined the `Part` function for a expression with the head `pandasSeries`.

```
pandasSeries /: 
 Part[ps_pandasSeries, 
  boolps_pandasSeries /; VectorQ[Data@boolps, BooleQ]] := 
 pandasSeries[Pick[Data@ps, Data@boolps], 
  If[Index@ps =!= Null, Pick[Index@ps, Data@boolps]], Name@ps]
```

Where `Data` and `Index` are just accessory functions for the data structure. Anyway once you redefine comparison operators on the data structure to thread over it, you can run expressions like:

```
ps1[[ps1 < 3]]
```

The real difficulty is defining what every function already written to work with lists should do for a new data structure. So far my solution has been to do something like:

```
pandasSeries /: 
  func_[fore___, ps_pandasSeries, after___] /; 
   Not@MatchQ[func, noItFuncs] :=

  With[{res = func[fore, Data@ps, after]},
   If[Head[res] === List, pandasSeries[res, Index@ps, Name@ps], res]];
```

The idea is simply to define that functions that work on lists can work on the new data structure by extracting its data and running on that data, then using the constructor for the data structure. It works okay for the most part, but I didn't write it for speed. It´s really supposed to be more a proof-of-concept.

Comment: Have you kept up with this project at all? I would be interested in seeing the github if it exists.

Comment: Haven't kept up. I'm using the pandas library in python for a lot of this kind of stuff recently, so it doesn't matter. The library is completely useless except as an exercise, but here it is:
https://github.com/searke/Pandas-Package

Answer (score 10):

Here's my solution based on the syntax of Rojo, it works for most syntaxes of Part (maybe all). All dimensions corresponding to the indices where the test function and All are present are considered in the data selection. The value argument can either have the dimension of the x list or of the list corresponding to non-integer positions.

## Warning

The code works by adding an UpValue to Part for the value assignment case, and an UpValue to Function for retrieving values satisfying a condition. These are non local changes meant to be experimental, I haven't tested this function extensively, so please use with caution.

If you want to use the functions below in a safe way, see the answer to [Alternative to overloading Set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1162/66).

First some usage example

```
x=Table[2,{3},{2},{3},{2}];
x[[All,1,EvenQ[#] &,All]]=6
x

y=x[[All,1,All,All]]*2
x[[All,1,EvenQ[#] &,All]]=y
x

x[[1;;,1,EvenQ[#] &,All]]=6
x[[1 ;;, 1, All, All]]
x[[1;;,1,EvenQ[#] &,All]]

(*The parts of another symbol than x can be accessed using Sequence@@#2  
 as the condition is applied in a MapIndexed*)
x[[1;;,1,EvenQ[y[[Sequence @@ #2]]]&,All]]=6
```

The code

```
Unprotect[Part];
UpValues[Part]={};
Part/:Set[Part[x_,leftIndices:((_Integer|All|_List|_Span)...),cond_Function(*|cond_Symbol/;!(ListQ[cond]||cond===All)*),rightIndices:((_Integer|All|_List|_Span)...)],value_]:=
    part[x,{leftIndices},cond,{rightIndices},value];
Protect[Part];

Unprotect[Function];
UpValues[Function]={};
Function/:Part[x_,leftIndices:((_Integer|All|_List|_Span)...),cond_Function(*|cond_Symbol/;!(ListQ[cond]||cond===All)*),rightIndices:((_Integer|All|_List|_Span)...)]:=
    part[x,{leftIndices},cond,{rightIndices}];
Protect[Function];

SetAttributes[part,HoldFirst];
part[x_,{leftIndices:((_Integer|All|_List|_Span)...)},cond_Function(*|cond_Symbol/;!(ListQ[cond]||cond===All)*),{rightIndices:((_Integer|All|_List|_Span)...)},value_:None]:=
    Module[{xDimensions,indexSpanRange,allIndices,matchedSubPositions,matchedPositions,valuesExtracted,nonIntegerPositions, valuesReturned},

        allIndices={leftIndices,Sequence@@ConstantArray[All,Length@Dimensions@x-Length@{leftIndices}-Length@{rightIndices}],rightIndices};
        matchedSubPositions=Position[MapIndexed[cond,x[[Sequence@@allIndices]],{-1}],True,{-1}];

        nonIntegerPositions=Position[allIndices/.{_Span->All},All|_List] // Flatten;

        If[matchedSubPositions=!={}&&(Length[{leftIndices}]>0||Length[{rightIndices}]>0),
            matchedPositions=ConstantArray[allIndices /.{_Span->0,All->0},Length@matchedSubPositions];

            If[Position[allIndices,_List|_Span]=!={},
                xDimensions=Dimensions[x];

                MapIndexed[
                    (
                        Switch[allIndices[[#1]],
                            _List,
                                matchedSubPositions[[All,First@#2]]=matchedSubPositions[[All,First@#2]]/.Thread[(Range@Length@allIndices[[#1]])->allIndices[[#1]]];,
                            _Span,
                                indexSpanRange=Range@@(allIndices[[#1]]/.{All->xDimensions[[#1]],i_Integer?Negative:>xDimensions[[#1]]+i+1});
                                matchedSubPositions[[All,First@#2]]=matchedSubPositions[[All,First@#2]]/.Thread[(Range@Length@indexSpanRange)->indexSpanRange];
                        ]
                    )&
                    ,
                    nonIntegerPositions
                ];
            ];

            matchedPositions[[All,nonIntegerPositions]]=matchedSubPositions;
            ,
            matchedPositions=matchedSubPositions;
        ];

        (*assignment*)
        If[value =!= None && matchedPositions=!={},
            If[NumericQ[value],
                x=ReplacePart[x,matchedPositions->value];
                ,
                If[Length@Dimensions@value==Length@nonIntegerPositions,
                    valuesExtracted=Extract[value,matchedSubPositions];
                    ,
                    valuesExtracted=Extract[value,matchedPositions];
                ];

                x=ReplacePart[x,Thread[matchedPositions->valuesExtracted]];
            ];
        ];

        (*returned values*)
        If[matchedPositions=!={},
            valuesExtracted=Extract[x,matchedPositions];

            valuesReturned = 
                ReplacePart[
                    ConstantArray[{},xDimensions[[nonIntegerPositions]]]
                    ,
                    Thread[matchedSubPositions->valuesExtracted]
                ];

            valuesReturned
            ,
            {}
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: I only noticed this answer right now, but I'd stress again that modifications of built-in functions are the last resort and may have unintended consequences. The `Part` and `Function` are among those I would never touch for anything serious. Apart from the general problems which come with overloading built-ins, `Part` is particularly important. It is easy, for example, to inadvertently make assignments have different complexity (like linear instead of constant time), and break `Part` in other subtle ways. If nothing else, I'd seriously recommend to put a warning at the top in large bold font.

Comment: In fact, while I don't downvote, this answer is a close candidate for my downvote had I changed my mind. Please don't take it personally, you have many great posts, and I also did all these experiments with overloading built-ins, many times. It's just that there is a difference between our private experimentation and putting this stuff out in a public answer, because many people may get excited by this and not have enough knowledge to see the dangers of this approach (this does not refer to you, of course).

Comment: Yes I hesitated before putting this here, my previous answer didn't modify Part and Function, I left it to interested people. I put the code more for sharing the experimentation, in case someone could improve it.

Comment: It is a pity that we don't have some place where we could share experimental stuff without all that responsibility, which would be as easily accessible / readable /etc as here. May be some day...