# Handling vector comparisons in "Piecewise" function

Tags: list-manipulation

Is it possible for the Piecewise function to process a vector comparison? For example, my input vector is

```
x={0,1,2,3,4}
```

I would like to define a function that gives me x^2 if x<3.5, and x+3 otherwise. i.e. I would like my output to be {0,1,4,9,7}. Here I define a function:

```
myfunc[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2,x<3.5},{x+3,x>=3.5}}]
```

which obviously does not work. Is there a way to let Mathematica know that I want to compare x with 3.5 elementwise and apply that particular value to the segment as appropriate?

I'm used to R programming where I can use the ifelse function for this job, but I'm relatively new to Mathematica and don't know if this is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2821/does-mathematica-have-advanced-indexing

Comment: Thanks for your solutions; all work perfectly. As a R user I don't feel particularly comfortable with the way mathematica handles vector manipulation. Due to the nature of this problem I couldn't think of any keywords to search for a solution effectively.

Comment: Note that solutions using `Listable` and `Map` lose the speed advantage offered by vectorized operations in Mathematica. If speed is important, you may wish to use things like `UnitStep` and `Unitize` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not in front of a computer now, but I think you should be able to set your function to Listable and use it as-is:

```
SetAttributes[myfunc, Listable]
```

Comment: I am in front of a computer. It works.

Comment: @yohbs: Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing wrong with your function. You can `Map` it to a list as

```
 myfunc/@{0,1,2,3,4}
```

you get your desired output.

Alternatively, you can use your `myfunc` to define a new function that accepts lists:

```
 mynewfunc[y_List] := Map[myfunc, y]
```

Now

```
 mynewfunc[{0,1,2,3,4}]
```

gives

```
 {0, 1, 4, 9, 7}
```

Comment: Should it work for a multivariate function that is being evaluated element-wise of two vectors? Because I have a piecewise function of two variables and I want to map two vectors on it but I can't make it work using the suggestion above.

Comment: @LauraK,  I think you can use `Apply (@@@)` instead of `Map (/@)` in the case you describe. For example,  given `ClearAll[myfunc];
myfunc[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{x^2 + y, x + y < 10}, {x + 3, y > 5}}];`  and an input list of pairs, say, `xylist = RandomInteger[9, {5, 2}]`, you can do `myfunc @@@ xylist` or `mynewfunc[y_List] := Apply[myfunc, y, {1}];
mynewfunc[xylist]` to get the same result.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much, @kglr!