# Concise alternative to First@First@Position[..., 1,Heads->False]

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a more compact way to accomplish this:

```
lst = {0,0,7};
idx = Position[lst, Except[0], 1, Heads -> False] // First // First
(* => 3 *)
```

For comparison, Matlab doesn't need flattening or special options:

```
// in matlab
lst = [0,0,7];
idx = find(lst ~= 0)
// => 3
```

It is safe to assume that `lst` contains only one nonzero value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
FirstPosition[lst, _?(# != 0 &)][[1]]
```

> 3

Or

```
FirstPosition[lst, Except[0, _?NumberQ]][[1]]
```

> 3

Comment: (+1) Probably the most idiomatic way in Mathematica, but I prefer Matlab's syntax

Comment: @tba : I do not.  Matlab has to switch its return type if you feed it the equivalent of `FirstPosition[{lst, lst}, Except[0], Heads -> False]` because now the location is a sequence, not an atom.  Input-dependent output types are irritating.

Comment: Actually `find` always returns a matrix -- Matlab "atoms" are simply 1x1 matrices. But I understand your point and respect your differing opinion.

Answer (score 8):

```
Pick[Range@Length@lst, Unitize@lst, 1]
```

Some cursory testing suggests that the need to `Unitize` doubles the amount of time it takes to run.

---

Since there are seven solutions in four answers, some timings are in order. Using the list suggested by `xzczd1`, i.e.

```
lst = ConstantArray[0, 10^7];
lst[[6 10^5]] = 1;
```

we define the functions

```
xzczd1 = Ordering[-Abs@#][[1]] &;
xzczd2 = Ordering[Abs@#, -1] &;
ciao1 = SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"][[1, 1]] &;
ciao2 = SparseArray[#]["AdjacencyLists"][[1]] &;
eldo1 = FirstPosition[#, _?(# != 0 &)][[1]] &;
eldo2 = FirstPosition[#, Except[0, _?NumberQ]][[1]] &;
march = First@Pick[Range@Length@#, Unitize@#, 1] &;
bmf1 = LengthWhile[#, # == 0 &] + 1 &;
(*bmf2 = # /. {x : Longest[(0 | 0) ...], ___} :> Length@{x} + 1 &;*)
bmf3 = ArrayRules[#][[1, 1, 1]] &;
bmf4 = Flatten@Position[#, x_ /; x != 0] &;
lopez1 = Values[KeySelect[PositionIndex[#], # != 0 &]][[1]] &;
lopez2 = Flatten[Reap[Do[If[#[[i]] != 0, Sow[Position[#, #[[i]]]]], {i, Length@#}]][[2]]] &;
(*eldo3 = PositionLargest[#][[1]]&;*)
fs = AbsoluteTiming@*# & /@{xzczd1, xzczd2, ciao1, ciao2, eldo1, eldo2, march};
```

(I did not check bm2 because it ran for at least a minute before I aborted it, and I did not check eldo3 because I don't have a new enough version of Mathematica.)

And the results are:

```
TableForm[Through[fs@lst], TableHeadings -> {{"xzczd1", "xzczd2", "ciao1", "ciao2", "eldo1", "eldo2", "march", bmf1,(*bmf2,*)bmf3, bmf4, lopez1, lopez2}}]
```

[image]

As seen below, ciao's versions are still near the top (no surprise: ciao is a performance-tuning Wizard), but they're not the fastest anymore (although it's close!); for some reason, march's solution has overtaken ciao's versions, at least for cases where the number of non-zero elements is small.  I've done some preliminary testing for cases where there are many more non-zero elements, and ciao's versions edge march's out there.

---

Old timings:

[image]

Comment: (+1) Nice attempt at duplicating Matlab's logic. I appreciate the profiling stats.

Answer (score 8):

`SparseArray[lst]["NonzeroPositions"][[1, 1]]`

`SparseArray[lst]["AdjacencyLists"][[1]]`

Answer (score 7):

```
Ordering[-Abs@lst][[1]]
```

The above solution is short and fast. If you don't need to peel off all the braces, the code can be even shorter:

```
Ordering[Abs@lst, -1]
```

And this solution is faster when `lst` is very large. (You can test them with something like `lst = ConstantArray[0, 10^7]; lst[[6 10^5]] = 1;`)

Comment: (+1) Short and fast, though doesn't generalize as nicely as the matlab syntax, e.g. `find(lst == 7)`

Comment: @tba If there's still only one matched element then `Ordering[Abs[lst - 7], 1]`

Comment: Great point, though the readability's not quite as good as Matlab

Comment: @tba Actually there's a related post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2822/1871, `find` isn't yet included in the package though, maybe you can suggest Szabolcs to add this function.

Answer (score 4):

Hats off to @eldo for the amazing work on revisiting old threads to demonstrate commands in newer versions. I think it's very beneficial for all.

Some more fun stuff

With the list

```
list = {0, 0, 7};
```

from the OP, we can use [**LengthWhile**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LengthWhile.html)

```
LengthWhile[list, # == 0 &] + 1
```

or [**Longest**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Longest.html) and [**Length**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html)

```
list /. {x : Longest[(0|0) ...], ___} :> Length@{x} + 1
```

or [**ArrayRules**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayRules.html)

```
ArrayRules[list][[1, 1, 1]]
```

or [**Position**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) and [**DeleteCases**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)

```
Position[list, DeleteCases[list, 0][[1]]][[1, 1]]
```

to get

> `3`

or

```
Position[list, x_ /; x != 0] // Flatten
```

to get

> `{3}`

Comment: Thank you, bmf, for your kind remark :)

Answer (score 4):

Another way, is to use `PositionIndex` and `KeySelect`:

```
list = {0, 0, 7};

Values[KeySelect[PositionIndex[list], # != 0 &]][[1]]

(*{3}*)
```

Or using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
Flatten[Reap[Do[If[#[[i]] != 0, Sow[Position[#, #[[i]]]]], 
{i, Length@#}]][[2]]] &@list

(*{3}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

If we don't have negative numbers (thank you 1066) we can use
`PositionLargest` (new in 13.2)

```
list = {0, 0, 7};

PositionLargest[list][[1]]
```

3

Comment: Astute observation - will update my answer