# How to efficiently compute all the index distances of 1's in a huge list of 0's and 1's?

Tags: list-manipulation

Although I am an experienced C programmer, I am somewhat new to functional programming. Therefore I am a bit embarrassed to ask questions regarding such a simple problem. Any how...

I have a huge list of 0's and 1's (with many more 0's than 1's) with about 10,000 elements. I want to compute all index distances between consecutive 1's, and from that list build an histogram. Any efficient ideas?

For instance: Consider the list `L={ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}`.

The distances list would be `D={ 4, 5, 3 }`.

Comment: `Differences@Position[1]@L` or take a look at `SparseArray` and `"Nonzeropositions"`: [100661](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100661/5478)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a sparse list:

```
list = RandomChoice[{0.8, 0.2} -> {0, 1}, 10000];

Flatten[Differences@SparseArray[list]["NonzeroPositions"]]
```

Less efficient than the `SparseArray` method, but still performs nicely:

```
(* alternative #1 *)
Values@KeyDrop[Counts[Accumulate@list], 0]

(* alternative #2 *)
With[{l = Accumulate@list}, BinCounts[l, {1, l[[-1]], 1}]]
```

The performance ratio (greater or less than 1) between these last two will depend on the sparse density and length of the list.

Answer (score 10):

Considering your `L`:

```
diff = Differences @ Flatten @ Position[L, 1]
```

> {4, 5, 3}

Also, `Flatten` may not be applied to `Position` but to `Differences`, or it may not be applied at all - then `diff` will be a list of single-element (i.e., differences) lists.

A list of $10^4$ elements is easily handled by Mathematica: it takes only 0.004 seconds to provide `diff` in this case. For a list of size $10^8$ it takes 15.5 sec on my machine.

And btw, `D` is a built-in command so don't use it as a name of something. A safe practice it to always use lowercase names and variables.

**NOTE:** [Xavier's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/31159/xavier) [approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126021/22013) using `SparseArray` with `"NonzeroPositions"` is $\sim 6$ times faster.

Answer (score 7):

```
Differences@SparseArray[L]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

> {4, 5, 3}

Answer (score 3):

After not much researching I found a one line solution myself, which I post now:

```
Histogram[Differences[Flatten[Position[L, 1]]]]
```

will do the trick.