# How can I avoid using a For-loop in my code?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, functional-style

I am trying to avoid using `For` because I heard that `For` is not cool in functional programming. Below is a problem that the first idea came to my mind is using `For`. How can I change this into a code using `Table` or `Range` or something else?

What the code does is to extract the elements in a list `ls` which satisfies certain condition into a new list `lsNew`.

```
ls = RandomInteger[20, 1000];
lsNew = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[ls], i++,
  If[ls[[i]] < 6, lsNew = Append[lsNew, ls[[i]]]]]
lsNew
```

Comment: Use [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) instead. The setup is much, much simpler, and it doesn't use $O(n^2)$ methods to do it. (`Append` used like this is the culprit.)

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2822/1871

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at `Select`.

```
lsNew = Select[# < 6 &]@ls
```

Comment: As from 10.3 we can also use `LessThan[6]` instead of the pure function.

Comment: @SimonWoods Ah, the operator forms of inequalities.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

OK, the related post I linked above may be too long, so let me extract the relevant part:

```
Pick[#, UnitStep[# - 6], 0] &@ls
```

Just for fun, here's a somewhat strange solution:

```
ls /. $_ /; $ >= 6 :> (## &[])
```

Answer (score 3):

Although `Select` is the classical *Mathematica* function for doing what you ask, in V10.2 or later one can map an `If` expression (for some a more natural way to express the problem) and get the desired results.

```
SeedRandom[42]; data = RandomInteger[20, 100];
If[# < 6, #, Nothing] & /@ data
```

> `{4, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 0, 1, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 
>   1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 0, 5, 3, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5}`

This is likely to run slower the `Select`, but will run much faster than a For-loop.

Comment: One can still use `If` to solve the problem before v10.2, by using [these](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3705/1871) instead of `Nothing` :).

Comment: I find: " `Select` items `< 6` ", to be a fairly natural way to express the problem.

Comment: @Edmund. I do too. But others don't. Note that I qualified my statement with "some".