# Code optimizations with functions inside Module

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, scoping

I wrote a small code by using functions inside `Module`:

```
M[Φ_] = RotationMatrix[Φ]; Nel = 33*6 + 31 + 2*7 + 4*8; 
norm[A_, μ_, σ_, q_] = 
 A PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], q];

Fsq[q_, σ_, p_, as_, bs_, Φ_, l_, w_ ] := 
  Module[{r, b1, a1, a, b, f, F, G, temp},
   r = 5;
   (*Defining the Q through Cartesian decomposition for G*)
   b1 = {0, 1}; 
   a1 = {Sin[Φ], -Cos[Φ]};
   G[n_, k_] := (2 π)/(2 bs Sin[Φ]) k b1 + (2 π)/(2 as Sin[Φ]) n a1;
   a = {as, 0};
   b = {bs Cos[Φ], bs Sin[Φ]};

   f[Q_] := 
    Nel/(l w )* Sin[Q[[1]] l/2]/(I Q[[1]]/2) Sin[Q[[2]] w/2]/(I Q[[2]]/2);

   F[Q_] := 
    f[M[-p[[1]]].Q] + f[M[-p[[2]]].Q] E^(I a.Q) + 
     f[M[-p[[3]]].Q] E^(I (a + b).Q) + f[M[-p[[4]]].Q] E^(I b.Q);


   Sum[(temp = G[n, k]; 
     norm[Abs[F[temp]]^2, temp, σ, q]), {n, -r, r}, {k, 1, r}]
   ];
```

Ran a speed test:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  Table[Fsq[q, 0.02, {0.5, 1.2, 1, 1}, 8, 4, 120, 4,1.5], {q, 0, 3, 0.03}];]
```

It's pretty slow even with all my optimization attempts: takes 5s on my laptop. I assume this has something to do with my inefficient style of writing this code, maybe I should avoid defining functions in the `Module`? What are the best practices for this type of codes with functions inside `Module`? Any suggestions to speed it up?

Comment: Maybe it is understandable for other people who have no knowledge of your area when you write down your **mathematical formula** of your implementation function, like `Fsq[],F[],f[]`.

Comment: Notice that `Nel` is not defined in the expression for `f[Q]` in your function `Fsq`. Is that intended?

Comment: Corrected.  I just missed it while copying. Thanks.

Comment: What does your code do? Perhaps knowing what you want to achieve somebody may have a more direct route. (Also, as an aside, if you want to notify somebody of your comment, put a @ + their username anywhere in your comment, such as @AlGuy).

Comment: I find your code difficult to follow, but if you run it with inexact numbers you cut the running time by half `Table[Fsq[q, 0.02, {0.5, 1.2, 1, 1}, 8., 4., 120., 4., 1.5], {q, 0, 3,
   0.03}]`

Comment: It sounds like one of your questions is: do those function definitions inside Module slow it down?  In general: yes.  In this case: I couldn't tell without benchmarking (partly due to embedding of some arguments like `as` in the definition).  You'd have to benchmark it.  But don't expect more than a few percent speedup.  Keep in mind that these are guesses on my part and Mathematica performance is notoriously hard to predict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without giving a full solution, here are some tips on how to speed up this sort of code:

- You are getting floating point results.  **Try to ensure that all calculations are done using floating point (not exact) values** (unless there is a special precision-related reason not to).  Your code takes 1.28 seconds on my computer.  If I change `b1 = {0,1}` to `b1 = {0., 1.}` it takes 0.77 seconds.  Go through your code and check for this.  `1`, `Pi`, `Sqrt[2] are exact numbers,`1.0`,`3.14`,`1.41`are floating point numbers.  Arithmetic between exact and floating point gives floating point results, so just make sure the starting values are floating point.  I noticed that in your current code`temp` is calculated purely using exact arithmetic.
- **Vectorize when you can!**  This means that instead of doing `Table[x+5, {x, 0., 10}]` you would do `Range[0., 10] + 5`. That is, work with vector variables instead of scalars.  Generally, if your code is scalar-only and arithmetic only, then it will also work with vector inputs.  But if you already do vector arithmetic in your code, then it will need modifications.

  In your case, you should try to vectorize on `q`.  Instead of the outermost `Table`, generate the vector of `q` values and pass them to your function.  For this to work, you will need to be careful about how your function is written to make sure it will handle vector-values `q`s.  Currently it does not because it already uses 2D vectors internally (i.e. `a1`, `b1`, `temp`, etc.)

I didn't try to rewrite it properly, but I tried a hack – just explicitly unpack `temp` into its components and handle each of the two components separately.  This makes it effectively scalar code, so we can plug in a vector-values `q` without further changes.

```
Fsq[q_, σ_, p_, as_, bs_, Φ_, l_, w_] :=

  Module[{r, b1, a1, a, b, f, F, G, A, μ1, μ2},
   r = 5;
   (*Defining the Q through Cartesian decomposition for G*)

   b1 = {0., 1.};
   a1 = {Sin[Φ], -Cos[Φ]};
   G[n_, k_] := (2 π)/(2 bs Sin[Φ]) k b1 + (2 \
π)/(2 as Sin[Φ]) n a1;
   a = {as, 0};
   b = {bs Cos[Φ], bs Sin[Φ]};

   f[Q_] := (
    Nel Sin[1/2 Q[[1]] l] Sin[
      1/2 Q[[2]] w])/(((l w) (I Q[[1]]) (I Q[[2]]))/(2 2));

   F[Q_] := 
    f[M[-p[[1]]].Q] + f[M[-p[[2]]].Q] E^(I a.Q) + 
     f[M[-p[[3]]].Q] E^(I (a + b).Q) + f[M[-p[[4]]].Q] E^(I b.Q);

   Sum[
    With[{temp = G[n, k]},
     {μ1, μ2} = temp;
     A = Abs[F[temp]]^2;
     {norm[A, μ1, σ, q], norm[A, μ2, σ, q]}
     ],
    {n, -r, r}, {k, 1, r}
    ]
   ];

AbsoluteTiming[
 res = Table[
    Fsq[q, 0.02, {0.5, 1.2, 1, 1}, 8, 4, 120, 4, 1.5], {q, 0, 3, 
     0.03}];]
(* {0.794848, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 res2 = Fsq[qvec, 0.02, {0.5, 1.2, 1, 1}, 8, 4, 120, 4, 1.5];]
(* {0.059728, Null} *)

res == Transpose[res2]
(* True *)
```

As you can see, this gave a more than 10x speedup.

**For this type of code you can get further speedups by using `Compile`.**  But that will be a bit more work (a lot more rewriting) and it will reduce readability somewhat.  I see that you tried to write your code in a way to keep it readable by using function definitions inside `Module`.  This will not be easily possible with `Compile`.

**To sum up,** for purely arithmetic code, vectorization is straightforward and will usually give great speedups.

If the code also has branches (like `If`) then vectorization is more trouble, [but still possible with some tricks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2821/12).

**Further reading:**

- [Performance tuning in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29349/12)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can the concept of vectorizing somehow be used with `NonlinearModelFit`? I am basically generating this theoretical curve to fit it to an experiment.

Comment: @AlGuy Not to my knowledge.