# Remove columns basing on binary sequence

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Possibly it is duplicate, still I could not find here elegant way to remove matrix columns basing on binary sequence. i.e. if I apply {1,1,0,0,1,0,1} to matrix it should delete columns 3,4 and 6.

Comment: You can simply use `matrix[[All, Pick[Range@Last@Dimensions@matrix, mask, 1]]]`, where `matrix` is your matrix, and `mask` is in your case `{1,1,0,0,1,0,1}`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It works! Thank you

Comment: Another option: `matrix[[All, Flatten[Position[{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 1]]]]`

Comment: Also, `Pick[Transpose[matrix], {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 1] // Transpose`

Comment: Similar to @BobHanlon's: `Pick[matrix, Table[{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {Length@matrix}], 1]`. Or, just to be safe: `Pick[matrix, 
 Table[PadRight[{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 
   Last@Dimensions@matrix], {Length@matrix}], 1]`.

Comment: [A related thread.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2821)

Comment: For Mathematica 10 or higher: `Extract[matrix, {All, Flatten@Position[mask, 1]}]`.

Comment: Also for Mathematica 10 or higher: `matrix[[;; , PositionIndex[{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}][1]]]`

Answer (score 4):

Various solutions were posted in comments:

```
matrix = RandomInteger[10, {3, 7}];
mask = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};

(* Leonid Shifrin *)
matrix[[All, Pick[Range@Last@Dimensions@matrix, mask, 1]]]

(* Coolwater *)
matrix[[All, Flatten[Position[mask, 1]]]]

(* Bob Hanlon *)
Pick[Transpose[matrix], mask, 1] // Transpose

(* march *)
Pick[matrix, Table[mask, {Length@matrix}], 1]

(* Alexey Popkov (for Mathematica 10 or higher) *)
Extract[matrix, {All, Flatten@Position[mask, 1]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list =
  {{2, 2, 1, 9, 8, 5, 6},
   {2, 5, 7, 2, 7, 3, 5},
   {0, 9, 5, 1, 9, 0, 4}};

mask = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};
```

Pre-define `p` for better comparability:

```
p = Position[mask, 0]
```

{{3}, {4}, {6}}

```
Delete[p] /@ list
```

returns

```
{{2, 2, 8, 6},
 {2, 5, 7, 5},
 {0, 9, 9, 4}}
```

We get the same result with

```
MapAt[Nothing, p] /@ list;

ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, p] /@ list;

ReplacePart[p :> Nothing] /@ list;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{2, 2, 1, 9, 8, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 2, 7, 3, 5}, {0, 9, 5, 1, 9, 
    0, 4}};
mask = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};

f = FoldList[If[Last@#2 == 1, First@#2, Nothing] &, Nothing, 
    Transpose[{#, mask}]] &;

f /@ list
```

> {{2, 2, 8, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 5}, {0, 9, 9, 4}}

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to define the following function:

```
f[vec_?VectorQ, binseq_] := vec*(binseq /. (0 -> 0.))
f[mat_?MatrixQ, binseq_] := Map[f[#, binseq] &, mat] /. {0. -> Nothing}
```

Grabbing the @eldo's matrix:

```
m1 = {{2, 2, 1, 9, 8, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 2, 7, 3, 5}, {0, 9, 5, 1, 9, 0, 4}};

mask = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};

f[m1, mask]

(*{{2, 2, 8, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 5}, {0, 9, 9, 4}}*)

m2 = { {2.1, 2.2, 1.3, 9.4, 8.5, 5.6, 6.7}, 
      {2.1, 5.2, 7.3, 2.4, 7.5, 3.6, 5.7}, 
      {0.1, 9.2, 5.3, 1.4, 9.5, 0.6, 4.7} };

f[m2, mask] === m2[[All, Flatten@SparseArray[mask]["ExplicitPositions"]]]

(*True*)
```

Comment: It is an integers only solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{2, 2, 1, 9, 8, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 2, 7, 3, 5}, {0, 9, 5, 1, 9, 0, 4}};

mask = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};


list[[All, Flatten @ SparseArray[mask]["ExplicitPositions"]]]
```

> ```
> {{2, 2, 8, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 5}, {0, 9, 9, 4}}
> ```

Comment: (+1) and happy new year! I am sure you know, but I am saying it in any case. `NonzeroPositions` also works

Comment: Thank you and happy  new year to you too @bmf. (I recently noticed the new property names for SparseArray. Old property names still work but the documentation page uses the new names.)

Comment: All hail the old-school :-)

Answer (score 2):

Explanation:

Rename all elements equal to `0` in the original list to something, say `x`
Multiply each sublist by the `mask`
Keep only the elements that are not equal to `0`
Rename `x` to `0` which are the ones from the `list` and not the `mask`

This is a prime candidate for `Threaded`

With

```
list = {{2, 2, 1, 9, 8, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 2, 7, 3, 5}, {0, 9, 5, 1, 9, 
    0, 4}};
mask = {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};
```

we do

```
DeleteCases[(list //. 0 -> x) Threaded[mask], 0, Infinity] /. x -> 0
```

to get

> `{{2, 2, 8, 6}, {2, 5, 7, 5}, {0, 9, 9, 4}}`

Comment: (+1) Nicely done, mate! :-)