# parallelization sum of list

Tags: parallelization

Is there a simple way to parallelize sum of list elements ?
when I use:

```
n = 500;
T1[z_] = Table[RandomReal[]/(RandomReal[] + RandomReal[] z), {i, n}];
Timing@Parallelize@Total@T1[1.]
```

error

```
Parallelize::nopar1: "T1[1.] cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential evaluation."
```

It is only an examle. I my calculation I have a huge expression with elements p/(q+r z) which are a result of using Apart[]

---

Thanks for your help , but  the problem is something else
f[z_]- very big formula (rational function) which should be integrated

Af[z_]:=Apart@f[z]

after that the Af[z] = p1/(q1+r1 z)+p2/(q2+ r2 z) +.....

thus integral is simply defined:

F[z_]:=Af[z]/. p_/(q_ + r_ z) -> p/r Log[q + r z]

The problem is:
F[z] has a lot of simple elements, and I should compute F[z] for many complex points  as quick as possible

regards, Olaf

Comment: Why do you feel the need to use `Parallelize` here? Evaluating each element of the lists in turn inside `Table` is very slow, you should be able to do everything in one step. If you have the lists `p`, `q`, and `r` then simply define `T1[z_]:=p/(q+r z)`.

Comment: Also see the suggestions here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128525/6588

Comment: Why not try directly parallelizing the `Table` evaluation with `ParallelTable`? I.e., `T2[z_] := 
  ParallelTable[RandomReal[]/(RandomReal[] + RandomReal[] z), {i, n}];`

Answer (score 1):

**tl; dr** Do not try to parallelize this. Use vector arithmetic (vectorization) instead.

`Total` cannot be parallelized because it already makes use of all your CPU cores in a way that is much more effective than Mathematica's parallel tools.  The same applies to vector arithmetic.  If `a` and `b` are two large arrays of equal size, then operations such as `a^2`, `a*b`, `a.b`, `Total[a]`, etc. will run very efficiently and will make use of all your CPU cores. In fact these will often be faster than a naïve `for` loop one might write in C.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 10^7;
p = RandomReal[1, n];
q = RandomReal[1, n];
r = RandomReal[1, n];

T1[z_] := p/(q + z r)

AbsoluteTiming[
 Total[T1[1.]]
]
```

> {0.143513, 6.92922*10^6}

Comment: But the problem is:

Comment: Thanks for your help , but the problem is something else f[z_]- very big formula (rational function) which should be integrated

Af[z_]:=Apart@f[z]

after that the Af[z] = p1/(q1+r1 z)+p2/(q2+ r2 z) +.....

thus integral is simply defined:

F[z_]:=Af[z]/. p_/(q_ + r_ z) -> p/r Log[q + r z]

The problem is: F[z] has a lot of simple elements, and I should compute F[z] for many complex points as quick as possible

regards, Olaf