# Threshold elements in a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm new to *Mathematica*. I hope this is not a too stupid question, but I couldn't find a solution in the *Mathematica* documentation.

My question is about creating a function to iterate over the elements in a table. For example, suppose I have a table

```
a = {{1, 2, 34, 2}, {1, 2, 8, 3}, {12, 4, 6, 2}}
```

I want to build another table such that when an element of `a` is < 10,the corresponding the new table is 1 , and when element of `a` is >= 10, the corresponding the new table is 0.

I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: `UnitStep[9.5 - a]`

Comment: in general: [Does Mathematica have advanced indexing?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2822/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b = a /. { x_ /; x < 10 -> 1, y_ /; y >= 10 -> 0}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was easier than i thought!

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
Map[If[# < 10, 1, 0] &, a, {2}]
```

> {{1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1}}

Or

```
Map[Boole[# < 10]&, a, {2}]
```

Or

```
Clip[a, {10, 10}, {1, 0}]
```

Comment: Vielen Dank! Ihrem Profil zu Urteile sind Sie aus Berlin. Mein Englisch ist schlecht, wie Sie sehen können! Danke nochmals! :)

Comment: Gern geschehen :)