# How can I use Pick to select items in one list when a value in a corresponding list is greater than some value of another list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following lists:

```
dat1 = {{43, 12.0541}, {44, 10.789}, {45, 9.505}};

dat2 = {{43, 11.60940}, {44, 10.693}, {45, 9.764}};
```

How can I implement Pick or Select to select from `dat1` the elements that have the second array position > than the correspondenting array position of `dat1`. In this simple explemple, the the element is  `{45, 9.764}`. I tried to use something like that:

```
Pick[dat1, dat2, dat2[[2]] > dat1[[2]]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use my [BoolEval package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/BoolEval):

```
<< BoolEval`
```

Use an all matrix elements:

```
BoolPick[dat1, dat1 > dat2]
(* {{12.0541}, {10.789}, {}} *)
```

Use the second part of each sub-element:

```
BoolPick[dat1, dat1[[All, 2]] > dat2[[All, 2]]]
(* {{43, 12.0541}, {44, 10.789}} *)
```

[How does it work?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2822/12)

`BoolPick[x,y]` is just a shorthand for `Pick[x, BoolEval[y], 1]`. You can see what `BoolEval` does by evaluating it with symbolic arguments:

```
BoolEval[a > b]
(* 1 - UnitStep[-a + b] *)
```

`BoolEval` is the engine that makes `BoolPick` so fast.

`BoolEval` (not `BoolPick`) is also available as a [resource function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BoolEval), but I recommend the package version for slightly better performance and convenience functions such as `BoolPick`.

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

```
Pick[dat1, 1 - UnitStep[dat1[[All, 2]] - dat2[[All, 2]]], 1]
```

> ```
> {{45, 9.505}}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
Pick[dat1, Positive[dat2[[All, 2]] - dat1[[All, 2]]]]
```

> ```
> {{45, 9.505}}
> ```

Pick from `dat2` using the same condition:

```
Pick[dat2, 1 - UnitStep[dat1[[All, 2]] - dat2[[All, 2]]], 1]
```

> ```
> {{45, 9.764}}
> ```

```
Pick[dat2, Positive[dat2[[All, 2]] - dat1[[All, 2]]]]
```

> ```
> {{45, 9.764}}
> ```

Comment: This picks those elements where `dat2[[All, 2]] >= dat1[[All, 1]]`. Note `>=` not `>`. OP asked for `>`. It is very easy to make small mistakes like this when writing inequalities in terms of `UnitStep`. This is why `BoolEval` is so useful: it does it for you automatically.

Comment: @Szabolcs, you are right. I don't remember ever getting `UnitStep` right in first try :)

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {{43, 12.0541}, {44, 10.789}, {45, 9.505}};

b = {{43, 11.60940}, {44, 10.693}, {45, 9.764}};
```

Using `Extract`

```
Extract[b, Position[a - b, {_, _?Negative}]]
```

{{45, 9.764}}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {{43, 12.0541}, {44, 10.789}, {45, 9.505}};

b = {{43, 11.60940}, {44, 10.693}, {45, 9.764}};
```

---

Using `Select`:

```
Last /@ Select[Thread[{a, b}], ! FreeQ[#[[1]] - #[[2]], _?Negative] &]

(*{{45, 9.764}}*)
```