# Error Using Sow in DensityHistogram with ColorFunction

Tags: plotting, bugs, color

To find the color values used in a plot, I was using `Sow` as shown here:

```
Short@Reap[Histogram3D[RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 500], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Sow[#1]] &)]
 ]
```

[image: Sow/Reap OK]

But I get an error if I simply replace `Histogram3D` by

```
Short@Reap[
  DensityHistogram[RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 500], 
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Sow[#1]] &)]
  ]
```

Now I get the following message:

```
Transpose::nmtx :  "The first two levels of the one-dimensional list"   
 {{{-3.5,3.},{-3.5,3.},{0.,24.}},0, ... , 1} cannot be transposed.

Transpose::argt :  "Transpose called with 0 arguments; 1 or 2 
arguments are    expected."
```

[image: error]

It's possible to work around this problem by doing without `Sow` and `Reap` as follows:

```
l = {};
{DensityHistogram[RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 500], 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][AppendTo[l, #1]; #1] &)], 
 N@l}
```

But it would be nice to know **if there is an explanation** for why `Sow` doesn't work in the `DensityHistogram` example whereas it works in `Histogram3D`. The same error appears if I leave out the `Reap`.

From the message it seems clear that a list of all `PlotRange` tuples is being *sown* at some point before the `ColorFunction` actually is put to use. I tried to suppress passing that kind of argument to `Sow` by modifying the `ColorFunction` to

```
ColorFunction -> (If[ListQ[#1], White, 
 ColorData["Rainbow"][Sow[#1]]] &)
```

but it had no effect. As Leonid pointed out in his answer, there must therefore be a *different* invocation of `Sow` outside the color function.

Maybe someone knows another way to suppress the invalid `ColorFunction` call that seems to trip up `Sow`. However, it doesn't seem to be obvious because when I *don't* use `Sow` as in my work-around based on `AppendTo` with a list `l`, there is no entry in the resulting list `l` that corresponds to the `PlotRange` tuples.

**Edit**

It seems that this is a problem specifically with `DensityHistogram`. I also noticed that the setting for `FrameTicks` is *ignored* by `DensityHistogram`. It can be restored by wrapping the plot in `Show` with the desired `FrameTicks` option.

None of these issues arise with the related function `SmoothDensityHistogram`.

Leonid pointed out what the probable cause for the `Sow` error is, but since  wrapping the result in another `Show`, I would for now stick with the workaround I mentioned above: ditch `Sow` and `Reap`, and use `AppendTo` to collect the desired values in a list `l` using a `CompoundExpression` of the type `AppendTo[l, #]; #`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create an example that doesn't require version 8?  I do not have `DensityHistogram` or `BinormalDistribution` -- does it affect *only* `DensityHistogram`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Fortunately (or unfortunately for you?) I so far only found this problem with `DensityHistogram`. You could replace `BinormalDistribution` by `NormalDistribution` with `Randomvariate` getting argument `{500,2}`, but that won't change anything. Sorry - I wasn't trying to rub in your lack of version 8... if I find another case I'll post an update.

Comment: "I wasn't trying to rub..." I didn't think you were, but I'm afraid I cannot help then.  Looks like Leonid is on the case so that shouldn't matter. :-)

Comment: I would not worry too much about unprotecting in this case, since I wrapped it inside ``Internal`InheritedBlock``, making this effect local to the execution stack inside `withTaggedReapSow` dynamic environment. The rest of the system is unaffected by these modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that's definitely a useful trick.

Comment: Yes, ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` is used specifically when you want to create a "dynamical local copy" of a system function, so that it inherits all definitions etc, but is otherwise independent, and subsequent changes in definitions of the copy do not affect the original, and only affect the code in the body of ``Internal`InheritedBlock``. I dwelled on that more [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/alternative-to-overloading-set/1163#1163), and you can also find many other examples of its use here and on StackOverflow. One of the very useful functions indeed.

Comment: Also, if you decide to stick with `AppendTo`, you may want to use linked lists instead (like `l={newElem, l}`), since for large number of points, as we know, `AppendTo` will have quadratic complexity and considerably slow things down.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like a defect in the implementation. Here is a simple test:

```
traced = 
  Trace[
    DensityHistogram[RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 500], 
    ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#] &)]
];

FreeQ[traced,Sow]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

What this means is that `Sow` is also used in the implementation, and apparently without tags, so when `Reap` is used in the implementation to collect the points, it also collects yours. Tags should have been used by the implementors to avoid such collisions.

And here is a fix:

```
ClearAll[withTaggedReapSow];
SetAttributes[withTaggedReapSow, HoldAll];
withTaggedReapSow[code_] :=
  Module[{internalTag},
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{Reap, Sow},
      Unprotect[Reap, Sow];
      Sow[arg_] := Sow[arg, internalTag];
      Reap[arg_] := Reap[arg, internalTag, #2 &];
      code]];
```

and now:

```
withTaggedReapSow[
 Short@Reap[
   DensityHistogram[RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 500], 
     ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Sow[#1, "MyTag"]] &)],
     "MyTag",
     #2 &
 ]
]
```

gives an expected result.

Comment: Sounds correct. I actually tried using tags myself but that didn't fix it...

Comment: @Jens The problem is not that *you* are not using tags, but that tags are not used in the implementation of `DensityHistogram`. So, `Reap` in there collects anything which was sowed, and that includes your points.

Comment: Yes, I think you nailed it.

Comment: @Jens I added a fix, have a look

Comment: That definitely suppresses the error. Only one thing: now it seems that the internal `Reap`/`Sow` didn't manage to produce a plot frame (apparently that was its purpose). But that can be fixed by wrapping the plot in `Show[..., Frame -> True]`

Comment: @Jens Indeed. Strange...well, figuring exactly why *that* is happening is beyond me :). Particularly given that you have the workaround with `Show`.