# Pure Functions with Lists as arguments

Tags: programming, functions

Assuming I have two function:

example 1:

```
add[{x_, y_, z_}] := x + y - z
add[{1, 3, 5}]
```

If use pure function,I know I can write it as :

```
Function[{x}, x[[1]] + x[[2]] - x[[3]]][{1, 3, 5}]
```

example 2:

```
fun[{a_, b_}, y_] := If[y~Mod~2 == 0, {a~Join~{y}, b}, {a, b~Join~{y}}]
Fold[fun, {{}, {}}, Range@10]

Fold[Function[{x, y}, 
  If[y < 5, {Join[x[[1]], {y}], x[[2]]}, {x[[1]], 
    Join[x[[2]], {y}]}]], {{}, {}}, Range[10]]
```

I think this a little prolix  with many "[[]]", can you tell me another simpler way?

**Updated**

```
Do[
  If[i[[1]] < i[[4]] < i[[7]] && 
    i[[1]]/(10 i[[2]] + i[[3]]) + i[[4]]/(10*i[[5]] + i[[6]]) + 
      i[[7]]/(10 i[[8]] + i[[9]]) == 1, Print@i
   ],
  {i, Permutations[Range[9]]}
  ] // Timing
{2.153, Null}
```

============

```
Do[If[(x /. {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_, i_} :> 
      a < d < g && a/(10 b + c) + d/(10 e + f) + g/(10 h + i) == 1), 
   Print@x], {x, Permutations[Range[9]]}] // Timing
{10.374, Null}
(*can't compiled*)
```

=============

```
Block[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i},
  Do[
   If[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i} = x;
    a < d < g && a/(10 b + c) + d/(10 e + f) + g/(10 h + i) == 1, 
    Print@x], {x, Permutations[Range[9]]}]
  ] // Timing
{2.543, Null}
(*easy compiled*)
(*If Module or Blcok within Do loop, Module will slower than Block *)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8382/121

Comment: Please see my edit which addresses speeding up / compilation within the approach I proposed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Preamble

This is IMO a very good question. I will try to describe an approach based on code-generation, which in my view would allow one to get the most benefits of declarative rule-based-like definitions without essentially imposing eny limitations or introducing any inconsistencies. The resulting functions can also be `Compiled`.

### General solution via code generation and overloading

#### Code

As an alternative, one can overload `Function`, in the following way:

```
Unprotect[Function];
Function[{left___, {syms__Symbol}, right___}, body_,atts_:{}] :=
  Module[{var},
    With[{
        rules = Thread[# :> Evaluate[  Range[Length[#]]]] &@
          Thread[HoldPattern[{syms}]] /. ind_Integer :> var[[ind]]
      },
      Function @@ (Hold[{left, var, right}, body,atts] /. rules)
    ]
  ];
Protect[Function];
```

Since by itself, `Function` does not have such extended syntax, this should be reasonably safe.

#### Usage

You can then call:

```
Function[{{x,y,z}},x+y-z]
```

and what you get will look like

```
(* Function[{var$28109},var$28109[[1]]+var$28109[[2]]-var$28109[[3]]] *)
```

so that the above code does some code-generation for you. Your second example also works verbatim, without any modiication:

```
Fold[
  Function[{{a, b}, y},If[y~Mod~2 == 0, {a~Join~{y}, b}, {a, b~Join~{y}}]], 
  {{}, {}}, 
  Range@10]

(* {{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}} *)
```

Function's attributes can also be handled. The following, in particular, will do in-place modifications of a list passed as a first argument:

```
lst = {0, 0, 0};
Function[{{a, b, c}, d, e, f}, a = d; b = e; c = f, HoldAll][lst, 1, 2, 3];
lst 

(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

again, with a transparent and easy to read syntax. Such behavior does not seem to be easy to reproduce in other approaches, at least without some loss of clarity / readability.

#### Advantages of this scheme

In my opinion, this scheme has a number of advantages w.r.t. other solutions, in particular those based on replacement rules. Some of them:

- Generality - it can handle all cases without any modifications to the body of the function, w.r.t. how you'd write it in a rule-based style.
- Support of function's attributes.
- No impedance mismatch with `Function`: since the result is good old pure function, it does not have any limitations or inconsistencies in terms of how it can be used (e.g. in `Compile`, see next item, but perhaps not only)
- Such functions can be `Compile`-d rather straightforwardly, which is described in the last section of the answer.

### Making it safer with a dynamic environment

Since overloading built-in functions globally is generally a bad idea, you can make it safer by creating a [local dynamic environment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/alternative-to-overloading-set/1163#1163).

#### Code

This is done with `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``:

```
ClearAll[withAddedFunctionSyntax];
SetAttributes[withAddedFunctionSyntax, HoldAll];
withAddedFunctionSyntax[code_] :=
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Function},
    Unprotect[Function];
    Function[{left___, {syms__Symbol}, right___}, body_, atts_:{}] :=
      Module[{var},
        With[{
            rules = Thread[# :> Evaluate[  Range[Length[#]]]] &@
              Thread[HoldPattern[{syms}]] /. ind_Integer :> var[[ind]]
          },
          Function @@ (Hold[{left, var, right}, body,atts] /. rules)
        ]
      ];
    Protect[Function];
    code
  ];
```

#### Usage

you can now execute the code in this environment:

```
withAddedFunctionSyntax[Function[{{x,y,z}},x+y-z][{1,3,5}]]

(* -1 *)
```

Note that it is enough to execute only the part with your function definition in that environment, you can export it to a global one:

```
fun= withAddedFunctionSyntax[Function[{{x,y,z}},x+y-z]]

(* Function[{var$357},var$357[[1]]+var$357[[2]]-var$357[[3]]] *)

fun[{1,3,5}]

(* -1  *)
```

### Certain special cases, speed-ups and compilation

As the OP rightly noted, using replacement rules presents also problems for speeding up and / or compiling the functions obtained that way. Here, I will use the OP's added example to show how one can speed up and also compile functions obtained via the procedure I proposed above. I will be using the global (less secure) version of the `Function` overloading for simplicity, but it is trivial to use also a dynamic environment.

#### Problems with naive usage in loops etc

First, let us try to run the naive version of the code:

```
Do[
  Function[{{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}},
     If[a < d < g && a/(10 b + c) + d/(10 e + f) + g/(10 h + i) == 1, 
         Print[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}]
     ]][i], {i,Permutations[Range[9]]}
] // Timing
```

I had to `Abort[]` this code, since it was taking way too long. And it is easy to understand why: since `Do` holds its arguments, the function expansion defined above was used at every function's invocation.

#### Simple work-around: store a pure function in a variable

The simplest way to deal with this problem is to define a function separately, and store in a variable, like so:

```
fn = 
 Function[{{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}},
  If[a<d<g&&a/(10 b+c)+d/(10 e+f)+g/(10 h+i)==1,Print[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}]]];

Do[fn[i],{i,Permutations[Range[9]]}]//Timing

During evaluation of In[42]:= {5,3,4,7,6,8,9,1,2}
(*  {4.593750,Null}  *)
```

This however is not the most general way.

#### General way out: adding function-expanding macro

Another way would be to write a function-expanding macro. Here it is:

```
ClearAll[functionExpand];
SetAttributes[functionExpand, HoldAll];
functionExpand[code_] :=
   Unevaluated[code] /. f_Function :> With[{eval = f}, eval /; True]
```

It uses [Trott-Strzebonski](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/Links/index_lnk_30.html)  in-place evaluation technique, described also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633236/replace-inside-held-expression/6633334#6633334) (see also the answer of WReach there), and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/how-to-inject-an-evaluated-expression-into-a-held-expression/), to expand `Function` inside the code. With it, one can do:

```
functionExpand[
  Do[
    Function[{{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}},
      If[a<d<g&&a/(10 b+c)+d/(10 e+f)+g/(10 h+i)==1,Print[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}]]
    ][i],{i,Permutations[Range[9]]}
  ]
]//Timing

During evaluation of In[43]:= {5,3,4,7,6,8,9,1,2}
(* {4.546875,Null} *)
```

#### Compilation

Let me now show how one would compile the code obtain in this way. The recipe is very simple - use `functionExpand` again. So, for example:

```
compiled = 
  functionExpand[
    Compile[{{p, _Integer, 1}},
       Function[{{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}},
         If[a < d < g && a/(10 b + c) + d/(10 e + f) + g/(10 h + i) == 1, 
           {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, 
           {}
         ]][p]
    ]]
```

where I slightly changed the output so that we return rather than `Print`, and there are no calls to the main evaluator then. You can check that `compiled` contains only the byte-code instructions, so it all works. Now, this speeds things up quite a bit:

```
Do[If[compiled[p]!={},Print[p]],{p,Permutations[Range[9]]}]//Timing

During evaluation of In[36]:= {5,3,4,7,6,8,9,1,2}
(* {0.890625,Null}  *)
```

This is not the end of the story, however. One improvement would be to compile to C. Another improvement is to compile entire loop as well:

```
fullCompiled = 
  Compile[{},
     Do[If[compiled[p] != {}, Print[p]], {p, Permutations[Range[9]]}],
     CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
  ];
```

One can also test that,apart from `Print`, we get byte-code instructions again (note that the option `"InlineCompiledFunctions"` was used). So,

```
fullCompiled[]//Timing

During evaluation of In[49]:= {5,3,4,7,6,8,9,1,2}
(*  {0.312500,Null}  *)
```

Finally, we can also inline external definitions:

```
fullCompiledInlined = 
  Compile[{},
     Do[If[compiled[p] != {}, Print[p]], {p, Permutations[Range[9]]}],
     CompilationOptions -> {
        "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
        "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True
     }];
```

which gives another 2x speedup in this case:

```
fullCompiledInlined[]//Timing

During evaluation of In[50]:= {5,3,4,7,6,8,9,1,2}
(* {0.187500,Null} *)
```

So, we got a 20x speedup due to compilation. Compilation to C target would likely bring further speed enhancements.

What I've shown here is the workflow involving the overloaded `Function`, and ways to speed up and / or compile code using it.

Comment: It's deja vu all over again! :o)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard But this time, I think this method is even more on target. Apparently, I seem to have used a more elegant code-generation scheme in the destructuring answer, but have no time now to check and refine it here.

Comment: I agree it's on target and you got my vote. ( It's your main purpose in life after all. ;^) )

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yep, you got it right once again :). Thanks. You got my vote too, even before I started writing my answer.

Comment: Wha?? No preamble?

Comment: @rm-rf Just for you :-) But, wait... where is Hypnotoad? That's not a fair game.

Comment: Hehe, the hypnotoad got `rm -rf`ed =) (see my profile). I did grow very fond of that avatar though... (maybe a guest appearance some day)

Comment: @rm-rf You know, in light of recent name-changing activity / questions etc, you should write an M script which would randomly alternate between the your names / avatars and change them on SE. I wonder if your mod status gives you a way to work around the 30 days per name rule.

Comment: Yeah, I can bypass the 30 day rule as a mod (that's how I changed back... "Hypnotoad" lasted only for about 7-10 days), but account management via M or API won't be possible. I could maybe create an M oracle that "tells" me what the name/avatar should be and change it myself :P

Comment: @rm-rf It is always possible, if not always easy. Take an open source browser, modify the js engine so that Mathematica gets hooked up there, and imitate click events, or use something like [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)). Nothing you'll have to do will be too high a price for such a noble goal :)

Comment: Or, I can post a "How can I ..." question and wait for you to answer it =)

Comment: @rm-rf The idea of posting a question crossed my mind, but I did not suggest it to you :)

Comment: Performance tuning, code generation, dynamic environments, preamble, several links, and 99999 words of which the 2 most redundant are "Leonid Shiffrin". +1

Comment: Thanks, @Rojo :) The 99999 words in the most problematic part, have to do something with it. As for the preamble, this time it was ordered by rm -rf.

Answer (score 8):

It is not exactly equivalent for all inputs, but neither are your examples. Does this serve your purposes?

```
# /. {{x_, y_}, z_} :> x + y - z^2 &
```

Comment: `Function[{x}, Module[{a, b, c}, {a, b, c} = x; a + b - c]][{1, 3, 5}]` ?

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your intentions this may be a duplicate of [Mathematica Destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8382/121) but if not:

```
# + #2 - #3 & @@ {1, 3, 5}
```

Or

```
# + #2 - #3 & @@ # & @ {1, 3, 5}
```

And

```
Fold[
  Function[{x, y}, If[y < 5, {# ~Join~ {y}, #2}, {#, #2 ~Join~ {y}}] & @@ x],
  {{}, {}},
  Range[10]
]
```

Similar to Rojo's answer (and my answer to [Mathematica Destructuring](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8382/121)):

```
Fold[
  # /. {a_, b_} :> If[#2 < 5, {a ~Join~ {#2}, b}, {a, b ~Join~ {#2}}] &,
  {{}, {}},
  Range[10]
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Mr. Wizard already linked to my previous answer on [deconstruction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9759/1194), but I though I'd add a solution using it anyway, since it seems to translate almost directly from the function definition which might be what you are looking for:

First, I define a new function `dFunction` which is only applied if it can successfully deconstruct its arguments:

```
 SetAttributes[dFunction, HoldAll]
 dFunction[pattern_, body_][arg___] /; MatchQ[{arg}, pattern] := 
    {arg} /. pattern :> body
```

Then I add to the definition of `Function` that whenever it's first argument contains patterns, it should switch to `dFunction` since this is invalid syntax for `Function`, it shouldn't cause any trouble:

```
 Unprotect[Function];
 patternQ[expr_]:=Not[0===Length@Cases[expr,_Pattern,\[Infinity]]]
 Function[a_List/;patternQ[a],body_,attr___]:=dFunction[a,body,attr]
 Protect[Function];
```

Note that attributes are dropped. My most often used attribute `HoldAll` doesn't work nicely with `SubValues`, so I've haven't yet sat down and tried to think about getting attributes handled. 
Then your example two is simply solved by taking the pattern from your definition and inserting into Function:

```
  fun[{a_, b_}, y_] := If[y~Mod~2 == 0, {a~Join~{y}, b}, {a, b~Join~{y}}]
  Fold[fun, {{}, {}}, Range@10]
```

vs.

```
  Fold[
  Function[{{a_, b_}, y_}, If[y~Mod~2 == 0, {a~Join~{y}, b}, {a, b~Join~{y}}]]
  , {{}, {}}, Range@10]
```