# Define function using variable list

Tags: function-construction

I have a list of variables `variables={a,b}` and a list with values `values={1,2}`. I'd like to define a function using the variables in `variables` like so:

```
f=Function[variables,2a+b];
```

Then, I'd like to call it in a way like

```
result=f@@values
```

or

```
result=f@@variables/.(Rule@@@Transpose@{variables,values})
```

or something similar.

Is there a way to create a function where the names of the variables are in a given list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the question at face value you merely need to add `Evaluate`:

```
variables = {a, b};
values = {1, 2};

f = Function[Evaluate @ variables, 2 a + b];
f @@ values
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

However, I recommend that you keep the Symbols in a `Hold` expression rather than a `List` to prevent unwanted evaluation.  You will then need something like this to "inject" those values into the `Function`:

```
{a, b} = {"fail!", "fail!"}; (* prove it works even with a and b assigned *)

variables = Hold[a, b];
values = {1, 2};

f = variables /. _[vars__] :> Function[{vars}, 2 a + b];
f @@ values
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

Comment: Nice solution! I just got the solution of the other answer to work, so I won't change it now. What exactly is the pattern `_[vars__]`? (I suppose `_[]` matches the `Hold[]`, and `__` for the list of variables, because we want the whole list, not just one element.)

Comment: @Ragnar `vars__` is a pattern that represents an arbitrary sequence of expression named `vars` (see `BlankSequence` in the docs) -- it matches `a, b` in `Hold[a, b]`.  This sequence is then inserted in the place of `vars` on the right-hand-side of `:>` (`SetDelayed`), forming `Function[{a, b}, . . .]`.  See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121) for another example.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
ClearAll[def];
Attributes[def]={HoldAll};
def[f_Symbol,vars_List,body_] := With[{x=vars}, f = Function[vars,body]];
```

used as follows:

```
def[f, {a, b}, a + b]
```

to define the function f:

```
f @@ {1, 2}
```

> 3

Comment: That's a lot of stuff I don't know yet :) Let's test it...

Comment: It works when I remove the `HoldAll` line. Otherwise, I can't use `v={a,b}` as the second argument, because it will still be interpreted as a symbol instead of a list of symbols. Thanks!

Comment: You can read the reply by Leonid Shifrin to this post: [Pure Functions with Lists as arguments](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17671/pure-functions-with-lists-as-arguments/17675#17675), which contains much better material than mine

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I like your solution better, because it doesn't involve in-depth programming (and I have to show my code to my teachers, who wouldn't understand it easily I guess). Also, I changed `HoldAll` to `HoldFirst`, and added another definition, where `f` is not a symbol, which clears it before assignment.