# Function of a function using variable list

Tags: function-construction

My question is clarification for the question here [Define function using variable list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40445/define-function-using-variable-list)

With doing this

```
variables = {a, b};
f = Function[Evaluate@variables, 2 a + b];
```

I can define a function of the array of variables. Now, I would like to define a function `f2` which is a function of the previous one. Just writing

```
f2 = Function[Evaluate@variables, f1@@variables -2*a];
```

doesn't work. What is correct syntax for defining `f2`? I want to call it like `f2[1,2]` (and get 2 as an answer, obviously).

Comment: What is `f1` supposed to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add another `Evaluate` in the function body:

```
variables = {a, b};
f1 = Function[Evaluate@variables, 2 a + b];
f2 = Function[Evaluate@variables, Evaluate[f1 @@ variables - 2*a]];
```

Answer (score 3):

How about defining things directly:

```
f[{a_, b_}] := 2 a + b;
f2[{a_, b_}] := f[{a, b}] - 2 a;
```

then

```
f2[{1, 2}]
2
```

and

```
variables = {1, 2};
f2[variables]
```

gives the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the method I recommended in my answer to the Question you referenced:

```
variables = {a, b};

f1 = Function[Evaluate@variables, 2 a + b];
f2 = variables /. _[vars__] :> Function[{vars}, f1[vars] - 2*a];

f2[1, 2]   (* Out[]= 2 *)
```

As in that answer I would encourage the use of `variables = Hold[a, b];` for robustness, but I want to show that the `/. _[vars__] :>` form also works on a raw `List` in case that is a concern.

With the method above the created definition of `f2` is `Function[{a, b}, f1[a, b] - 2 a]`.  If instead you want full evaluation of the function body, and you don't need variable holding, you can do this instead:

```
Function @@ {variables, f1 @@ variables - 2*a}
```

> ```
> Function[{a, b}, b]
> ```

Or:

```
Function @@ {#, f1 @@ # - 2*a} &[variables]
```

> ```
> Function[{a, b}, b]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to use this question to promote the `ResourceFunction` [ExpressionToFunction](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ExpressionToFunction) I submitted recently, which is specifically designed to facilitate the creation of `Function`s from all sorts of expressions and to allow you to call them in a variety of ways.

Comment: Sjoerd Smit, Do you know if there is a functionality to achieve something like this `Function[{{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}}, {x1 - y1, x2 - y2}]` instead of `Function[{x1, x2, y1, y2}, {x1 - y1, x2 - y2}]`?

Comment: @E.Chan-López not with `Function` in that specific way. The closest thing would be `ResourceFunction["ExpressionToFunction"][{x1 - y1, x2 - y2}, {x1, x2} -> 1, {y1, y2} -> 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
variables = {a, b}; 
f1 = Function[Evaluate@variables, 2 a + b]; 
f2 = With[{f1 = f1, v = variables}, 
           Function[Evaluate@v, (f1 @@ v) - 2*a]]
```