# Define a delayed function with tested patterns for fitting

Tags: function-construction, fitting

This question is a variant of ["Define function using variable list"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40445/define-function-using-variable-list)

Fitting functions require a model function defined in terms of explicit symbols that should only evaluate given numeric inputs, and a list of those symbols. That is, the function needs to be SetDelayed, and the arguments must be tested patterns in the form of `_?NumericQ`.  An example is given in the Generalizations section of [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html).

```
data = {{6.47, 3.65}, {7.43, 3.45}, {3.9, -2.94}, {4.8, -1.29}, {2.48, -0.35}, 
{6.32, 3.16}, {2.59, -1.19}, {9.13, -2.}, {3.81, -3.04}, {3.33, -2.68}}; 

model[(a_)?NumberQ, (b_)?NumberQ, (c_)?NumberQ] := 
  Module[{y, x}, First[y /. NDSolve[{Derivative[2][y][x] + a*y[x] == 0, y[0] == b, 
   Derivative[1][y][0] == c}, y, {x, 0, 10}]]]

NonlinearModelFit[data, model[a, b, c][x], {a, b, c}, x, Method -> "Gradient"]; 
%["BestFitParameters"]

(* {a -> 1.04052, b -> 2.47, c -> 2.29708} *)
```

This is easy enough if you hard-code the function, but what if you do not know the function or symbols until runtime? For example, what if the model being fit is generated by other code? Lets say we have a piece of code elsewhere that generates the differential equation and parameter list:

```
diffeq = {Derivative[2][y][x] + a*y[x] == 0, y[0] == b, Derivative[1][y][0] == c}; 
params = {a, b, c};
```

Now we need to programmatically generate the model function to put into `NonlinearModelFit`. So far, this is the best solution I can find:

Define a function that will solve the given equations

```
solver[eq_] := Block[{y, x}, First[y /. NDSolve[eq, y, {x, 0, 10}]]]
```

Define a function that takes a list of valueless symbols and returns a list of tested patterns

```
numericPattern = Function[sym, sym:_?NumericQ, Listable];
```

Generate the function and test

```
Activate[
  Inactive[SetDelayed][
    genmodel @@ numericPattern[params], 
    Inactive[solver][diffeq]
  ]
]

Information[genmodel, "DownValues"]

(* genmodel[a:_?NumericQ, b:_?NumericQ, c:_?NumericQ] := 
solver[{a*y[x] + Derivative[2][y][x] == 0, y[0] == b, Derivative[1][y][0] == c}] *)

NonlinearModelFit[data, (genmodel @@ params)[x], params, x, Method -> "Gradient"]; 
%["BestFitParameters"]

(* {a -> 1.04052, b -> 2.47, c -> 2.29708} *)
```

This works, but seems awkward to me. I understand that there is no safety net here for symbols that have values, but I am assuming that we could not have gotten to this point if that were the case. I also do not understand this solution to the depth I would need to explain it to someone else. Is there something simple (or complicated) that I am missing, or a better solution anyone can suggest?

Comment: At least for this particular example, the modern way to go about it would be to use `ParametricNDSolve(Value)[]` along with indexed variables. Using the same data given in the OP: `model2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] + c[1] * y[x] == 0, y[0] == c[2], y'[0] == c[3]}, y, {x, 0, 10}, Array[c, 3]]; fm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Apply[model2, Array[c, 3]][x], Array[c, 3], x, Method -> "Gradient"]; fm["BestFitParameters"]`

Comment: @J.M.willbebacksoon Thanks for the tip. This particular example was only chosen as it was already documented and exemplary of my problem, but in detail bares little resemblance to my actual problem

Comment: I thought it had to have been a toy example, that's why it's a comment and not an answer. That being said, indexed variables might still be of interest for your actual problem.