# Define a function that returns a function with a variable number of arguments

Tags: function-construction, pure-function

Previously, I've defined a function with a variable number of arguments with the following method.

```
x = {x1, x2, x3};
f1 = Function[
  Evaluate[x],
  x + 1 //
  Evaluate
];
f1 @@ x
Output: {1 + x1, 1 + x2, 1 + x3}
```

Also, I've defined a function that returned a function as follows.

```
g[x_] := Function[
  {z},
  x + z //
  Evaluate
];
f2 = g @@ {z};
f2 @@ {x1}
Output: x1 + z
```

But when I attempt to put these ideas together, I have an issue. The hang-up seems to be in passing the argument of the first function to the argument of the second. Note that in our second example, above, we weren't passing `x` as an argument to the inner function. However, this is exactly what we want to do:

```
h[x_] := Function[
  Evaluate[x],
  x + 1 //
  Evaluate
];
f3 = h @@ x;
f3 @@ x
Output: h[x1, x2, x3][x1, x2, x3]
```

The desired output is `{1 + x1, 1 + x2, 1 + x3}`. My motivation for writing such a function is to bury it in a package.

Comment: Very closely related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17671/pure-functions-with-lists-as-arguments) (may be even a duplicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = {x1, x2, x3};

h[x_] := Function[Evaluate[x], x + 1 // Evaluate];
f3 = h@x
f3 @@ x

(* {1 + x1, 1 + x2, 1 + x3} *)
```

Comment: thanks! Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @RicoPicone: When you `Apply` (`@@`), think of it as basically turning your list into the *arguments* to the function. So in your example, you're trying to apply a function of *one* argument to *three*, so since it doesn't match, it returns unevaluated. In your next step, you're applying *that* to the list, giving you the `h[x1, x2, x3][x1, x2, x3]` nonsense. By changing your first operation to just `@` (function invocation), the *whole list* is passed as the argument, allowing a function of *three* arguments to be returned, so the following `Apply` matches it, presto. If not clear, comment!

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up. I had always been unclear on the difference between `@` and `@@`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will leak evaluation in cases where `x1`, etc. have prior values. But the real problem is how the question is formulated, because it is rather hard to partially evaluate the input to a list of symbols but not further. Put another way, what is asked for is a macro rather than a function, but Mathematica has no read-time, and so writing this sort of macros is hard, since macro-expansion gets mixed with evaluation.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, that's a good point. This was my way of trying to write *something* that generates a function with a variable number of arguments. Is there a better workaround?

Comment: @RicoPicone The biggest problem is that you store a list of variables in another variable. If you'd be fine with always supplying it explicitly, then the following modification of Rasher's solution would do: `SetAttributes[h, HoldAll]; h[vars:{___Symbol}]:=Block[vars, Block[vars, Function @@ {vars, vars + 1}]]`. If you want to store your variable list somewhere, the best thing to do is to store them in some `HoldAll` / `HoldAllComplete`-attributes-carrying container (e.g. `Hold[]`), and then redefine `h` to work as `h[Hold[sym___Symbol]]:=...`. Otherwise, it gets harder.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thanks, I like that advice. In my application it is convenient to define a list and make the entries of the list the arguments (and not the list itself) of a function because I will later differentiate that function with respect to its arguments. (I'm generating systems of pdes from these functions.) I like to write my routines to work for the n-variable case, which precludes explicitly specifying the inputs. If I can think of a simple way to explain my application and the nuances that arise, I'll try to ask it as a question.