# Define Function explicitely with List as argument

Tags: functions, argument-patterns

## Background

There are multiple ways to define `Function`s. I would assume all methods are equivalent, and allow for the same options. However, I fail to find the explicit equivalent of a `Function` with a `List` as an argument.

### SetDelayed on List

In particular, consider this implicit function. This allows you to fill in a list as an argument and immediate assigns variable names to the elements of the list:

```
func1[{a_,b_}]:=a+b
func1[{3,4}] (** 7 **)
func1[3,4] (** func1[3,4] **)
```

### Set on Two Arguments

Now, consider this explicit function. As defined this way, the function has two arguments and cannot deal with a list.

```
func2=Function[{a,b},a+b];
func2[{3,4}] (** Function::fpct **)
func2[3,4] (** 7 **)
```

### Set on List

Finally, attempt to define a new function with a list as an argument. Similar to above, we want the elements of this list to be assigned variable names directly. This does not work.

```
func3=Function[{{a,b}},a+b]; (** Function::flpar **)
func3[{3,4}] (** Function::flpar **)
func3[3,4] (** Function::flpar **)
```

## My Question

Is it possible to define a `Function` explicitly (using the syntax `fun=Function[listarg,body]` as in `func3`) and also directly assign names to the elements? If so, what is the correct syntax / pattern?

## Answer I am Not looking for

Please note that I realise there are many work-arounds, for example using `With`.

```
func4=Function[{x},With[{a=x[[1]],b=x[[2]]},a+b]];
func4[{3,4}] (** 7 **)
```

This is not the point of my question. I merely want to understand *Mathematica* syntax and patterns better.

## Answer I am looking for

**Why** is it possible to define `func1` using `SetDelayed` or `:=` and make it work directly on a `List`, but **not** using the syntax of `func3`. Perhaps there is no clear answer. Perhaps this is just the way *Mathematica* works, nothing more. But perhaps I am missing some fundamental understanding of `Patterns`. This is where I need help.

Comment: You could try `f[x_List]=...`

Comment: Note that I want `fun=Function[listarg,body]`. I call that 'explicit', perhaps there is a better name.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin So to sum up: No, there is no out-of-the-box equivalent of `func[{a_,b_}]:=a+b` in terms of `func=Function[{{a,b}},a+b]`. However, your answer in [Pure Functions with Lists as arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17671/pure-functions-with-lists-as-arguments) provides the best self-made work-around. Am I interpreting that correctly? If so, I will indeed close this question.

Comment: @LBogaardt Yeah, more or less. I can't attest to how good my answer is, since adding downvalues to `Function` is not the best thing in the world - it was more like an illustration. I would  still ask you to not delete the question - it can serve as a gateway to that other one, once we close it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]
```

The form that you request implies that the length of the list is known. If the length is known, then you can use `Part` to reference ("name")  the individual elements of the list.

```
f[x_List?(Length[#] == 3 &)] := (x[[1]] + x[[2]])/x[[3]]

f@Array[x, 3]
```

[image]

```
f@Array[x, 5]
```

[image]

Or if the length is at least three,

```
f[x_List?(Length[#] > 2 &)] := (x[[1]] + x[[2]])/x[[3]]

f@Array[x, 3]
```

[image]

```
f@Array[x, 5]
```

[image]

However, it generally would be better to define a function of a list using list operations so that the length of the list need not be a specific value.

```
f1[x_List] := Total[Most[x]]/Last[x]

f1@Array[x, #] & /@ Range[4]
```

[image]

Comment: How to define a function of more than two list operations? I.e. I want to give more than two arrays as an input variable to a function and also evaluate the function by assigning values to the array variables.

Comment: @Rakesh - post a question that includes a concrete example so that it is clear what you are trying to accomplish. Include the code for what you have tried and and data necessary.

Comment: I have posted the question here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291316/how-to-effectively-input-more-than-two-list-of-arguments-into-a-function