# How can I effectively input more than two list arguments into a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, argument-patterns, arguments

I am trying to input more than two list arguments into a function. For example, I have written the following code:

```
g[xList_, yList_] := 
 For[ϕ = 1;  j = 2, j <= 6, j++, 
  For[i = 1, i < j, 
   i++, ϕ = ϕ*((x[i])^2 + (x[j])^2 - (2*x[i])*(x[j])*Cos[y[i] - y[j]])]];

xList = Array[x, 6];
yList = Array[y, 6];
g[xList, yList]
ϕ
```

Here, each of `x[i]` and `y[i]` is a variable of the function `g`. However, in the above code, it seems that `g` is really not a function of `xlist` and `ylist` because by varying the list of arguments, I am not getting the desired output. In particular, I can't input a new set of list arguments `wlist=Array[w, 6]` , `zlist=Array[z, 6]` into the function `g`.

Is there a way to input two sets of list arguments as input variables to a function?

Comment: [Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/26598)

Comment: You appear to have some syntax errors.  To declare a variable as a specific type you need `x_List` not `xList_`. Next `Part` shorthand is with two square brackets; `x[[i]]` , not `x[i]`. You also have "side-effects" with `ϕ` as it is not localised; see `Module` for help.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a construct like

```
g[xList_, yList_] := ...
```

it is presumed that the symbols `xList` and `yList` will appear in the right hand side. That's sort of what it means to be an argument. Your definition for `g` doesn't reference `xList` or `yList`. You could have just written `g := ...` or `g[] :=`  and achieved the same thing.

The "arguments" that `g` does reference, `x`, `y`, `\[Phi]`, are not localized to `g`, so `g` operates via side effects. `g` also doesn't produce any output. So, `g` isn't really a function, but just a fancy way of assigning a constant expression to `\[Phi]`. So, really, you could have just written `\[Phi] = ...`.

But, of course, you aren't deliberately trying to just assign a value to `\[Phi]`, and you do want your `g` to depend on some arguments.

Here's an alternate definition that corrects these problems, but it's not particularly good style:

```
g2[x_, y_] :=
  Module[
    {\[Phi] = 1},
    For[j = 2, j <= 6, j++,
      For[i = 1, i < j, i++,
        \[Phi] = \[Phi]*((x[[i]])^2 + (x[[j]])^2 - (2*x[[i]])*(x[[j]])*Cos[y[[i]] - y[[j]]])]];
    \[Phi]]
```

Notice the double square brackets for accessing elements of a list. Now, `x` and `y` will take on the values of whatever arguments you pass in to `g2`.

One reason this isn't good stye is because of the "magic numbers" that show up in `j=2` and `i<=6`. These should really depend on the arguments. Also, you can probably avoid the `For` loops by using regular list-based operations. And there's the gratuitous `\[Phi]`. But, I didn't take the time to reverse engineer your code to apply these fixes.

Comment: Could you please tell what are the regular list based operations instead of "For"?

Comment: @Rakesh Have a look at guide/FunctionalProgramming. For your example, Table probably does what you want.