# How can I use variables instead of slots in DeleteCases?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Here is a toy example to illustrate my problem. I have a list of 3-tuples and I want to delete elements from this list that satisfy a condition shown below.

```
tuples = Tuples[{-1, -2, 3}, {3}];
DeleteCases[tuples, _?((#[[1]] + 2 #[[2]] + #[[3]] == 0) &)]
```

This works perfectly. However, because each element of `tuples` has this form `{a,b,c}` and symbols `a, b, c` have problem-specific meanings attached to them, the code would become more readable if written as follows:

```
tuples = Tuples[{-1, -2, 3}, {3}];
DeleteCases[tuples, _?((a + 2*b + c == 0) &)]
```

The motivation is that `a + 2*b + c == 0` is easier for a human to read and understand than `(#[[1]] + 2 #[[2]] + #[[3]] == 0`.

**Question** Is it possible to write this code using variables instead of slots?

Comment: If your problem has the same structure, you can use something like `Pick[tuples,Unitize@Total[Transpose[tuples]*{1, 2, 1}], 1]`

Comment: @BenIzd Or `Unitize[tuples . {1, 2, 1}]` for the selection vector.

Comment: Related: [pure-functions-with-lists-as-arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17671/pure-functions-with-lists-as-arguments)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
tuples = {{1, 1, -3}, {1, 2, 3}};

(* Solution 1: *)
DeleteCases[tuples, {a_, b_, c_} /; a + 2 b + c == 0]
(* {{1, 2, 3}} *)

(* Solution 2: *)
DeleteCases[tuples, _?(({a, b, c} |-> a + 2 b + c == 0) @@ ## &)]
(* {{1, 2, 3}} *)

(* Solution 3: *)
test[{a_, b_, c_}] := a + 2 b + c == 0  
DeleteCases[tuples, _?test]
(* {{1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Comment: nice, I probably go for test function as I have many conditions.

Comment: @hana And `Select` is a choice, too: `test2[{a_, b_, c_}] := ! a + 2 b + c == 0; Select[tuples, test2]`

Comment: Or with `Select[tuples, Not@*test]`

Answer (score 12):

`Pick` could also be useful:

```
Pick[tuples, Function[{a, b, c}, a + 2 b + c == 0] @@@ tuples, False]
```

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps (Thanks to comment/correction @BenIzd )

```
DeleteCases[tuples, _?(Apply@Function[{a, b, c}, a + 2 b + c == 0])]
```

is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that you can use Function like that.

Comment: @hana ……This answer is incorrect. 2nd argument of `DeleteCases` is not a function. Try `tuples = {{1, 1, -3}};`

Comment: `DeleteCases[tuples, _?(Apply@Function[{a, b, c}, a + 2 b + c == 0])]`

Comment: @xzczd I see, it doesn't remove anything.

Answer (score 8):

```
g[{a_, b_, c_}] := a + 2 b + c == 0
```

Using the operator form:

```
DeleteCases[x_ /; g[x]][tuples]
```