# How to put the result(and its specified variable) to clipboard

Tags: function-construction, syntax

I have a such custom function to do some complicated thing:

```
customFun[str_] := 
 Defer[StringJoin["abc",ToString[#]]&@*StringLength][StringDrop[str,{1,-1,2}]]
```

#### Case one

If one use it like this:

```
string = "adfjdlgkjfghfvnckdklgjfkg";
customFun[string]
(* ("abc" <> ToString[#1] &@*StringLength)["djlkfhvcdljk"] *)
```

I hope put the `("abc" <> ToString[#1] &@*StringLength)["djlkfhvcdljk"]` into clipboard

#### Case two

If one use it like this:

```
string = "adfjdlgkjfghfvnckdklgjfkg";
var = customFun[string]
```

I hope it will return

```
(*var= ("abc" <> ToString[#1] &@*StringLength)["djlkfhvcdljk"] *)
```

It mean I want to assign the **defer expression** to `var`.**In the meantime**,I want to put the `var=("abc" <> ToString[#1] &@*StringLength)["djlkfhvcdljk"]` into clipboard.How to achieve this?

Comment: what degree of front-end integration will you have? You could do something *supremely* hacky, but very easy using the way it applies `Format` and a very greedy `UpValues` pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hilariously twisted way I found for approaching the problem, but I think it's actually got it's good sides. More bad sides than good. But some good.

We're gonna treat your expression as totally inert and create a round-about delegator for it (pulling `cf` and `set` from the previous answer).

```
cf[str_] :=
  (CopyToClipboard@#; #) &@
   Defer[StringJoin["abc", ToString[#]] &@*StringLength][
    StringDrop[str, {1, -1, 2}]];
heldQ[s_Symbol] :=
  MemberQ[Attributes[s], HoldAll | HoldAllComplete];
heldQ[_] :=
  False;

customFunDelegate[head_, pre_List, value_, post_List] :=

  Replace[Hold[head, pre, post], {
    Hold[Set, {var_}, {}] :>
     With[{c = cf@value},
      (CopyToClipboard@Defer[var = c]; var = c)
      ],
    Hold[h_?heldQ, {a___}, {b___}] :>
     Block[{$$recursionProtected = True},
      h[a, customFun[value], b]
      ],
    Hold[Format, ___] :>
     cf[value],
    Hold[_, {a___}, {b___}] :>
     head[a, cf[value], b]
    }];
customFunDelegate~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
```

Basically `customFunDelegate` will be what actually does `customFun`, but since it's got the `DownValues` we can stick `UpValues` on `customFun` without fear!

```
$recursionProtected;
customFun /:

  HoldPattern[s_[pre___, customFun[v_], post___]] /; ! 
    TrueQ@$recursionProtected :=

  customFunDelegate[s, {pre}, v, {post}];
```

Now note that just with this your users won't generally see the effect of a bare evaluation:

```
In[1490]:= customFun["a"]

Out[1490]= customFun["a"]
```

But we can hack that in if you're sure they're using the FE:

```
In[1491]:= $Post := Identity

In[1492]:= customFun["a"]

Out[1492]= ("abc" <> ToString[#1] &@*StringLength)[""]
```

And this can still be held normally because of that hold protection we stuck in there:

```
In[1493]:= Hold@customFun["a"]

Out[1493]= Hold[customFun["a"]]
```

It's *super* convoluted, but then again, you're trying to circumvent the way the language works, so you an't expect too much.

Comment: When I run `myvar = customFun["adfjdlgkjfghfvnckdklgjfkg"]`,actually I expected to get a output like `myvar = ("abc" <> ToString[#1] &@*StringLength)["djlkfhvcdljk"]`,and put the output into clipboard

Comment: @yode Easily fixed. What I just did should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could first define these functions:

```
customFun[str_] := (CopyToClipboard@#; #) &@
 Defer[StringJoin["abc", ToString[#]] &@*StringLength][
 StringDrop[str, {1, -1, 2}]]

set[var_,f_]:= (CopyToClipboard@Defer[var = f]; var = f);
SetAttributes[set,HoldFirst];
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
customFun["adfjdlgkjfghfvnckdklgjfkg"]
(*(abc<>ToString[#1]&@*StringLength)[djlkfhvcdljk]*)

Paste[]
(*(abc<>ToString[#1]&@*StringLength)[djlkfhvcdljk]*)

var~set~customFun["adfjdlgkjfghfvnckdklgjfkg"]
(*(abc<>ToString[#1]&@*StringLength)[djlkfhvcdljk]*)

var
(*(abc<>ToString[#1]&@*StringLength)[djlkfhvcdljk]*)

Paste[]
(*var=(abc<>ToString[#1]&@*StringLength)[djlkfhvcdljk]*)
```

If you insist on using the = operator, then it might be possible to redefine the UpValues of customFun such that Set is replaced by set. This would require changing the attributes of Set. However, it is not always a good idea to mess with the behavior of Set (see [Alternative to overloading Set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/alternative-to-overloading-set)).

You can easily overload the SetDelayed operator though (I wouldn't recommend doing this):

```
customFun /: SetDelayed[var_, customFun[s_]] := 
  set[var, customFun[s]]

var2 := customFun["adfjdlgkjfghfvnckdklgjfkg"]
(*("abc" <> ToString[#1] &@*StringLength)["djlkfhvcdljk"]*)

var2
(*("abc" <> ToString[#1] &@*StringLength)["djlkfhvcdljk"]*)

Paste[]
(*var2 = ("abc" <> ToString[#1] &@*StringLength)["djlkfhvcdljk"]*)
```

Comment: The function is build for orthers,it would be better is `=`.

Comment: Set has attribute HoldFirst. This means that when you evaluate var = customFun[s] it will always evaluate the right side first. So customFun will never get to see what var is.

The only way I can think of is to Unprotect Set and change its attributes. However Set (=) is a very common function and doing this will cause a lot of issues (see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/alternative-to-overloading-set)

Comment: Yes,we can not do that

Comment: You can overload the SetDelayed operator is you want. Another alternative would be to modify $Pre to look for instances were Set[var,customFun[s]] is used and replace it with set.

Comment: The `#0` representative all the express.I don't know this symbol can help or not.Maye it can match the input

Comment: If you want your final input to be var = customFun[s], all you can change is the definition of customFun (not counting Set). In that case using #0 will not help, since it will only refer to customFun, not the whole expression.