# ReplaceAll inside an Iterator

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I'd like to apply a set of rules to an expression defining the iterators of the table, like this:

```
ExampleParameters = {x0 -> 0, xp -> 1}
Table[x,{x, x0 - 3*xp, x0 + 3*xp, xp} /. ExampleParameters]
```

The kernel returns the following error:

```
Table::itform: Argument {x, x0 - 3 xp, x0 + 3 xp, xp} /. ExampleParameters
 at position 2 does not have the correct form for an iterator.
```

Any ideas on how to generalize the table expression? Explicitly using

```
Table[x,ReplaceAll{x, x0-3*xp, x0+3*xp, xp}, ExampleParameters]]
```

leads to the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mathematica throws the error because `Table` has the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute which prevents the replacement from being performed before `Table` sees the iterator.  You can force evaluation using `Evaluate`:

```
Table[x, Evaluate[{x, x0 - 3*xp, x0 + 3*xp, xp} /. exampleParams]]
```

Alternatively, instead of `ReplaceAll`, use `With`:

```
With[{x0 = 0, xp = 1}, Table[x, {x, x0 - 3*xp, x0 + 3*xp, xp}]]
```

In similar situations I like to use a custom-defined `With`-like function that can take parameter lists.  I described this function [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/993/12) and I'm going to reproduce it in this answer as well for completeness:

```
ClearAll[withRules]
SetAttributes[withRules, HoldAll]
withRules[rules_, expr_] :=
  First@PreemptProtect@Internal`InheritedBlock[
    {Rule, RuleDelayed},
    SetAttributes[{Rule, RuleDelayed}, HoldFirst];
    Hold[expr] /. rules
]

withRules[exampleParams, Table[x, {x, x0 - 3*xp, x0 + 3*xp, xp}]]
```

Comment: Perfect, the `Evaluate[]` trick did the job - what would be the advantage of using WithRules instead?

Comment: @qdot What if you use those parameters in multiple places in the expression and can't place the `Evaluate` at the right position, or need to use a separate `ReplaceAll` for each?  In this case `With`/`withRules` is a lot more convenient.