# Dynamics and Block interfere

Tags: dynamic, scoping

As mentioned by [Albert Retey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/169/albert-retey) in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs#comment1375_569), we can unintentionally interfere with our dynamics as follows

```
x = 2;
Dynamic@Framed@
  Panel[x, "The value of Global`x is dynamically displayed below"]
Block[{x}, x = 1; Pause[1]; x]
```

> ```
> (*The value of Global`x is dynamically displayed below*)
> 1
> (*regular output*)
> 1
> ```

We can also interfere the other way around, which is perhaps even more troublesome, as follows

```
Dynamic[y = 1; 
  Framed@Panel[y, "This cell changes Global`y and displays it"], 
  UpdateInterval -> 0.1]
Block[{y}, y = 5; Pause[1]; y]
```

> ```
> (*This cell changes Global`y and displays it*)
> 1
> (*regular output, could be expected to be 5*)
> 1
> ```

A special case of the problems is highlighted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25673/4330), also by [Albert Retey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/169/albert-retey).

I had thought the advice about not using `Block`, e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/4330), referred to other problems that I figured I knew how to handle. It seems this particular behavior did not receive much attention.

Surrounding `Block` with `PreemptProtect` seems to mitigate these problems.

**Question**: Does consistently surrounding `Block` with `PreemptProtect` provide complete protection against this kind of interference?

Comment: Yes, I think so. For both examples, the explanation is that the update procedure for the Dynamic is started while the kernel is executing the Pause command, so it interrupts its task when the Pause is over and then returns the current value, i.e. the local value, to the frontend. Wrapping Block in PreemptProtect makes the kernel returning the current value of x when the evaluation of the Block is completed, so now it will return the value outside the Block.

Comment: @FredSimons yes, I agree with you, this is probably safe. But I figured I had better ask, before I discover I have been arrogant in ignoring advice again. Another method to protect yourself against this is to use contexts. It is good symbol management to put local variables in a in a separate context anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two examples you mention are easily understood from the way Dynamic updating works. Let us concentrate on `Dynamic[x]`. It is sent by the frontend to the kernel and the kernel returns it unevaluated to the frontend, together with the boxes in which the frontend will display. Then the front starts an update procedure over the preemptive link, asking the kernel for the value of `x`. So the kernel interrupts what it was doing, evaluates it and returns the value to the frontend.

The two examples strongly rest on the use of Block instead of Module; the variable inside Block is the same as inside Dynamic, so it is not surprising that interference may occur.

Example 1:

```
x = 2; Dynamic[x]
Block[{x = 1}, Pause[1]; x]
```

Here the update procedure starts when the kernel is evaluating the `Block` command. So the kernel completes the `Pause` and then returns the value 1 to the frontend. When the Block was wrapped in `PreemptProtect`, the kernel would first have competed the evaluation of the Block command and would then return the value of `x`, now again 2.

Example 2:

```
Dynamic[x = 1, UpdateInterval -> 0.1]
Block[{x = 5}, Pause[1]; x]
```

The frontend sends the expression `x=1` for updating to the kernel when the kernel is evaluating the `Pause` statement of the `Block` command. So when the Pause is over, the kernel sets `x` to `1` and sends that value to the frontend. Then it resumes the evaluation of `Block`, with the value 1 instead of 5.

When the Block was wrapped in `PreemptProtect`, this would not have happened.

I would like to add another similar example, with the scoping construct Table instead of Block.

```
x = 10; Dynamic[x]
Table[Pause[1]; x, {x, 1, 5}]
```

In the `Table` command, each second the value of `x` changes, so each second the kernel informs the frontend that it must start an update procedure and that is shown in the Dynamic display. But when the evaluation of the Table command is finished, no assignment is done to `x`, so the frontend is not informed that it has to start another update procedure, so the Dynamic will display 5 instead of 10. Of course, when we wrap Table in `PreemptProtect`, the updating takes place when `x` again has the original value 10, so it then looks fine. Nevertheless, even now there can be some interference. First evaluate this command:

```
x = 10; Dynamic[{x, RandomInteger[{1, 100}]}]
```

And then:

```
Table[Pause[1]; x, {x, 1, 5}] // PreemptProtect
```

During the execution of the above table, the kernel changes the value of `x` so it sends an update mesage to the frontend. The resulting update procedure by the frontend is now done when the construction of the Table is finished, so `x` will still be displayed as 10. But the random integer will be recomputed as well, so almost surely the display of Dynamic will change.

Edit: SUMMARY

The answer to the question is negative. Even when we wrap `Block` in `PreemptProtect`, there might be side effects. This is not restricted to `Block`; it applies to any scoping construct with dynamic scoping.

Suppose that we have a displayed `Dynamic[ expression(x) ]`, and that we have a scoping construct with a local variable `x` that uses dynamic scoping. Then the name `x` in Dynamic is exactly the same as the name `x` in the scoping construct. Whether or not the scoping construct is wrapped in `PreemptProtect`, changing the value of `x` in the scoping construct forces (by means of a kernel message) the frontend to start a, maybe unwanted, update procedure for `Dynamic[ expression(x) ]`, and this updating procedure may give a changed display of `Dynamic[ expression(x) ]`, as in the above example. The only effect of `PreemptProtect` is the time when the kernel executes the update call. Without `PreemptProtect` very likely during the evaluation of the scoping construct, otherwise when the evaluation of the scoping construct is finished.

On the other hand, when we wrap the scoping construct in `PreemptProtect`, the evaluation of the scoping construct cannot be influenced by preemptive calls, and therefore it will always return the expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I think the example with `Table` is really good, because it shows that we still may have to be careful even when we wrap all `Block`s in `PreemptProtect`. Again we can interfere both ways, so that the outcome of `Table` can be unexpected. I expect the same is true for `Do`. Perhaps you could edit your answer slightly to start with something like "No, the are other scoping constructs, for example `Table` that can also be interfered with in this way. You would have to wrap these in PreemptProtect as well."

Comment: I think this would be a good summary and a direct answer to the question. I will probably accept this answer either way.

Comment: I agree, again, that that is probably safe. I suppose the question is a bit vague. I also consider the interference with `Table` to be contained in "this kind of interference", but that was not very clear. I think your comment is very on topic so no need to delete it.

Comment: Also by "marking a message as temporary" I simply mean putting the text "(temporary message)" at the end of the message. The website does not have any support for temporary messages or anything like that. It is just a reminder for myself and for others that I mean to delete the message :).

Comment: In my opinion, these pathological, but highly instructive examples have more to do with the limitations of dynamic scoping than with interactive functions such as Dynamic. If I am not mislead by my memory, in Mathematica 2 the scoping construct Module was introduced to overcome unwanted behaviour of the scoping construct Block of Mathematica 1. For example, the following function  f[x_] := Block[{i = 2}, x^i] squares its argument. But when we happen to use the name of the local variable, we get an unwanted answer: f[i] returns 4. With Module, we indeed find i^2.

Comment: I agree that `Block` (/dynamic scoping) has limitations and that `Module` is an excellent scoping construct to have. Regardless, I think `Block` is also excellent and has many good uses. I think we should not compare the example in your last comment and the examples in this Q&A too much. My strategy for using scoping constructs is basically: "If the input of a function can not contain arbitrary (unevaluated) symbols, (it is safe to) use `Block`". `Block` has some advantages, one of which is easier debugging if you cause an interrupt inside a `Block`, as opposed to `Module`.

Comment: Ah, I see I did not fully get your meaning concerning your last example. Relying on updates to symbols to evaluate dynamic expressions at appropriate times is then also a problem, indeed! Nice find :).