# Dynamic fails to update after evaluating `Pause[]` within `Block`

Tags: dynamic, scoping

When evaluating this, the final value of `a` is `0` as it should be, but `Dynamic[a]` shows a `1`.

```
a = 0;
Dynamic[a]
Block[{a = 1}, Pause[1]; a];
(*1*)
```

When excluding all `Pause` calls, there is no bug.

```
a = 0;
Dynamic[a]
Block[{a = 1}, a];
(*0*)
```

Is it possible to force `Dynamic` to update without changing the value of `a`?

Comment: Have you seen `Refresh` as in `Dynamic[Refresh[a, UpdateInterval->0]]`?

Comment: I suppose it is closely related to "Rare in Practice:" part of Albert's answer in [How safe is the use of Block and Internal`InheritedBlock](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25934/5478)

Comment: It happens to me if I replace `Pause` with `Do[1, {10000000}];` -- I think it's a lengthy calculation that causes the system to update `a` when it is 1.

Comment: That one is better: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83035/5478

Comment: @Kuba I think that (Albert's answer) explains it.  And `Clear[a]` solves it.  Note that the second comes out `0` only because `a` is restored to `0` by the time the dynamic update executes.  It's possible that it won't always be `0`, I suppose, since there is a very small window between setting and restoring `a` (in the second example).