# How to use same cell for printing in a loop?

Tags: cells, procedural-programming, printing

I want to manually tag images.

For example, we prepare a list of images like

```
imgList = Table[Rasterize[i, ImageSize -> 50], {i, {a, b, c}}]
```

it gives

[image]

Now I made a loop like this

```
tagAssoc = <||>;
Do[
  Print[imgList[[i]]];
  tagAssoc[i] = Input[],
  {i, 1, Length@imgList}];
tagAssoc
```

Basically, in each loop, it print a image, then popup an input window for me to input the description of the image. All tag information is saved in `tagAssoc`. After loop finished, it looks like below

[image]

The print order of images should be reversed for better view and tagging. But this is not my concern. **Since I only need to see one image at a time, how to make this loop update the same cell with different images instead of print all images in different cell.**

Comment: Apparently you need `Dynamic`, not `Print`.

Comment: ..or use `PrintTemporary`?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Do you mean replace `Print` with `PrintTemporary`? But that does not work, it still outputs 3 images

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I feel stupid, but could you show me how to do it? : )

Comment: Example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270215/what-is-an-appropriate-setting-in-ndsolve-to-get-feedback-about-the-progress-of/270222#270222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple approach is to replace `Print` with `Dynamic` wrapped by `PrintTemporary`:

```
tagAssoc = <||>;
PrintTemporary[Dynamic[imgList[[i]]]];
Do[tagAssoc[i] = Input[], {i, Length@imgList, 1, -1}];
tagAssoc
```

... or even simpler, you can use `Monitor` instead as [Lukas Lang suggests in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271637/how-to-use-same-cell-for-printing-in-a-loop/271639?noredirect=1#comment678307_271639):

```
tagAssoc = <||>;
Monitor[Do[tagAssoc[i] = Input[], {i, Length@imgList, 1, -1}], imgList[[i]]]
tagAssoc
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solution. One thing I do not understand. I thought `i` is local variable in Do loop, how can it affect outside `i`?

Comment: @matheorem if you look at the documentation of [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) (specifically the second to last point in "Details"), you'll see that it effectively uses [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html), which implements dynamic scoping. As you can see in the documentation, this means that the global value of `i` is temporarily changed.

Comment: @matheorem It's an interesting question. As I understand, during evaluation of `Do` the scoped variable is changed globally, but after leaving the `Do` scope the variable is set up to the value it had before intering `Do`. But I can be slightly wrong in the details. It is worth to ask a separate question on it.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov you could probably use `Monitor` instead of manually combining `PrintTemporary` and `Dynamic`

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks, added to the answer.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thank you so much for pointing out the dynamic scoping of `Do`. I agree with you except that there is some subtle things happen after exiting the loop. I'd like to make a post on that : )

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you so much for `Monitor` solution, it is much suited for me : )

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Oh, it seems that someone already explain it https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83043/4742    Fred Simons mentioned when `Table` or `Do` finished, it does not inform the front end to update

Comment: @matheorem Thank you for the link, hadn't read it.