# Weird behaviour of If inside of Block definitions?

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, scoping

I am on Mathematica 9 and I have discovered, that, when I use `If` inside of the definitions of the `Block` variables, then other, previously defined `Block` variables don't seem to be replaced correctly in the second argument of `If`:

```
test[a_] = Block[{b = a, c = If[b > 0, b, 0]}, c]
```

Will return

```
If[a > 0, b, 0]
```

I would have expected it to return `If[a > 0, a, 0]`. Is this a bug? If not, can I understand, why this happens? Is there a general workaround for this?

PS: I'm not sure about the tagging for this question, maybe someone knows a better fitting tag.

Comment: @Kuba: I see. And I see why this would be useful for an `If`. I'm using `Piecewise` instead now, where everything gets evaluated.

Comment: My answer is quite dense, should be clear if you follow links though. But let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not, `a>0` isn't True or False so it does not evaluate subsequent arguments of If.

Also, notice that `c = If[b > 0, b, 0]` can't use `b = a` and the replacement happens when the body of `Block`, is evaluated, which is a subtle difference. Check the second link and related topics. See:

```
Block[{b = a, c = If[b > 0, b, 0]}, Hold[c] /. OwnValues[c]]
```

> ```
> Hold[If[b > 0, b, 0]]
> ```

A tip, unless you know you need `Block` you should not use it, it may have subtle implications. Use `With/Module`, check the first link to compare.

Also check the last link to understand `=` vs `:=`.

At the end I'd rewrite it:

```
test[a_] := Module[{b = a, c }, c = If[b > 0, b, 0]; c]
```

Further reading:

- [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/5478)
- [How to avoid nested With[]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10432/5478)
- [`=` vs `:=`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487)

Comment: I always preferred `Block` over `Module` and `With`, because I can do things like `f[x_] = Block[{a = x*x, b = 2x}, a + b]`. Would you say that I'm better off always using `Module` and doing `f[x_] := Module[{a,b}, a = x*x; b = 2x; a + b]`?

Comment: @Wauzl that is indeed useful but `Block` scopes 'more than you see', which is not generally a problem but can be. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25673/5478