# How to define a differential operator?

Tags: programming, function-construction

I have a linear differential operator, for instance, $L\left (\partial _{t}  \right )=\partial _{tt} - 3\partial _{t} + 2$. I use it in 2 different ways:

- apply the operator to a function: $L\left (\partial _{t}  \right )\sin(t)=-\sin(t)-3\cos(t)+2\sin(t)=\sin(t)-3\cos(t)$
- find roots of the polynomial $L(p)=0$, in this case $p=1,p=2$

What is the best way to define such operator?

Comment: You should include in your question your attempts to define such an operator. What have you tried ? In any case take a look at this post where a dalambertian was defined : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/using-d-to-find-a-symbolic-derivative/5441#5441. Perhaps you know there are in `Mathematica 9` new differential operators like `Div`, `Curl`, `Laplacian` etc.

Comment: I am new to Mathematica, so my only guess was to create 2 distinct functions, one behaving like differential operator, other like a polynomial. I was wondering if there was a way to write it in 1 statement.

Comment: The section "Some noncommutative algebraic manipulation" in the notebook at this [link](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/325/) might be useful for some of what you are trying to do. (probably not much help with factoring differential operators though).

Comment: A closely related question is [Having the derivative be an operator](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5030/245)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Define the operator as

```
op[t_]=(D[#,{t,2}]-3D[#,t]+2#)&
```

Then you get

```
op[t][Sin[t]]

(* -3 Cos[t]+Sin[t] *)
```

and also

```
op[t][Exp[p t]]/Exp[p t]//Factor

(* (-2+p) (-1+p) *)
```

where I have used that $\partial_t \exp(p t) = p\exp(p t)$ to "convert" the action of the operator $\partial_t$ into multiplication by $p$, and then I tidy up by dividing out the $\exp(p t)$ afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! Shame that it's a bit more complicated than I thought to get the roots of a polynomial, but that will work.

Comment: Try this: `op[x, t][Exp[p t] Exp[q x]]/(Exp[p t] Exp[q x]) // Factor`. The comment this addresses has disappeared. It was to do with how to handle the case where the operator depended on both t and x.

Comment: Oh, I deleted it because I came up with a solution `op[x,t][Exp[x t]]/Exp[x t]`, where I've actually gotten my polynomial, though with the variables that switched places. But your solution is much more generic, thanks again!

Comment: Re: your previous comment on getting the roots of a polynomial, `Factor` alone does that for you. The `Exp` trick/hack was for converting your particular operator-valued problem into an algebraic one, which `Factor` could then get to work on.

Comment: What is the purpose of the ampersand at the end of your first line of code?

Comment: `&` is shorthand for `Function`. This is illustrated in the documentation where the input `(3 + #) &[x]` gives the output `3 + x`.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for a variable number of iterations of the operator? Like applying a differential operator n times to a function?

Comment: `op[t][Sin[t]]` is equivalent to `Nest[op[t], Sin[t], 1]`, so `Nest[op[t], Sin[t], n]` applies the operator `n` times, where `n` is an integer 1,2,...

Answer (score 5):

The following slides are from a I talk I gave on implementing polynomial differential operators and teaching with them:
http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~is/talks/JMM2011.nb

Comment: Please consider adding some more information to your answer itself, should for example the `.nb` file become unavailable.  Answers that are merely single links to an external resource are discouraged, no matter how good that resource may be.