# Symbolic differentiation of an arbitrary function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I often work with expressions in one or more arbitrary function, and would like to get simplified expressions for their derivatives.

For example I would like to define the normal to a graph as follows

[image: normal to graph]

and then compute symbolically its derivatives, and second derivatives etc. WITHOUT specifying the arbitrary function u.

Thank-you for any help.

PS. Apologies if my question has been asked before, I was not able to find an answer on the site yet.

EDIT: this is the error I get trying to naively differentiate

[image]

Comment: like: [How to define a differential operator?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15605/5478)?

Comment: @Kuba thanks, but this seems to be something different, my main question is how to define and simplfy expressions in an arbitrary function (u in the above example). i am afraid it is quite an elementary question

Comment: I see, missed that. Try `Block[{u}, n[x_, y_] = .... // SimplifyOrSomething` notice no `:=`.

Comment: What do you mean by symbolically computing derivatives without specifying `u`? What is wrong with `D[n[x, y], x]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll I've tried this, see the error in my now editted answer. Kuba I am getting a similar error using Block

Comment: This should be a duplicate. You want to do either `Derivative[1,0][n][x,y]` or something like `Block[{x, y}, D[n[x,y], x]]`. I prefer the former.

Comment: You have definitions for `x` and `y` lingering

Comment: @CarlWoll thank-you, using block for {x,y} made a difference, but my result still has .5's floating around in all of the arguments, could you explain this?

Comment: As @MariusLadegårdMeyer says, you have lingering definitions for `x` and `y`. Just `Clear[x, y]` and try again.

Comment: Ah, many thanks for your help! I am still very much a novice with mathematica.