# How to define custom differential operator using the arguments of the expression?

Tags: function-construction, programming

This is essentially a follow-up to the question/answer here: [How to define a differential operator?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15605/how-to-define-a-differential-operator)

Suppose I wish to define an operator `DiffOp`, e.g.,

```
DiffOp[t_]:=D[#,t]+4t D[#,{t,2}]&;
```

but in such a way that the function can read in the argument without having to state it explicitly. Can this be done? If so, how?

In code, what I'd like (using the example above) is a definition that would give

```
DiffOp[f[x]]

(* f'[x]+4x f''[x] *)
```

and

```
DiffOp[x^2+Sin[x]]

(* 10x+Cos[x]-4x Sin[x] *)
```

Note that I'm not explicitly calling the function as `DiffOp[x][...]`.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I changed the example expression to be more complicated to test.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
diffOp[a_] := Module[{sym},
  sym = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[a, _Symbol, Infinity];
  If[
   Length@sym == 1,
   Return[D[a, First@sym] + 4 First@sym D[a, {First@sym, 2}]]
   ]
  ]
```

then

```
diffOp[y^2 + Sin[y]]
```

> `2 y + Cos[y] + 4 y (2 - Sin[y])`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the undocumented internal function `` Reduce`FreeVariables `` to determine the free variables:

```
DiffOp[expr_] := Replace[Reduce`FreeVariables[expr],
    {
    {} -> expr,
    {x_} :> D[expr, x],
    x_List :> D[expr, {x}]
    }
]
```

A couple examples:

```
DiffOp[x^2+Sin[x]]
DiffOp[x^2+Sin[Subscript[y, 1]]^2]
```

> 2 x + Cos[x]
>
> {2 x, 2 Cos[Subscript[y, 1]] Sin[Subscript[y, 1]]}

The latter example shows that `` Reduce`FreeVariables `` thinks that subscripted variables can be free variables as well as just ordinary symbols.

Comment: What exactly does ``Reduce`FreeVariables`` do?  I seem to be getting drastically different results for these two similar expressions: ``Reduce`FreeVariables[
f[g[d[rho]],g[d[s[rho, m, n]]]]*(-x[0,a^2,u,v,m]-2*a*x[1,a^2,u,v,m])]`` versus ``Reduce`FreeVariables[
f[g[d[rho]],g[d[s[rho, m, n]]]]*(-x[0,a^2,u,v,m]-2*x[1,a^2,u,v,m])]``.