# Checking what a function depends on

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, conditional

I'd like to define specific partial derivative operators that change based on if the passed expression is a function of, for example, `x` vs. `xi`. I'm not finding anything in the documentation on how to code a check for the expressions dependence. My question is, if given some function `f[x,y]`, how can I check the variables that it depends on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define custom differential operator using the arguments of the expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165648/how-to-define-custom-differential-operator-using-the-arguments-of-the-expression)

Comment: I think it should be possible to also use `DownValues[f]` to find what the function depends on, since the `DownValues` has the function signature right there.  It just needs to be parsed out and to extract all the symbols from inside `f[x_,y_,....]` and this part might be tricky to do. `?DownValues`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps `` Internal`DependsOnQ ``:

```
h = f[x, g[y]];
Internal`DependsOnQ[h, #] & /@ {x, y, g[y], w}
```

> {True, True, True, False}