# How to define a differential operator in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, operators, differentials

I want to define an operator $(\partial_{t}+1)^{2}=\partial_{t}\partial_{t}+2\partial_{t}+1$. Then, I want it to act on $t$. My code looks like this:

```
op[t_] := (D[#, {t, 1}] + 1 #)^2 &
op[t][t]
```

Instead of giving $2+t$, its result is $(1+t)^{2}.$ To verify if $2+t$ is really the answer, I write the right-hand side of the operator in Mathematica. My code looks like this:

```
op[t_] := (D[#, {t, 2}] + 2*D[#, {t, 1}] + 1 #) &
op[t][t]
```

And, it gives $2+t$. I want to write the exponent explicitly because I plan to extend it to $5$ (instead of $2$), and act it on another function. Can someone help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: I apologize. It should be $(\partial_{t}+1)^{2}t=2+t$.

Comment: $(\partial_{t}+1)^{2}t=(\partial_{t}^{2}+2\partial_{t}+1)t= (\partial_{t}^{2}t+2\partial_{t}t+t)=(2+t)$

Comment: @CarlWoll, I actuallly referred to [How to define a differential operator?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15605/how-to-define-a-differential-operator), but, still, my operator does not give the correct answer.

Comment: What is meant by *"act it on another function"* and *"act on"* (in this context)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, what I meant by *"act on"* is the usual operation done by a differential operator on a function. And *"act it on another function"* means using *another function* instead of the function *t*. I hope this clarifies your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use composition, not powers:

`op := (D[#, {t, 1}] + #) &`

`op[t]`

`Out[86]= 1 + t`

`op[op[t]]`

`Out[87]= 2 + t`

`Composition[op, op]@t`

`Out[97]= 2 + t`

`Apply[Composition, Table[op, 5]]@(t^5)`

`Out[99]= 120 + 600 t + 600 t^2 + 200 t^3 + 25 t^4 + t^5`

`Expand[(x + 1)^5]`

`Out[101]= 1 + 5 x + 10 x^2 + 10 x^3 + 5 x^4 + x^5`

Comment: Off topcic note: to play with it one needs to copy it and manually drop/delete `In[85]` and friends. Consider not pasting them and insert output as e.g. commented code or quoted block (`> `)

Comment: Thank you. I think this is better.

Answer (score 7):

*(From my answer to the linked question)*

Install the `DifferentialOperator` paclet with:

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/carlwoll/DifferentialOperator/releases/download/0.1/DifferentialOperator-0.0.1.paclet"]
```

and load with:

```
<<DifferentialOperator`
```

The paclet defines an input auto replacement for a special partial character, which you must use instead of the normal `\[Partial]` character. Specifically, you must enter <kbd>p</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> and not <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. Then, you can define a differential operator and apply it to a function as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But, I don' understand why I get $0[t]$ instead of $2+t$.

Comment: @RaymartJay Assuming you loaded my paclet, then you should use `pd`, not `esc pd esc` to enter the partial symbol.

Comment: @CarlWoll, I am using your paclet for a project of mine and I am wondering if you put a built in function to make a change of variable in the differential operators ?

Comment: It's not clear how to enter the pd command