# Definition of differential operators

Tags: operators, pure-function

I am curious how differential operators are defined in Mathematica. More specifically, if the Laplacian function wasn't available, how would one go on to define such a function in Mathematica directly without reference to Grad or Div? I am thinking of pure functions, but I haven't been able to reproduce the effect of the Laplacian.

Comment: At the end of this answer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/using-d-to-find-a-symbolic-derivative/5441#5441 you can find a definition of the d'Alembertian operator, for the Laplacian one can proceed analogically.

Comment: @Artes Thank you for the interesting link. Reading more about `Derivative`, I see that Mathematica tries to convert this to a pure function such as `D[f[#],{#,n}]&` . That was what I was trying to achieve directly.