# Products of Differential Operators

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, syntax, operators

I have a differential equation defined as the product of operators which I want to expand out into a polynomial in powers of $z\frac{d}{dz}$

$\qquad \prod_{n=1}^p(z\frac{d}{dz}+a_n)$

However when I try to code this using the D[#,x]& function it doesn't multiply out as I would wish it to. Instead each derivative just acts on the z rather that than $z\frac{d}{dz}$ and the whole thing just reduces to a number.

Do I need to define some special properties of an operator $z\frac{d}{dz}$?

I have considered trying to nest the operator but I am quite inexperienced and don't fully grasp how to do this whilst preserving the integrity of the operator.

Comment: You can mark $z \frac{d}{dz}$ as $x$ and expand it as a regular polynomial since powers of $x$ commute with each other. However it will be interestion to find the general solution.

Comment: You should use `Derivative` instead of `D` and when defining that operator use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) rather than `Set`. Examine e.g. this answer [Using D to find a symbolic derivative](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/using-d-to-find-a-symbolic-derivative/5441#5441).

Comment: There is a section in the notebook located [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262223580_Symbolic_FAQ) that discusses ways to work with products of differential operators.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Fold`, e.g.

```
q[f_, x_, a_] := Expand@Fold[ x D[#1, x] + #2 #1 &, f, a];
```

Or rule replacement of polynomial as suggested in comment:

```
fun[f_, x_] := x D[f, x]
op[n_, f_, x_] := Nest[Expand@fun[#, x] &, f, n]
w[f_, x_, a_] := Module[{v, pol, r},
  pol = Expand[Times @@ (v + # & /@ a)];
  r = pol /. {Times @@ a -> (Times @@ a) f, v -> x D[f, x], 
     v^(s_) :> op[s, f, x]};
  Expand[r]]
```

For example:

```
ar = Array[a, 4];
Grid[Table[{q[h[x], x, ar[[1 ;; j]]], w[h[x], x, ar[[1 ;; j]]]}, {j, 
   2, 4}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]