# Nesting differential operators

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, iteration

Suppose I define differential operators $d=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $L=g(x)d^4$ (so that $L(f)=g(x)(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^4f$ ) and I want to expand the differential operator $L=a_0+a_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ a_2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \cdots$. I tried doing the following but it doesn't work.

```
d[f_] := x D[f,x]
g[x_] := 2 x
L[f_] := g[x] Nest[d,f,4]
Expand[L[g[x]]]
```

Comment: Maybe a starting point: `d[f_] := # Derivative[1][f][#] &`.

Comment: Fourth Derivative is D[f[x],{x,4}]

Comment: It seems that everything is correct. L[g[x]] == L[2 x] == 4 x^2, because g[x] is defined to be 2x. Expand[L[h[x]] looks like what you expected.

Comment: Section "Some noncommutative algebraic manipulation" [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262223580_Symbolic_FAQ) might have usable approaches.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71643/products-of-differential-operators

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think you want:

```
ClearAll[d, g, L];
d[f_] := x D[f, x]
g[x_] := 2 x
L[f_] := g[x] Nest[d, f, 4]
exL = Evaluate[Expand[L[#[x]]]] & /.
  Derivative[k_][#][x] :> D[#, {x, k}]
```

> [image]

The replacement `Derivative[k_][#][x] :> D[#, {x, k}]` changes the argument `#` from representing a pure function to representing an expression.  This seemed unavoidable because if we had used `L[#]`, then `D[#, x]` would be zero; but in `L[#[x]]`, `D[#[x], x]` would be correct.

If you want the coefficients:

```
Block[{D = $f^#2[[2]] &},
 CoefficientList[First@exL, $f]
 ]
```

> ```
> {0, 2 x^2, 14 x^3, 12 x^4, 2 x^5}
> ```

Compare applications:

```
L[Exp[a x]] // Expand
exL[Exp[a x]]
```

> [image]

Here's a refactoring with the parameters as arguments:

```
ClearAll[d, g, L];
d[x_][f_] := x D[f, x]
L[f_, g_, x_] := g Nest[d[x], f, 4]
exL = Evaluate@Expand[L[#[x], g[x], x]] & /. 
  Derivative[k_][#][x] :> D[#, {x, k}]
```

> [image]