# Need help with computing symbolic derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

Imagine you are trying to get an equation of motion (in my case, the Lagrangian of a coupled drives CE108 system).

In such a case, you need to symbolically define certain derivatives as themselves, not as their value (i.e. D[x] = x' instead of D[x] = 1).

Is there any way within Mathematica to derive completely symbolically?

Complicated Example:

```
f = x' + mx + 7y
SymbolicDerivative[f,x] = x'' + mx'
```

Edit regarding duplication:
This question tries to find a way to partially derive a function symbolically continuously - meaning, derive x to x' and then x'' and then x''' and so forth rather than trying to derive a function and plug values in

Comment: `D[x[t],t]` returns `x'[t]` as you need. Have a look into Help/WolframDocumentation/D.

Comment: Take a look at e.g. [Using D to find a symbolic derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/using-d-to-find-a-symbolic-derivative/5441#5441)

Comment: Both are helpful, thanks Artes and Alexei! However, the question is about finding a derivative or partial derivative of an entire function with respect to, say, x in a way that returns, for example, x' from x, not about expressing x' (which was a very helpful tip Alexei, thanks again)

Comment: There's `VariationalD` to get the variational derivative. Also worth to have a look at `EulerEquations`, which derives the Euler-Lagrange equations for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using total derivatives (`Dt`) and defining additional constraints:

```
f=Dt[x]+m x+7 y
Dt[f] /. {Dt[m] -> 0, Dt[y] -> 0}
(* output -> m Dt[x] + Dt[Dt[x]] *)
```

In short, take the total derivative of `f`, and then hold every variable but `x` constant.

An automatic function for doing this process is provided below:

```
symD[f_, x_] := Module[{y, r},
r = Dt[f];
y = #[[1 ;; -2]] & /@ Position[r, Dt];
y = Part[r, Sequence @@ #] & /@ y;
y = DeleteDuplicates[Pick[y, Length[#] == 1 & /@ Dimensions /@ y]];
y = Select[y, Not[#[[1]] === x] &];
y = # -> 0 & /@ y;
r /. y]
```

It takes the total derivative and then assumes that all variables aside from the one entered as `x` have a total derivative equal to 0.

Note however that in most situations it's far more practical to define x as a function of another variable and take the derivative with respect to that.