# Differentiating with D vs. Derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, symbolic

I was tinkering with something and needed a high-order derivative of a function that, when differentiated, needs the product rule (and so, subsequent derivatives - without simplification - become messy).

I was trying to sort of get a nice one liner without typing too many "prime" symbols or doing anything tricky (trying to share code with students who don't all have serious Mathematica experience), but I couldn't really sort out some subtle difference between `D` and `Derivative`.

So here's my minimal working example that is confusing me:

```
f[x_] = (x + 1) (x - 3) (x + 2) (x - 5)/((x + 10) (x - 12) (x + 13));
n = 10;
AbsoluteTiming[Derivative[n][f][0]]
AbsoluteTiming[g[x_] = D[f[x], {x, n}]; g[0]]
AbsoluteTiming[ ToExpression["f" <> StringJoin @@ Table["'", {n}] <> "[0]"] ]


(* Out[]= {0.109908, 618976254473740800} *)
(* Out[]= {0.001136, 618976254473740800} *)
(* Out[]= {0.119808, 618976254473740800} *)

(* output with n=20 *)
{4.06785, 4754242157890032492148882597005066240000}
{0.0179687, 4754242157890032492148882597005066240000}
{4.5623, 4754242157890032492148882597005066240000}
```

I suppose this means the `f'''''''` construction does about the same as `Derivative`, but how is it that I'm having so much more efficiency with `D` instead?

Comment: A related question [Using D to find a symbolic derivative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/using-d-to-find-a-symbolic-derivative).

Comment: Try `Trace[...]`.

Comment: "I suppose this means the `f'''''''` construction does about the same as `Derivative`". Not "about the same", they're the same i.e. `'` is the shorthand of `Derivative`. Try `f''''''' // Hold // FullForm`.

Comment: @xzczd Agreed, but what's the reason for the significant difference in timing?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Honestly speaking, I don't know. I didn't know there's such a big difference in performance before reading this question. (Already +1. ) Even more surprising: `ff = x |-> (x + 1) (x - 3) (x + 2) (x - 5)/((x + 10) (x - 12) (x + 13)); AbsoluteTiming[Derivative[n][ff][0];]` takes about 40 seconds on 2GHz laptop! Tested in _v12.3._ Let's report this to WRI.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The trace for the slower ones uses `System'Private'DerivativeX` while setting `g[x_]=D[f[x],{x,n}]` uses `\[PartialD]`. I'm not really sure how to interpret `Trace` objects though. @xzczd How would we do that? I don't know much about that either.

Comment: One of the traces is really, really long compared another one, which explains in part why it takes longer. (Another factor is how long each step takes.) `Length@Flatten@Trace[<derivative code>, TraceInternal -> True]` is approximately how many steps are taken, although "step" is not a clearly defined unit (steps are not pairwise equivalent).

Comment: One can only @ one member in one comment. (Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/284701 ) As to bug reporting, it can be done in: https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback (You can find this in _Mathematica_ menu Help -> Give Feedback )