# How can I implement object oriented programming in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, meta-programming, design-patterns, object-oriented

Roman Maeder's object oriented programming package is nice, but I'm hoping someone can suggest a sleek and novel implementation that is easy to use.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what functionality of OOP you'd most like to implement in Mathematica?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7363253/615464

Comment: OO is a moving target, as is nicely summarized [here](http://www.paulgraham.com/reesoo.html), so you first need to define which set of features you call OO (as noted already by @Jagra). Implementing some basic OO by itself is not very difficult, but you will face some pretty hard to solve problems, such as performance and garbage collection.  In [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica/991#991), I dwell a little more on this topic and link to some previous discussions on the matter, which you may find of some interest.

Comment: Some interesting discussions in this topic can be found on MathGroup. [Here is a recent one](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/K91BE35WM7A/discussion).

Comment: Here is the answer to you long waiting for OOP in Mathematica. Please visit to my article page ["OOP environment for Mathematica without additional packages"](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/897081).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, one obvious idea would be to build on the [struct implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6069/129) by Bob Beretta. You would have to add information about methods and modify the implementation of `-->` to consider those as well, and for polymorphism, you'd also have to store the base class (or base classes, if multiple inheritance should be supported), and have `-->` look there if the field or method is not found.

Answer (score 16):

Here's I think my 5th version of this type of thing. I've got another framework for this [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-ObjectFramework) whose construction I explained [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/home/a-fake-object-framework.html#main-content).

The package version of this lives [on GitHub](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/raw/master/SymbolObjects.wl), which you can load by:

```
Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/raw/master/SymbolObjects.wl"]
```

### Why do this again

OOP is overdone (well, over-emulated) in Mathematica. Personally I've done this upwards of 5 times in some capacity, each with different levels of sophistication and memory footprint.

This time I wanted to have a very light-weight, robust implementation that doesn't affect any part of the system at all.

### Basic Setup

#### Core idea

The driving principle behind this was to effectively make my objects [`Associations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) (hash maps), but encapsulated in a mutable `Symbol` with accessors and things to make them really feel like an `Association`.

To do this I picked a primary `Head` to wrap my `Symbols` which I called `SObj` and it was pretty much straightforward from there.

I'm going to omit parts of this that don't really give us much. Follow along by looking at the package if you want the entire story. It's ~500 LOC and I don't want to copy the entire text here.

#### Constructing a new object

The first thing I needed to do was build a constructor function, which I called `SObjNew`:

```
SObjNew[
   name : _String | Automatic : Automatic,
   templates : {___String} : {},
   a : _Association : <||>
   ] :=
  With[
   {
    symbol =
     Unique[
      c <> "$Objects`" <>
       If[StringQ@name, name, "SObj"] <>

           "$"
      ],
    state =
     Merge[
      {
       "ObjectID" -> CreateUUID["sobj-"],
       a,
       Lookup[$SObjTemplates,
        Prepend[
         templates,
         If[StringQ@name, name, "Object"]
         ], 
        {}
        ],
       "ObjectType" -> 
        If[StringQ@name, name, "Object"],
       "ObjectTemplates" -> templates
       },
      First
      ]
    },
   SetAttributes[symbol, Temporary];
   symbol = state;
   SObj[symbol]
   ];
```

The main things to note here: we use [`Unique`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unique.html) to build a new `Symbol` in a specific context. We give that `Symbol` the attribute [`Temporary`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Temporary.html) so it can automatically be garbage collected.

There's also stuff for managing templates (essentially classes, but with a different sort of inheritance mechanism so I didn't want to call them that).

#### Defining accessor functions

Since we want this to work like an `Association` we need to support a bunch of different types of attribute lookups. Primarily we'll support `[]`, `[[]]`, `Extract`, and `Lookup`. These give us the broadest coverage:

```
(*
SObjAccess[___]:
Basic [___] wrapper for SObj
*)
SObjAccess[
  o : SObj[s_Symbol],
  k__
  ] :=
 If[$SObjGetDecorate, SObjGetDecorate[o, #] &, Identity]@
  s[k]
(*
SObjPart[___]:
Part wrapper for SObj
*)
SObjPart // Clear
SObjPart[
   o : SObj[s_Symbol], 
   k : _Span | _List
   ] :=
  If[$SObjGetWrap, SObj, Identity]@Evaluate@
    s[[k]];
SObjPart[
   o : SObj[s_Symbol], 
   k__
   ] :=
  If[$SObjGetDecorate, SObjGetDecorate[o, #] &, Identity]@
   s[[k]];
(*
SObjExtract[___]:
Extract wrapper for SObj
*)
SObjExtract // Clear
SObjExtract[
   o : SObj[s_Symbol], 
   k : {_List} | Except[_List]
   ] :=
  If[$SObjGetDecorate, SObjGetDecorate[o, #] &, Identity]@
   Extract[s, k];
SObjExtract[
   o : SObj[s_Symbol], 
   k_
   ] :=
  If[$SObjGetWrap, SObj, Identity]@Evaluate@
    Extract[s, k];
SObjExtract[
   o : SObj[s_Symbol], 
   k_,
   h_
   ] :=
  If[$SObjGetDecorate, SObjGetDecorate[o, #] &, Identity]@
   Extract[s, k, h];
(*
SObjLookup[___]:
Lookup wrapper for SObj
*)
SObjLookup[
   o : SObj[s_Symbol], 
   k_
   ] :=
  If[$SObjGetDecorate, SObjGetDecorate[o, #] &, Identity]@
   Lookup[s, k];
SObjLookup[
   o : SObj[s_Symbol], 
   k_,
   d_
   ] :=
  If[$SObjGetDecorate, SObjGetDecorate[o, #] &, Identity]@
   Lookup[s, k, d];
SObjLookup[
   o : {__SObj},
   k_
   ] :=
  If[$SObjGetDecorate, SObjGetDecorate[o, #] &, Identity]@
   Lookup[SObjSymbol /@ o, k];
SObjLookup[
   o : {__SObj},
   k_,
   d_
   ] :=
  If[$SObjGetDecorate, SObjGetDecorate[o, #] &, Identity]@
   Lookup[SObjSymbol /@ o, k, d];
```

You'll notice two weird parameters here, `$SObjGetDecorate` and `$SObjGetWrap`. The first of these handles a special type of attribute I called an `SObjMethod`. `SObjGetDecorate` automatically binds these to the instance they were extracted from. It's a convenience, but can be inefficient, so we allow it to be turned off. The latter handles the fact that we want these to act like `Association` and when you do `<|1->2, 2->3, 3->4|>[[2;;]]` you get an `Association` back. By analogy we should expect to get an `SObj` out when we do `obj[[2;;]]`.

#### Defining setter functions

`Association` supports a few different setting methods, `a[___]=val`, `a[[__]]=val`, and `AssociateTo[a, rules]`. We want to support all of them for flexibility. Happily this is pretty easy as we just delegate to the held `Symbol`:

```
(*
SObjSet[___]:
Set wrapper for SObj
*)
SObjSet[SObj[s_], prop_, val_] :=
  s[prop] = val;
(*
SObjSetPart[___]:
Set Part wrapper for SObj
*)
SObjSetPart[SObj[s_], part__, val_] :=
  s[[part]] = val;
(*
SObjAssociateTo[___]:
AssociateTo wrapper for SObj
*)
SObjAssociateTo[SObj[s_], parts_] :=
  (AssociateTo[s, parts];);
```

And with this we've defined the core of our lower-level interface.

### Setting up a good object type

This is where the bulk of the fun starts. We'll want our `SObj` object to delegate to all those methods we just defined in the right cases.

#### Constructor

First we define a constructor case:

```
SObj[
   name : _String | Automatic : Automatic,
   templates : {___String} : {},
   a : _Association : <||>
   ] :=
  SObjNew[name, templates, a];
```

#### NoEntry

Then we'll do a funky thing, since we're going to want our `SObj` to look atomic, we'll make sure that if it's a valid object it's got [`` System`Private`NoEntryQ ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139974/38205).

```
o : SObj[s_Symbol] /; (
   System`Private`EntryQ[Unevaluated@o] &&
    SObjSymbolQ[s]
   ) :=
 (System`Private`SetNoEntry[Unevaluated@o]; o)
```

#### Property access

Then we define our property access, mostly via `UpValues`:

```
(o : SObj[s_Symbol]?SObjQ)["Properties"] :=
  SObjKeys@o;
(o : SObj[s_Symbol]?SObjQ)[
   i__
   ] :=
  (SObjAccess[o, i]);
SObj /: Lookup[SObj[s_Symbol]?SObjQ, i__] :=
  (SObjLookup[s, i]);
SObj /: Part[o : SObj[s_], p___] :=
  (SObjPart[o, p] /; SObjQ@o);
SObj /: Extract[o : SObj[s_], 
   e___] :=
  (SObjExtract[o, e] /; SObjQ@o);
```

#### Property setting

Here's where most of my old attempts have really struggled. It's easy to redefine things like `a / : Set[a[p_], b_]:=(mySet[a, p, b])`, but it's harder to handle `Part` and friends without things getting messy. Happily we now have the function `` Language`SetMutationHandler `` which will do this for us.

We'll want to handle all the cases we declared before, so we set it up like this:

```
SetAttributes[SObjMutationHandler, HoldAllComplete];
SObj /: Set[o_SObj?SObjQ[prop_], newvalue_] :=

  SObjSet[o, prop, newvalue];
SObjMutationHandler[
   Set[(sym : (_SObj | _Symbol)?SObjQ)[prop_], newvalue_]
   ] := SObjSet[sym, prop, newvalue];
SObjMutationHandler[
   Set[Part[(sym : (_SObj | _Symbol)?SObjQ), p__], newvalue_]
   ] := SObjSetPart[sym, p, newvalue];
SObjMutationHandler[
   AssociateTo[(sym : (_SObj | _Symbol)?SObjQ), stuff_]
   ] := SObjAssociateTo[sym, stuff];
Language`SetMutationHandler[SObj, SObjMutationHandler];
```

#### A brief note on MutationHandlers

Note that without a mutation handler, there are a few core cases that would be very tough. For instance, if we wanted to set a part on an object and tried it naively:

```
a = obj[uuid];
a[[1]] = 2;
a

obj[2]
```

it doesn't work.

Similarly, if we tried to set a part on an `Association` we set as a `SubValue`:

```
b = obj[uuid];
b[1] = <||>;
b[1, 2] = 10;
b[1]

<||>
```

this also fails

Alternatively, if we use a `MutationHandler` in a minimal object implementation:

```
myO`myO~SetAttributes~HoldFirst;
myO`myO[s_Symbol][k__] := s[k];
myO`myO[[s_Symbol]][k__] := s[[k]];
myO`setPart[myO`myO[s_Symbol], p__, v_] :=
  s[[p]] = v;
myO`setKey[myO`myO[s_Symbol], p__, v_] :=
  s[p] = v;
myO`mutate~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
myO`mutate[a_Symbol?(Head[#] === myO`myO &)[k__]~Set~ v_] :=

  myO`setKey[a, k, v];
myO`mutate[a_Symbol?(Head[#] === myO`myO &)[[k__]]~Set~ v_] :=

  myO`setPart[a, k, v];
Language`SetMutationHandler[myO`myO, myO`mutate];
```

We can handle those cases:

```
o = myO`myO[Evaluate@Unique[]];
o[1]
o[1] = 2

$1406[1]

2

o =
  With[{s = Unique[]},
    s = Range[10];
   myO`myO[s]
   ];
o[[1]] = 2;
First@o

{2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

#### Attributes

Finally we'll need to make this thing `HoldFirst`:

SObj~SetAttributes~HoldFirst

### Take-aways

Hopefully that was a simple enough explanation of one of many takes on OOP in Mathematica. The key things that this provides for us:

1. All top-level
2. `Temporary` allows for `Automatic` garbage collection
3. By using the `Association` interface we can get efficient object emulation
4. `` System`Private`SetNoEntry `` allows our object to act atomic
5. `` Language`SetMutationHandler `` fixes the issue of how to set parts on the object when `UpValues` will only go to depth 1 as well as the more crucial issue of how to handle mutating the object if it's bound to a symbol.

#### Classes

I added in an instantiation / class system to this based on simply having an object with a `"New"` method that will call a function `SObjInstantiate` that will build an instance from the object.

Similar features are simple enough building off that.

---

### Examples

#### Basic mutability

Here's a little example of how this works:

```
Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/raw/master/SymbolObjects.wl"];
myObj = SObj[]
```

[image: asd]

```
AssociateTo[myObj, 
 KeyMap[CanonicalName]@ChemicalData["Water", "Association"]
 ]

myObj // Length

113

myObj["BondLengths"]

{Quantity[1., "Angstroms"]}

myObj["BondLengths"] *= 2

myObj["BondLengths"]

{Quantity[1.9, "Angstroms"]}

myObj[["BondLengths", 1, 2]] = "Kilojoules"

"Kilojoules"

myObj["BondLengths"]

{Quantity[1.9, "Kilojoules"]}
```

We can see it generally does act like an `Association` (although `Lookup` of course doesn't really work for it), but this object is stateful, is never copied, and when we use it with another `Symbol` the changes map back:

```
asd = myObj;

asd["BondLengths"] *= 2

myObj["BondLengths"]

{Quantity[3.8, "Kilojoules"]}
```

#### Implementing an iterator

Here's how we can build an `iter` type with this. First we set up a `Next` and `Skip` functions that would work with a passed `Symbol` capturing an `Association`:

```
iterNext[iter_, Optional[1, 1]] :=
  Quiet[
   Check[
    (iter["Index"] += 1; #) &@
     iter[["Iterable", iter["Index"]]],
     EndOfBuffer,
    {Part::partw}
    ],
   {Part::partw}
   ];
iterNext[iter_, n_Integer] :=

  Block[{tally = 0, i = iter["Index"], res, range},
   range =
    i +
     If[n > 0,
      Range[0, n - 1], 
      Range[-1, n, -1]
      ];
   res =
    Join[
     Map[
      Quiet[
        Check[
         iter[["Iterable", #]],
         tally++;
          EndOfBuffer,
         {Part::partw}
         ],
        {Part::partw}
        ] &,
      Select[range, Positive]
      ],
     ConstantArray[EndOfBuffer, Length@Select[range, Not@*Positive]]
     ];
   iter["Index"] = Max@{i + n - tally, 1};
   res
   ];
iterSkip[iter_, n : _Integer : 
    1] :=
  (iter["Index"] = Max@{iter["Index"] + n, 1};);
iterExtend[iter_, l_] :=
  With[{i = Join[iter["Iterable"], l]},
   iter["Iterable"] = i;
   ];
```

Then we define a function for initializing the iter and a class template which we bind to the `$SObjTemplates` variable provided by the package.

```
iterInit[obj_, iter_: {}] :=
  (
   AssociateTo[
    obj,
    {
     "Iterable" -> iter,
     "Index" -> 1
     }
    ];
   obj
   );
SymbolObjects`Package`$SObjTemplates["Iterator"] =
  <|
   "ObjectInstanceProperties" ->
    <|
     "Next" ->
      SymbolObjects`Package`SObjMethod[iterNext],
     "Skip" ->
      SymbolObjects`Package`SObjMethod[iterSkip],
     "Extend" ->
      SymbolObjects`Package`SObjMethod[iterExtend],
     "ExhaustedQ" ->
      SymbolObjects`Package`SObjProperty[
       With[{res = iterNext[#] === EndOfBuffer},
         iterNext[#, -1];
         res
         ] &
       ]
     |>,
   "ObjectInitialize" -> iterInit
   |>;
```

And now we can initialize our `"Iterator"` class:

```
iter = SObj["Iterator", {"Class"}]
```

[image: asdasd]

Then we can instantiate the iter:

```
inst = iter["New"][Range[5]]
```

[image: asddd]

```
inst["Next"][]

1

inst["Skip"][]

inst["Next"][5]

{3, 4, 5, EndOfBuffer, EndOfBuffer}

inst["Skip"][-5];
inst["Next"][5]

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

inst["Extend"][Range[10]];
inst["Skip"][5]
inst["Next"][10]

{6, 7, 8, 9, 10, EndOfBuffer, EndOfBuffer, EndOfBuffer, EndOfBuffer, EndOfBuffer}

inst["ExhaustedQ"]

True
```

---

### Final notes

If this interests you, look at the package, email me with questions. If there are things you want to see in the package, let me know and I'll try to get to them when I have time. I really just knocked this thing out as fast as possible (maybe like ~2 or 3 hours) so it's undoubtedly highly incomplete.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problematic cases where mutation handler really helps?

Comment: @Kuba added a note on that

Answer (score 15):

> [...] but I'm hoping someone can suggest a sleek and novel implementation
>   that is easy to use.

The answer to this is to use [Object-Oriented Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) in *Mathematica* as explained and exemplified in the presentation ["Object Oriented Design Patterns"](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=400&v=1470) at the [Wolfram Technology Conference 2015](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2015/). (The presentation recording is also [uploaded at YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Q6hOx63b08).)

Here is a link to a document describing how to implement OOP Design Patterns in *Mathematica*:

["Implementation of Object-Oriented Programming Design Patterns in Mathematica"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Documentation/Implementation-of-Object-Oriented-Programming-Design-Patterns-in-Mathematica.pdf)

The described approach does not require the use of preliminary implementations, packages, or extra code.

Design Patterns brought OOP into maturity. Design Patterns help overcome limitations of programming languages, give higher level abstractions for program design, and provide design transformation guidance. **Because of this it is much better to emulate OOP in *Mathematica* through Design Patterns than through emulation of OOP objects.** (The latter is done in all other approaches and projects I have seen.)

### Related posts/descriptions/answers

1. MSE discussion ["Which Object-oriented paradigm approach to use in Mathematica?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119991/34008).
2. Blog post ["Object-Oriented Design Patterns in Mathematica"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/03/20/object-oriented-design-patterns-in-mathematica/).
3. Blog post ["UML diagrams creation and generation"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/uml-diagrams-creation-and-generation-2/).
4. [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109914/34008) in the discussion [General strategies to write big code in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109888/general-strategies-to-write-big-code-in-mathematica/).
5. [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/110524#110524) in the discussion [Can one identify the design patterns of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/can-one-identify-the-design-patterns-of-mathematica/).

Comment: I think this is a great point. I use OOP as an architectural and design construct all the time but only a few times have a truly used any of my proper object frameworks for serious things. It’s much lighter weight and with the introduction of `Association` in my opinion almost always the way to go (unless you really need the extra encapsulation and mutability that a true object brings).

Comment: @b3m2a1 Right, the introduction of Association makes some OOP approaches more convenient. For example, see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134390/34008) of ["Functions with changeable global variables"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134381/34008) that compares the use of Association and the use of faithful OOP.

Answer (score 4):

#### Minimal Object Implementation

As part of extending my other answer, I came up with a minimal mutable object implementation:

```
myO`myO~SetAttributes~HoldFirst;
myO`myO[s_Symbol][k__] := s[k];
myO`myO[[s_Symbol]][k__] := s[[k]];
myO`setPart[myO`myO[s_Symbol], p__, v_] :=
  s[[p]] = v;
myO`setKey[myO`myO[s_Symbol], p__, v_] :=
  s[p] = v;
myO`mutate~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
myO`mutate[a_Symbol?(Head[#] === myO`myO &)[k__]~Set~ v_] :=

  myO`setKey[a, k, v];
myO`mutate[a_Symbol?(Head[#] === myO`myO &)[[k__]]~Set~ v_] :=

  myO`setPart[a, k, v];
Language`SetMutationHandler[myO`myO, myO`mutate];
myO`myO[] := myO`myO[Evaluate@Unique[]];
```

For those who don't like to load packages, this will get you most of what you want

#### Slightly-Less Minimal

Here's an object implementation that lives somewhere between that minimal one and my packaged up one. It's basically the package minus the template / class interface and constructor and things.

```
BeginPackage["Obj`"];
Unprotect["Obj`*"];
ClearAll["Obj`*", "Obj`*`*"];
Obj::usage = "object wrapper";
MakeObj::usage = "Makes an object";
Protect["Obj`*"];
BeginPackage["`Package`"];
apply::usage = "applies a function to an Obj";
mutate::usage = "mutates an Obj";
EndPackage[];
Begin["`Private`"];
(* constructor *)
Obj~SetAttributes~HoldFirst;
MakeObj[e_] :=
  With[{u = Unique[`$Objects`Obj]},
   u = e;
   SetAttributes[u, Temporary];
   Obj[u]
   ];
Obj[] := MakeObj[<||>];
(* define a application function *)

apply~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
apply[Obj[s_Symbol], f_, args___] := f[s, args];
apply[Obj[s_Symbol][a___], f_, args___] := f[s[a], args];
apply[Obj[s_Symbol][[a___]], f_, args___] := f[s[[a]], args];
apply[e_, r__] :=
  apply[Evaluate@e, r] /; MatchQ[e, Obj[_Symbol]];
(* define access interface via application function *)
(o_Obj)[k___] :=
   apply[o, Function[Null, #[k], HoldFirst]];
$basicInterfaceFunctions =
  {
   Part, Extract, Take, Drop, First, Last, Most, Rest, Length, 
   KeyTake, KeyDrop, MemberQ, KeyMemberQ, KeyExistsQ
   };
Map[(Obj /: #[o_Obj, a___] := 
     apply[o, #, a]) &, $basicInterfaceFunctions];
Obj /: Normal[Obj[s_Symbol]] := s;
(* define mutation interface via apply function *)

SetAttributes[mutate, HoldAllComplete];
$basicMutationFunctions =
  {
   Set, SetDelayed, Unset, PrependTo, AppendTo, AssociateTo, 
   KeyDropFrom, AddTo, SubtractFrom, TimesBy, DivideBy
   };
Map[
  (mutate[#[o : (_Symbol?(MatchQ[#, Obj[_Symbol]] &) | Obj[_Symbol]), 
       a___]] :=
     apply[o, #, a];
    mutate[#[
       o : (_Symbol?(MatchQ[#, Obj[_Symbol]] &) | Obj[_Symbol])[k__], 
       a___]] :=
     apply[o, #, a];
    mutate[#[
       o : (_Symbol?(MatchQ[#, Obj[_Symbol]] &) | 
           Obj[_Symbol])[[k___]], a___]] :=
     apply[o, #, a]
    ) &,
  $basicMutationFunctions
  ];
Language`SetMutationHandler[Obj, mutate];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

Answer (score 3):

Data abstraction is one aspect of object-oriented programming, in my opinion, the most important aspect. I frequently use a schema abstracted, I hope in a very obvious way, from the following example, to implement data abstraction. I can just keyboard new 'classes' according to this schema without thinking much at all. My answer ignores many aspects of "object-oriented programming," such as namespace control (all my symbols must be free of global definitions), polymorphism (it's not straightforward to inherit from my 'class' simulacrum), lifetime management (I can only hope Mathematica's garbage collector does the right thing), and many other aspects, I am sure. I offer this only because it's been useful to me many times and it doesn't require any special support. And, in the hope that it is self-explantory, here it is with no further prose.

```
ClearAll[complex, real, imaginary, magnitude, phase, asMMA, setReal, 
  setImaginary, setMagnitude, setPhase, setEulerian, setCartesian];
(* Constructor for 'complex' numbers stands in for the 'class' \
concept. There are no functions, here, for algebraic operations on my \
complex numbers, but I hope it's obvious how to add them. *)
complex[
   r : (_Real | _Integer | _Rational),
   i : (_Real | _Integer | _Rational)] :=
  Module[{this,(* a perforce unique 'instance' symbol *)
    realPart, 
    imaginaryPart, phasePart, magnitudePart,
    setEulerian, setCartesian (* closures that depend on other unique symbols *)},
   (* private *)
   realPart = r;
   imaginaryPart = i;
   setEulerian[] :=
    (magnitudePart = 
      Sqrt[realPart^2 + imaginaryPart^2];
     phasePart = ArcTan[realPart, imaginaryPart];);
   setCartesian[] :=
    (realPart = magnitudePart*Cos[phasePart];
     imaginaryPart = magnitudePart*Sin[phasePart]);
   (* initialize! *)
   setEulerian[];
   (* public getters; patterns unique to the instance, but installed in the global namespace *)
   this@real[] := realPart;
   this@imaginary[] := imaginaryPart;
   this@magnitude[] := magnitudePart;
   this@phase[] := phasePart;
   this@asMMA[] := Complex[realPart, imaginaryPart];
   (* public setters *)
   this@setReal[newR_] := (realPart = newR; setEulerian[];);
   this@setImaginary[newI_] := (imaginaryPart = newI; 
     setEulerian[];);
   this@setMagnitude[newM_] := (magnitudePart = newM; setCartesian[];);
   this@setPhase[new\[Phi]_] := (phasePart = Mod[new\[Phi], 2 \[Pi]]; 
     setCartesian[]);
   (* return 'this' instance symbols as result of constructor *)
  this   ];
aComplexNumber = complex[42, 157];
Print[aComplexNumber@real[]];
aComplexNumber@setReal[39];
Print[aComplexNumber@real[]];
Print[aComplexNumber@asMMA[]];
Print[N@aComplexNumber@phase[]];
Print[N@aComplexNumber@magnitude[]];
aComplexNumber@setPhase[0];
Print[N@aComplexNumber@asMMA[]];
```

> ```
> 42
> 39
> 39+157 I
> 1.32732
> 161.771
> 161.771 +0. I
> ```