# how implement OOP

Tags: object-oriented

I have a task implement OOP in wolfram mathematica. I think write class Point and inherit from it class Rectangle. In C# or C++ it's very easy, but I don't know how do it in wolfram mathematica. All books which I found I must pay for them. 
   Can you advise some free books, or give examples how write and work wit classes.
Tnanks,Maria.

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/how-can-i-implement-object-oriented-programming-in-mathematica) for some discussion, links, and references.

Comment: Just bear in mind that you might be letting yourself in for more than you expect. It's not just about how to write a class. First you have to write the entire OOP implementation, because *Mathematica* is not an object-oriented language. It can be done, but going down the OOP route might not be the easiest way to attain your goals, whatever they might be.

Comment: I have implemented a version of OOP which I described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/once-more-on-object-orientation-in-mathematica-does-it-have-to-be-so-hard). In that post, I explained how it works and added a few examples you may find useful. My implementation is somewhat similar to Maeder's (although I did this independently, not based on his code), but IMO I have more idiomatic method calls, which allow usual Mathematica patterns and method overloading. OTOH, class field support currently is suboptimal, something I have to work on.