# Functions with changeable global variables

Tags: programming

I'm not sure is the topic title correct, but I mean such a case.

I have several functions and "changeable" global variables, e.g.:

```
f1[x_]:=Module[{q}, q=expr1[x, V0]; V0=expr2[V0]; q];
```

This means that function `f1` depends on `x` explicitly and on global `V0` implicitly. Inside this function we compute some expression `expr1` and return its result `q` as a result of functioin `f1`. `V0` has some initial value before `f1` run, and this value is changed inside `f1` ( as result of `expr2`). This changed value of `V0` is now initial value for some other function `f2`, which also may change `V0`. These functions `f1, f2` run inside `Which` construction: if an element of some list has specific property this triggers one of the `f1, f2, ...` functions, after each `fi` run the value of `V0` is changed and this new value is initial value for next `fi`.

The question is: how to correctly organize all this? Where to initiate `V0`: at the very beginning of Notebook (as individual Input), or inside `Which` construction (`Which` is enclosed in `Module`)?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

As I was asked in comments for details of functions and variables, there are examples.

One of the functions draws a line:

```
line[l_]:=Module[{q, V, W}, V=W0.straight[l] + V0; q={RGBColor[0.5,0.5,0.5], CapForm -> "Butt", Tube[{V0, V}, size]}; W=W0.mstraight; W0=W; V0=V; q];
```

Other functioins look similar. So, `line[l]` takes length of straight as input, and also depends on "global" variables `V0, W0` -- initial coordinate and direction. `V0` is vector, initially defined as `{0,0,0}` at the very beginning of my nb file. `W0` is rotation matrix depending on 3 angles, this may change after function drawing arc, and initially `W0 = IdentityMatrix[3]`. `straight[l_] = {0,0,l}` and because line doesn't change direction, `mstraight = IdentityMatrix[3]`, `size` is global constant defining size of all the straights. Hence after this function `line` run I have `Tube` object (which can be drawn later together with other objects) and changed `V0, W0` for input to next function as new initial coordinates and direction. Now I have these variables as globals initiated at the beginning of nb, so that every such function knows their instant changed values and may change as well.

I ask, if this approach is incorrect, please explain why and how to change it to be right.

**EDIT 2**

Many thanks to Anton Antonov for his versatile answer. My present code is as follows:

```
Module[{},v0={0,0,0}; W0=IdentityMatrix[3]; size=0.2;
(* here go other initials and constants*)
graphics=Reap[(Which[list[[#]]==somevalue1,Sow[line[...]],
list[[#]]==somevalue2,Sow[arc[...]] (* and so on*)]&)/@ Range[Length@list]][[1]];]
```

With Anton's approach I have to change `Sow` construction to compound expression like this:

```
(Sow[line[...][[1]]]; {V0, W0}=line[...][[2]];)
```

Well, for me these additions complicate and lengthen code. I'm not programmer, just beginner in using MMA and WL, and for me my code looks more simple and transparent to control and understand, all needed changes in `V0, W0` are done automatically beacause these variables are global.

Can anybody explain in simple way (understandable for novice) why globals and code like mine are not recommended in MMA? Not just for the reason that advanced users of WL are not used to do things this way, but what is really wrong, what may lead to errors. I really don't understand the advantages of approach like  proposed by Anton.

Comment: `The question is: how to correctly organize all this?` well, you can start by _not_ using global variables. This is bad programming, not just in Mathematica, but in any other language. Just pass all the parameters to the function. Sorry that I can't follow the rest of your description. sometimes we use global variables here when we write code as answers, but this is just for a quick answers, and throw away code. In actual real software, global variables are not good.

Comment: Couldn't you do `With[{V0 = (* stuff *)}, f1[x_] := (* stuff *)]`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the OP uses V0 as a global variable because he doesn't know how to assign a value to V0 as a parameter of f1 ("byref" parameter)

Comment: Probably my description is not clear. Each function make some stuff and changes `V0`. You may think of `V0` as, say, current coordinate, or direction. E.g. each `fi` produce some geometrical object: line, or arc, and `V0` is initial coordinates where to start object. Then after `fi` run we should compute new initial coordinates for next function. So, `V0` is current start value for `fi`, which all functions need to see and can change.

Comment: As Nasser said, you should avoid global variables. Why not pass the current coordinate/ direction around as arguments to your functions? One function's return becomes the new coordinate/direction for the next function.

Comment: @Sascha, as I understood you this is right approach and should work: `f1[x_, V0_]:=Module[{q}, q=expr1[x, V0]; V0=expr2[V0]; q]`? So, `f1` returns `q`, but how to return `V0` changed after `expr2` to be able use this new value in next `f2[x_, V0]`?

Comment: @Alx It would help if you could add a concrete example to your question. As it is, it's hard to say what would be an appropriate answer. Can you give an example including definitions for `expr1`, `expr2`, `f1`, `f2` and `V0`.

Comment: @Alx Your code :`f1[x_, V0_]:=Module[{q}, q=expr1[x, V0]; V0=expr2[V0]; q]` will not work because of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18737/5467). That is the problem I was thinking of in my previous comment.

Comment: @Sascha and andre I addet information to my question, please read EDIT section.

Comment: @Alx: I think your question suffers from that fact that what a "correct" way to implement/organize code is is ill-defined. You should try to make more clear why you think that what you do might be "incorrect" and what you expect from more "correct" code. Answers and comments so far refer to the usual software development best practices. The advantage of these show when the code base grows, gets more complex and needs to be maintained or optimized, probably by more than one person. For a short notebook solving a problem once for your own use only they might not be obviously advantageous...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Introduction

> > The question is: how to correctly organize all this?

Of course, there are many ways to answer the question, ranging from re-education suggestions to click-through paths in a relevant IDE.

The main [conflicting forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern) behind these kind of software design questions (as the one in this discussion) are:

- using global variables is convenient, and
- using global variables can make code hard to read and full of bugs.

Below are given several styles that provide a compromise.

#### Answers to EDIT 2 of the question

> > Can anybody explain in simple way (understandable for novice) why globals and code like mine are not recommended in MMA? Not just for the reason that advanced users of WL are not used to do things this way, but what is really wrong, what may lead to errors.

With the standard software engineering goals (not "novice" ones) using global variables is bad in any language not just Mathematica / WL.

Of course, if the code is short and/or is a one-off affair, run in a notebook, then global variables are fine.

For code that is under development or it is supposed to be developed further global variables are bad mainly because:

- they prevent from reasoning effectively about the functions definitions, and
- the state of execution is unpredictable -- any part of the code can change the global variables at any time.

There are other reasons and possible coding styles and remedies that can be classified from different perspectives. See for example:

- ["Global Variables Are Bad"](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad), or
- the answers of ["Why is Global State so Evil?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) at [softwareengineering.stackexchange](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com).

The links above give answers to the request:

> > [...] Not just for the reason that advanced users of WL are not used to do things this way, but what is really wrong, what may lead to errors.

In general, since Mathematica / WL is mainly a functional language one is better off undertaking longer programming endeavors without relying on side effects during function execution (global state change or using `Sow`).

## Suggested code changes

### Using a context

The minimal effort way (i.e. rarely a good one) to somewhat contain the possible bugs is to move all function definitions and global variables [into a context](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html).

### Monads(-like)

I would say the simplest thing to do in the direction of "doing it right" is to add the global variables as an argument to all functions and as a result element to all functions. (See [this related discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125537/34008).)

With this approach all of the functions are defined to have the type (domain->codomain):

```
{args__, params_List} -> {result_, newParams_List}
```

or

```
{args__, params_Association} -> {result_, newParams_Association}
```

For example:

```
Clear[line]
(*line[l_,{V0_,W0_,mstraight_,size_}]:=line[l,{V0,W0,mstraight,size}];*)
line[l_, {V0_, W0_, mstraight_, size_}] :=
  Module[{q, V, W},
   V = W0.straight[l] + V0; 
   q = {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], CapForm -> "Butt", Tube[{V0, V}, size]}; 
   W = W0.mstraight; 
   {q, {V, W, mstraight, size}}
  ];
```

**Remark:** Note the commented out overloading of the function `line` to support your current signature -- it is better not to have it since the return result structure is different, but it might be an useful intermediate step during the code refactoring / transition.

A call to that function would be:

```
{res, newParams} = line[lVal, currentParams];
```

A further step in that direction is to use an `Association` in order to facilitate the management of the global parameters. For example:

```
Clear[line]
line[l_, params_Association] :=      
  Module[{q, V, W, V0, W0, size, mstraight},
   {V0, W0, size, mstraight} = params /@ {"V0", "W0", "size", "mstraight"};
   V = W0.straight[l] + V0; 
   q = {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], CapForm -> "Butt", Tube[{V0, V}, size]}; 
   W = W0.mstraight; 
   {q, 
    Join[params, 
     AssociationThread[{"V0", "W0", "size", "mstraight"} -> {V, W, 
        mstraight, size}]]}
  ];
```

### Using named arguments and results

Following the suggestion in the previous section of using `Association`, instead of separating the function arguments into particular (`l`) and common (`params`), we can just use an `Association` to hold -- and name -- all arguments.

For example:

```
Clear[line]
line[args_Association] :=     
  Module[{l, q, V, W, V0, W0, size, mstraight},
   {l, V0, W0, size, mstraight} = args /@ {"l", "V0", "W0", "size", "mstraight"};
   V = W0.straight[l] + V0; 
   q = {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], CapForm -> "Butt", Tube[{V0, V}, size]}; W = W0.mstraight; 
   Join[args, 
    AssociationThread[{"Result", "V0", "W0", "size", "mstraight"} -> {q, V, W, mstraight, size}]]
  ];
```

Note the special key "Result".

Assuming `glParams` is an `Association` with the global parameters

```
glParams = <|"V0" -> 12, "W0" -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}], 
   "size" -> 200, "mstraight" -> {0, 0, 1}|>;
```

a call to that function would be:

```
glParams = line[Append[glParams, "l" -> 34]];
glParams["Result"]

(* {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], CapForm -> "Butt", Tube[{12, 
    12 + {{0.178045, 0.278631, 0.528348}, {0.344852, 0.57178, 
   0.0358229}, {0.693822, 0.454272, 0.93838}}.straight[34]}, 200]} *)
```

**Remark:** R supports this style of naming arguments and results in a direct way.

### Object encapsulation (OOP style)

We can define an object that holds the variables envisioned as global and define functions for that object. (Using `SubValues`.)

For example:

```
ClearAll[PlotObject]
PlotObject[id_]["Line"[l_]] :=
  Module[{q, V, W, obj = PlotObject[id]},
   V = obj["W0"].straight[l] + obj["V0"];
   q = {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], CapForm -> "Butt", Tube[{obj["V0"], V}, obj["size"]]};
   W = obj["W0"].obj["mstraight"];
   obj["W0"] = W;
   obj["V0"] = V;
   q
  ];
```

Here we create the object and set parameters:

```
ClearAll[obj1]
obj1 = PlotObject[Unique[]];
obj1["V0"] = 12;
obj1["W0"] = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}];
obj1["size"] = 200;
obj1["mstraight"] = {0, 0, 1};
```

And here is a function call:

```
obj1["Line"[34]]

(* {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], CapForm -> "Butt", 
 Tube[{12, 12 + {{0.337577, 0.582427, 0.344005}, {0.333857, 0.879125, 
   0.867341}, {0.345823, 0.873797, 0.344179}}.straight[34]}, 200]} *)
```

For more details how to use this OOP style see this blog post ["Object-Oriented Design Patterns in Mathematica"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/03/20/object-oriented-design-patterns-in-mathematica/) and the references in it.

Other OOP styles in Mathematica are referenced in ["Which Object-oriented paradigm approach to use in Mathematica?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119991/which-object-oriented-paradigm-approach-to-use-in-mathematica).

Comment: Anton, great answer. But if I run your first code (Monads-like) I get errors: `{res, newParams} =  line[10, {{0, 0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[3], IdentityMatrix[3], 0.1}]` --> "Set: Cannot assign to raw object 0" and similar errors, but nevertheless Out is provided.

Comment: @Alx Fixed it. The first definition of `line` is my least favorite one, so I did not run it. Please note that the codes in my answer are just for illustration purposes not to be run. (Also note how trivial the fix was.)

Comment: Anton, thanks for fix. I made new edit (comments are very short to explain my point), please read EDIT 2.

Answer (score 3):

I like Anton Antonov's answer and I would like to offer this utility function in support of his `Association` method.

```
Attributes[aModule] = HoldRest;

aModule[asc_Association, body_] :=
  Set @@@ Hold @@ KeyValueMap[Hold, asc] /. _[set__] :> Module[{set}, body]
```

Now one can easily write:

```
foo = <|a -> 1, b -> 2|>;

aModule[foo, a = 2 b; a]
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

- Global values of `a` and `b` are unaffected, as is `foo`.
- The Keys must be Symbols.  If people desire I can post a more verbose version of this code designed to handle arbitrary Key names.

This function is also useful for handling options, if passed as an `Association` or converted to such.

Likely related, though in 10.1.0 I do not have this functionality:

- [What's the purpose of the GeneralUtilities`UnpackOptions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135919/121)

---

### Generalization

When I wrote "arbitrary" above I was merely thinking of automatic conversion of String keynames to Symbols.  At the same time it would be nice to handle delayed rules in the Association.  That could be done something like this:

```
Attributes[aModule] = HoldRest;

aModule[asc_Association, body_] :=
  Replace[
    Join @@ Cases[Hold @@ Normal @@ {asc},
      h_[L : _Symbol | _String, R_] :>
        With[{sy = Quiet @ ToHeldExpression @ ToString @ L},
          Hold[h[sy, R]] /; MatchQ[sy, Hold[_Symbol]]
        ]
     ],
    {(_[a_] -> b_) :> (a = b), (_[a_] :> b_) :> (a := b)},
    {1}
  ] /. _[sets__] :> Module[{sets}, body]
```

We can now also do this:

```
aModule[<|x :> Print[1]|>, Do[x, {3}]]  (* 1 printed three times *)

aModule[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c+d" -> 3|>, a = 2 b; a]
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

- `"c+d" -> 3` is ignored as its Key cannot be directly converted into a Symbol.
- Unlike the simple code at the start of this answer this function will not work with something like `a =.; foo = <|a -> 1|>; a = 2; aModule[foo, a += 3; a]` due to my use of `Normal`.  If that edge case should be handled it can be, but again the code will become longer.

---

If we really want *arbitrary* key names that is a rather different problem.  Here is a first attempt at approximating this idea.

```
Attributes[aModule] = HoldRest;

aModule[asc_Association, body_] :=
  Module[{f},
    Replace[Hold @@ Normal @@ {asc}, {
      (L_ -> R_) :> (f[L]  = R),
      (L_ :> R_) :> (f[L] := R)
     }, {1}] // ReleaseHold;
    Unevaluated[body] /. x : Alternatives @@ Keys[asc] :> f[x]
  ]
```

This allows things such as:

```
aModule[<|"c+d" -> 1, {12} -> 2|>, "c+d" = 2 {12}; "c+d"]
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

As written this has the disadvantage of using indexed objects in place of Symbols which means that among other things this won't work:

```
aModule[<|a -> {1, 2, 3}|>, a[[2]] = 5; a]
```

> Set::setps: f$2174[a] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

With a yet more verbose definition [`Unique`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unique.html) Symbols could be created for each replacement but I am unsure of the merit of general replacement like this to begin with; is using a Key name like `{12}` and treating appearances of it as a Symbol actually useful or just confusing?  Is there a less confusing way to approach this that would usefully extend `aModule`?

Comment: This definition of `aModule` is great! I can use it in my [Mathematica-vs-R](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaVsR) comparisons.

Comment: @Anton Glad to be of use. :-)

Comment: "If people desire I can post a more verbose version of this code designed to handle arbitrary Key names." -- Please do! I am very interested.

Comment: @Anton I didn't have anything fancy in mind and I realize now I misspoke (miswrote?) by using "arbitrary" as I was thinking merely of `"a" -> 1` etc.  However I'll try to craft something more general and see were it takes me.

Comment: @Anton Please see my addendum and give me your thoughts on it when you have time.

Comment: This new version is great!! It is exactly what I needed for [my State monad implementation](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/Misc/StateMonadCodeGenerator.m).

Comment: @Anton I'm glad this is useful, but these functions are not ready for "prime time."  Specifically in the first `Quiet @ Symbol @ ToString @ L` doesn't Hold the Symbol correctly, and I'll be fixing that.  Is the "edge case" I noted an issue or is that part good as-is?

Comment: The `_Association` contexts I have in mind for that State monad have keys that are (simple) strings, so the current definition works for me fairly well. (I plan to stress test the whole implementation later this week.)

Comment: @Anton Okay.  Please use the current version with `ToHeldExpression` when you do and let me know of any problems that come up.