# Is there a way to make $g$ changeable independently of $f$ in this code?

Tags: coding-style, design-patterns, writing

**My problem is that in the below code, every time I want to change $g$ I also have to change $f$.**

Let's say we have three functions: $f$, $h$, and $g$ ($h$ is not really relevant for the question, but its there).

Now let's say that we don't specify what $g$ is yet, because we don't want to restrict it to one particular form. But we define $f$ as follows:

```
f[x_]:=h[x]+NIntegrate[g[y],{y,0,x}]
```

Now let's say we want to plot $f[5]$ as a function of a parameterization of $g$:

```
g[y_]:=a*y^b
(*I am tempted to write the following:*)
Plot3D[f[5],{a,0,1},{b,0,1}]
```

But the above code obviously doesn't do anything. In order for the approach to work, we would have to instead define

```
f[x_,a_,b_]:=h[x]+NIntegrate[g[y,a,b],{y,0,x}]
g[y_,a_,b_]:=a*y^b
Plot3D[f[5,a,b],{a,0,1},{b,0,1}]
```

**There are two problems with this approach:**

1. It is kind of clumsy
2. It is not versatile. If we want a specification of $g$ that has 3 parameters, then we need to redefine $f$ as well.
3. If we have higher levels of nesting of functions, this becomes even more of a hassle.

**Is there a way to do this in a cleaner way without passing parameters from function to function, or at least in a way that if we want to change the parameter specification of $g$, we don't have to change all the others as well?**

**Is there a Canonical way to do this?**

Comment: You could use `g` and `h` also as arguments to `f`...

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134390/34008) for a question about using global variables has several suggestions to achieve the versatility OP wants.

Comment: Also look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/12558) where `SubValues` are used. Can't find `SubValues` in Help though.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, could you point me to something on how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I see an equation with an integral, I always think about trying to convert it into an ODE. Your question falls into this category. So, let's differentiate your equation:

```
eqn = f[x] == h[x] + Inactive[NIntegrate][g[y], {y, 0, x}];
D[eqn, x]
```

> f'[x] == g[x] + h'[x]

Now, let's solve this ODE and plot the solution:

```
g[x_] := a x^b
h[x_] := x^2

f = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {u'[x] == h'[x] + g[x], u[0] == h[0]},
    u[5],
    {x, 0, 5},
    {a, b}
];

Plot3D[f[a, b], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

You can include `g` in the definition of `f` as follows:

```
f[g_, p_] := ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {u'[x] == h'[x] + g, u[0] == h[0]}, 
    u[5], 
    {x, 0, 5}, 
    p
]
```

Then, we can use different `g` functions:

```
f1 = f[a x^b, {a, b}];

Plot3D[f1[a, b], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
f2 = f[a Cos[b x], {a, b}];

Plot3D[f2[a, b], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: what is the name of the technique you use in the end, when you define f2 not as a function, and then later treating it as a function? (so I can look it up in the references of the mathematica language)

Comment: @Programmer2134 `ParametricNDSolveValue` returns a `ParametricFunction` object. If `pf` is a `ParametricFunction` object, than `pf[parameters..]` evaluates to a number in this case, but more typical is that it evaluates to an `InterpolatingFunction` object. So, `f[..]` returns a `ParametricFunction` object, and then the `Plot3D` function evaluates the `ParametricFunction` object with `a` and `b` values.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably half a dozen ways to do what OP wants. Below are given two relatively simple ones.

### args___

I would say the simplest way is to have arbitrary arguments passed from `f` to `g`.

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]    
h[x_] := x^2    
f[x_, args___] := h[x] + NIntegrate[g[y, args], {y, 0, x}]
```

Using `f` with a definition of `g`:

```
g[y_, a_, b_] := a*y^b    
f[6, 0, 1]

(* 36. )
```

Using `f` with another definition of `g`:

```
g[y_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := a + b*y + c*y^2 + d*y^3
f[6, 1, 2, 3, 4]

(* 1590. *)
```

A version of this approach is to use `OptionsPattern`; another version is to use `Association`. (For the latter see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134390/34008).)

### Using `SubValues`

Here the definition of `f` takes the functions `h` and `g` as arguments (instead of the parameters of `g` as done above.)

```
ClearAll[f, g, g1, g2, h]
f[h_, g_][x_?NumberQ] := h[x] + NIntegrate[g[y], {y, 0, x}]
h[x_] := x^2
```

Here is a couple of definitions of `g`:

```
g1[y_, a_, b_] := a*y^b

g2[y_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := a + b*y + c*y^2 + d*y^3
```

Here is how we invoke them:

```
f[h, g1[#, 0, 1] &][6]

(* 36. *)

f[h, g2[#, 1, 2, 3, 4] &][6]

(* 1590. *)
```

The convenience of this approach is that we can specify `g` "on the spot." For example,

```
f[h, (#^2 + 3*#) &][6]

(* 162. *)
```

Note that with the approach in the previous section we do enforce the use of a definition of `g` (which might be desired in some cases.)

Comment: Thank you. Couple of questions: **1. What** does the "?" do in "?NumberQ"? **2. why** do you use f[..][..] (i.e. 2 sets of brackets instead of 1: f[...])? Is there a name for this? (so I can look it up in the documentation) **3. Is there** a way to do it without the "#" (Which I think defines a "pure function")?  **4. I cannot** find "SubValues" in the documentation. Is there now a new term for it?

Comment: @Programmer2134 **1.**  `_?NumberQ` is a pattern matching for something that passes the test `NumberQ`. **2.** For clarity. You can use single [] if your prefer. See "tutorial/TheRepresentationOfDerivatives" in the documentation. **3.** Why? If `#` bothers you use `args___`; or just define `g3[x_]:=g2[x,1,2,3,4]` and then pass `g3`. **4.** It was given a reference to [`SubValues`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8003/34008) in another comment.