# Convenient value assignments in OOP

Tags: core-language, object-oriented

It is possible to implement OOP in Mathematica using something like

```
obj=c[<|a->1,b->2|>]
```

and it's convenient to extract value from the object by setting:

```
c[a_][b_]:=a[b]
obj[a]
```

> 1

but how to write a convenient value assignment so that this form of set action is valid?

```
obj[a]=3
```

> 3

```
obj
```

> c[<|a->3,b->2|>]

Thanks!

---

**My (obviously unsuccessful) attempts:**

```
c /: Set[o : (c[a_])[b_], val_] := (o=c[ReplacePart[a,Key[b]->val]])
```

This obviously won't work as the `HoldFirst` attribute of `Set` prevent the pattern matching of `c[a_]`

but without it:

```
Set[o_[b_], val_]/;Head[o]==c := (o=c[ReplacePart[a,Key[b]->val]])
```

`Set` is `Protected` and simply matching all `o_[b_]` type and then filter by `Head` is simply so inefficient.

Comment: You have to use ``Language`SetMutationHandler``. See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165910/38178) for detailed info an an example.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks! I will have a look!

Comment: Please try to determine the place of your approach among the ones listed (and taxonomized) here: ["Which Object-oriented paradigm approach to use in Mathematica?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119991). Consider posting an answer (in the referred MSE discussion.)

Answer (score 0):

Kernel definitions precede over user definitions, and subvalues precede over upvalues. As @HenrikSchumacher commented, `` Language`SetMutationHandler `` should be used.