# How can I implement a listener variable in Mathematica?

Tags: front-end, customization, symbols

I'd like to be able to listen to a variable and know when it's been changed and accept/reject the change as well as use it as an update listener for `Dynamic` how can I do this?

Comment: Do you need this functionality contained in the `Manipulate` or is something external to the `Manipulate` updating the variable? If external then is it in the same `Module`\`DynamicModule` or elsewhere?

Comment: @Edmund I was imagining this would be a pure kernel thing without reference to `Manipulate` or `Dynamic` (although usable by the latter).

Answer (score 11):

As part of handling this for myself [I wrote a package](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/blob/master/Listeners.m) that does it. The idea was to mimic the [`*Var()` classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) in [`tkinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). I'll do a quick demo then explain how I built this, which is the actually interesting part of this.

First we'll load that package and make one of these `Listener` objects:

```
Get["https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-tools/raw/master/Listeners.m"]

var=Listener["b"];
var//InputForm
(*Out: Listener["b"] *)
```

It looks like nothing happened, but we'll look at the proper display form:

```
displayedForm[expr_] :=
 First@FrontEndExecute@
   ExportPacket[Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@expr], "PlainText"]

displayedForm@var
(* Out: "Null" *)
```

So the object is displaying as `Null`.

Now we'll assign something new to `var`:

```
var = 1;
displayedForm@var
(* Out: "1" *)

OwnValues@var//InputForm
(* Out: {HoldPattern[var] :> Listener["b"]} *)
```

And now even though it *displays* as `1` the value of `var` hasn't changed at all.

Next we'll attach a callback that simply tells us what kind of change is being applied to this `Listener` object:

```
var["Callback"]=Print[#]&;
var=2
(* Print: Update *)
(* Out: 2 *)
var={1}
(* Print: Update *)
(* Out: {1} *)
var[[1]] = 5
(* Print: UpdatePart *)
(* Out: 5 *)
```

This callback is telling us the type of change applied. It's also passed the name (`"b"` in this case) and the args of the change and if it returns `False` the change is rejected.

Now we'll get to the original reason this was made, which is for forcing updated in `Dynamic`. If we use:

```
ListenerDynamic[RandomReal[], var]
```

every time `var` is updated the argument (`RandomReal[]`) gets re-evaluated.

Updates to `var`, while slow relative to standard variable assignment, are still faster than box updates, so we can the classic:

```
ListenerDynamic[var = RandomReal[], var]
```

And watch it tick away. I haven't supported `Increment` and `AddTo` and things, so don't get too crazy with it, but it would be easy to add.

Unlike `Dynamic[x = RandomReal[]]`, though, we can turn this off by setting: `var["Callback"] = False &`

So, great, we got what we came for. We effectively have a Tk `*Var*` object.

## Implementation

But what's fun about this is *how* it's done. I didn't really do anything fundamentally different than my OOP work [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165486/38205) but I used a completely different backend that could have been handled in a very different way to very different effect.

### Language`ExpressionStore

To implement this I used the new [`` Language`ExpressionStore ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171154/38205). These are "weak" hash maps in that they store values without messing with the ref-counts of stored object and they use a specific object instance as a key and when that object is destroyed all its associated keys and values in the map are destroyed.

There's an example of this in the linked question, but we can see how it works here. First we'll make a new object and get the variable it uses for storing state:

```
$HistoryLength = 0 (* to prevent ref count changes from Out *)
obj = Listener["object"];
obj["Variable"]

(* Out: Hold[Listeners`Private`listener$21210] *)
```

This `Symbol` is what is doing all the state holding and is what that `ListenerDynamic` is looking for updates on.

Now we'll do some memory tests. First we'll create a large array any attach it to the object:

```
mem1 = MemoryInUse[];

obj = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 100, 100}];
mem2 = MemoryInUse[];
mem2 - mem1

(* Out: 8000368 *)
```

And then we'll simply remove any reference `obj` as a variable has to its held `Listener` object in a way where I couldn't have even attached `UpValues` to mess with things:

```
OwnValues[obj] = {};
mem3 = MemoryInUse[];
mem3 - mem1

(* Out: -1128 *)
```

And we see that all the memory associated with `obj` has been freed. And if we check the definitions on that storage symbol:

```
Listeners`Private`listener$21210

(* Out: Listeners`Private`listener$21210 *)
```

We see it cleaned itself up. This is because it was a `Temporary` symbol and once there were no references to the `Listener` object that was its key in the underlying `ExpressionStore` both of them were cleaned up.

### Language`MutationHandler

We use `ExpressionStore` as our backend and then as the interface (front-end?) to the object we use the [`` Language`*Mutation* ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165910/38205) functions to allow us to cleanly allow `var = x` to call a custom setter instead of simply calling `Set` on `var`.

### `` System`Private`*Entry* ``

I also use the [`` System`Private`*Entry* `` functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/139974/38205) as a way to test whether my objects have truly been "constructed" or not. If we get a raw `Listener[...]` expression we can check whether `` System`Private`HoldEntryQ `` is true or not and if it is we call a constructor that will return a `Listener[...]` object that *looks* the same but is a fundamentally different object with `` System`Private`HoldSetNoEntry `` called on it.

### Object lookup

I wanted to be able to just use `Listener[name]` raw without ensuring I had the variable bound as a convenience, so I actually had to check whether an object with that `name` had already been built. I did this by searching the keys in the expression store I built (`` Listeners`Package`$Listeners ``). This is slightly inefficient, but it only happens in the construction step, so I thought the time hit was worth taking.

### New forms of OOP

One nice thing about this form of OOP is that it allows us to have more opaque objects than I used in my `SymbolObjects` package. We could simply use `ExpressionStore` as a way to store *all* fields and methods. The memory will be naturally cleaned when whatever object we return from our constructor goes out of scope.

This is both cleaner and potentially more robust than writing interfaces to `Symbol` or `Association`.

I wouldn't be surprised to see a lot more development from WRI and package developers around here in that vein.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`PersistentValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PersistentValue.html) with its [`ValuePreprocessingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ValuePreprocessingFunction.html) option.

For some listening function such as

```
listen = Echo;
```

included in a validation function

```
validateInteger[x_] := If[IntegerQ[x], listen@x; x, $Failed]
```

then a `PersistentValue` can be created which is validated and notifies updates via the `ValuePreprocessingFunction`.

```
PersistentValue["int", PersistenceLocation["KernelSession"], 
  ValuePreprocessingFunction -> validateInteger] = 0;
```

> » 0

When set to a value that validates the `listen` function is called and the `PersistentValue` updated.

```
PersistentValue["int", "KernelSession"] = 6
```

> » 6
>
> ```
> 6
> ```

When set to a value that does not validate the `listen` function is not called and the `PersistentValue` is not updated.

```
PersistentValue["int", "KernelSession"] = 6.5
```

> ```
> $Failed
> ```

```
PersistentValue["int", "KernelSession"]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

Clean up with

```
DeleteObject[PersistentObjects["int"]];
```

Hope this helps.