# Swap two entries in a matrix

Tags: function-construction, matrix

Is there a nice, simple script one can use to swap two entires in a matrix? For example, suppose we have the matrix below:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 4 & 1\\
3 & 1 & 2\\
4 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Is there a script of the form `switch[A,a,b]`, which will swap all occurrences of $a$ in the matrix with $b$, and vice versa, and then update the matrix $A$ accordingly? So in this case the output of `switch[A,2,3]` would be:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 4 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 3\\
4 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

My own solution involves a lot of `If` and `For` functions, and will, I think, also run into the problems detailed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7214/how-to-set-parts-of-indexed-lists). I think it will work eventually (and I'd be happy to post what I have so far if people would like), but really I'm just wondering whether there's a simpler way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A minor point regarding `ReplaceAll`: `ReplaceAll` does not change the matrix `a`, so you do need to set `a= (a/. {replacement rules})` or `a=ReplaceAll[a,{replacement rules}]`.

```
 a = {{2, 4, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 1}};
 a = (a /. {2 -> 3, 3 -> 2});
 a // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Another alternative is to use `Replace` at level 2:

```
 a = Replace[a, {2 -> 3, 3 -> 2}, {2}]
```

or at level -1:

```
 a = Replace[a, {2 -> 3, 3 -> 2}, {-1}]
```

Yet another alternative:

```
 a = Cases[a, {x___, aa : (3 | 2), y___} :> {x, If[aa == 3, 2, 3], y}, {1,Infinity}]
```

**Update:** functions to swap a pair of elements of a matrix:

```
ClearAll[swap];
SetAttributes[swap, HoldFirst];
swap[mat_, elem1_, elem2_] := (mat = mat /. {elem1 -> elem2, elem2 -> elem1})
swap[a,2,3]
 (* {{3, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {4, 2, 1}} *)
```

Swap multiple pairs of elements:

```
ClearAll[swap2];
SetAttributes[swap2, HoldFirst];
swap2[mat_, pairs:{{_, _} ..}] := (mat = mat /.(Rule @@@ Join[pairs, Reverse /@ pairs]))
swap2[a,{{2,3}}]
 (* {{2, 4, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 1}}  *)
swap2[a,{{2,3},{1,4}}]
 (* {{3, 1, 4}, {2, 4, 3}, {1, 2, 4}} *)
```

For large matrices and many pairs to swap:

```
ClearAll[swap3];
SetAttributes[swap3, HoldFirst];
swap3[mat_, pairs : {{_, _} ..}] :=  With[{dispatch = Dispatch[Rule @@@ Join[pairs, Reverse /@ pairs]]}, mat = (mat /. dispatch)]
```

Comment: Another way to generate the replacement rules: `Dispatch[Apply[Join, Thread[# -> Reverse[#]] & /@ pairs]]`.

Comment: @J.M. really nice. More concise than everything I have tried.

Comment: @kguler Won't it be better if the `swap` function do not replace the original matrix itself? (I mean, if both `a` and swapped `a` are needed.)

Comment: @Noble P. Abraham That's probably because I asked for the original matrix to be replaced in my question.

Comment: That's true. Considering `swap` as a general function, it might be better if it does not replace.

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham, I agree with you. To get a version  that does not replace the input matrix,  one can remove the part `mat=` in the definition of `swap`  and use `a=swap[a,...]` when one needs to replace `a`.

Answer (score 11):

`ReplaceAll` should do it:

```
{{2, 4, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 1}} /. {2 -> 3, 3 -> 2}
```

Answer (score 4):

I like the above `ReplaceAll` solution the most. But to make sure there are at least 10 different ways to do something in Mathematica, here is another way

```
mat = {{2, 4, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 1}};
pos1 = Position[mat, 2];
pos2 = Position[mat, 3];
mat = ReplacePart[mat, pos1 -> 3];
mat = ReplacePart[mat, pos2 -> 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

With `ReplacePart` and `Position`:

```
a = {{2, 4, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 1}};
ReplacePart[a, {Position[a, 2] -> 3, Position[a, 3] -> 2}]

(* {{3, 4, 1}, {2, 1, 3}, {4, 2, 1}} *)
```