# Error in setting matrix elements

Tags: list-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Set parts of indexed lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7214/how-to-set-parts-of-indexed-lists)

For better organization of my code, sometime I use data objects in the form:

```
data["A", "1"] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

instead of

```
dataA1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

One of the advantages is when working with `Module`, because I can declare `data` just one time, and I can use `data["A","1"]`, `data["A","2"]`, `data["B","1"]` and so on, with limited scope.

Everything works fine except for one detail. With `data["A", "1"]` I can't perform operations like:

```
data["A", "1"] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
data["A", "1"][[All, 2]] = "X"
```

to change `data["A", "1"]` to `{{1, "X"}, {3, "X"}}`

I got the error:

```
Set::setps: data["A", "1"] in the part assignment is not a symbol
```

When I try with:

```
dataA1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
dataA1[[All, 2]] = "X";
dataA1
```

I have no problem and get `{{1, "X"}, {3, "X"}}` as expected.

There is nome way to perform this kind of operation in `data["A", "1"]` object?

**Update**

The question indicated as duplicated do not handle the case: `data["A", "1",...]` but just `data["A"]`

Comment: See also [this Mathgroup thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/5O0JeqYbdP4)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin tks!.. Should I delete this?

Comment: Not sure about deletion. It may be better to close this but keep it alive. If you make a slightly more specific / descriptive title, it may drive future visitors to that question. I take it that you tried to find something on the topic before asking, and did not find that one. And I only found it because I remember answering it. So, right now I am for closing, let's see what others think.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin hi!.. I'm studying Upvalues and I just saw that your answer and Mr.Wisard too do not apply to my case `data["A", "1"]` they work for just one arg function. It's not the case to reopen it? Or it's simple to extend it for `data[__]` case?

Comment: Hello! In my answer to that question, simply replace everywhere `sym[index_]` with `sym[indices__]` (of course, consistently across the bodies of the functions), and it should work, I think. Let me know if it does not. As for the answer of @Mr.Wizard, I suppose that should work for it too.

Comment: Yes! It works. For your and Mr.Wizard. For me this is the best simpler application of Upvalues. Tks!

Comment: Good to know it worked for you!

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```
 data["A", "1"] = ReplacePart[data["A", "1"], {_, 2} -> "X"]
```

It transforms `data["A", "1"]` from `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` to `{{1, "X"}, {3, "X"}}`.

Comment: The problem with this is that `ReplacePart` copies entire expression, so a single element assignment using `ReplacePart` will not have a constant time complexity. For most applications, this will be a disaster.

Comment: I agree that this should only be used when computing time is insignifiant