# Create a list of indexed matrices and then change their entries

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, assignment

I make a list of 5 empty $3 \times 3$ matrices via

```
 Table[m[i]=IdentityMatrix[3]-IdentityMatrix[3],{i,1,5}]
```

However when I want to change an entry via

```
 m[2][[3,4]]=5
```

I get an error which reads:

Set::setps: m[2] in the part assignment is not a symbol. >>

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Why not do something like `m = ConstantArray[0, {5, 3, 3}]` and then do `m[[2, 3, 4]] = 1`?

Comment: You mean instead of explicitly indexing the matrices, placing them in a list and identifying them there. That does make the way I call the matrices a little more intuitive, I don't have the single brackets and then the double brackets. However, I'm curious why indexing the matrices directly messes with the assignment I make.

Comment: The docs for the error message just says "Part assignments are implemented only for parts of the value of a symbol." So since `m[2]` is not a symbol itself, but a reference to one of the `DownValue`s of the symbol `m`, this is what you get.

Comment: Also, note the difference between `Do` and `Table`, we don't use `Table` just for side effects ;)

Comment: You can do e.g. `m[2] = ReplacePart[m[2], {3, 4} -> 5]` but that copies the whole of `m[2]` so I would prefer @J.M. 's suggestion.

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7214/121

Answer (score 2):

As the comments read, the problem is that m[2] is not a symbol but a reference to a value of the symbol m, so to change the value there I have to actually replace it via:

```
 m[2]=ReplacePart[m[2],{4,5}->5].
```

Which copies the entirety of m[2] and doesn't look all that pretty.

J.M.'s suggestion is to just make a list of the matrices and refer to them from there.