# What is the right way to work with indexed variables bound to vectors?

Tags: core-language

I have following matrix defined in the start of a problem.

```
f[m_] = Table[f[m, n], {n, 1, 6}];
```

At an intermediate step of the calculations, I get (say)

```
 f[1] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

When I use f[1, 3] for further steps, according to the original definition of f[m_], I expect it to take the value from f[1], which is 3. Though it is not working.

To solve the problem I also tried to define f[m_] as f[m_, n_], but it does not work at all because n is not a free variable. 
I also tried to tell separately that f[m][[n]] ==f[m, n], but it results in a cyclic iteration.

Will be thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: There's a difference between `[ ]` and `[[ ]]` ([`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)). `f[1][[3]]` will return the third element of the list `f[1]`.

Comment: I understand, but if I have defined f[m_] = Table[f[m, n], {n, 1, 6}], f[1, 3] should give same value as f[1][[3]]. Or at least there should be a way to tell mathematica about it !

Comment: You haven't defined `f` as a function of two variables anywhere (at least not in your posted code), so _Mathematica_ doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Perhaps you could give some context. There may be a better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do with this construction.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Problem is that for the next step I cant use f[1][[3]] because I have to use it in a table with two indicies i & j. In the table, I would require to use the element other than i & j th. Which can't be defined as f[1][[x_]]. But if I can make mathematical realize f[1, n]==f[1][[n]], I would be able to use f[1, x_]. Hope i am able to explain it properly.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this will help you understand what is going on.

The Wolfram Language does not make any real distinction between functions and data the way many other programming languages do. It deals with expressions which internally all have the form `headExpression[partExpression...]`, where `...` means a sequence of zero or more items, and it has rules for evaluating such expressions. So whether a form like `f[1]` should be considered a function call or an indexed variable depends only on how it is used.

To see how this applies to your specific problem, let's consider three forms `f[1], f[2], f[3]`. As long they are value-free, WL doesn't treat them as functions or indexed variables—they simply will not evaluate.

Now we will give the forms `f[1], f[2], f[3]` values by binding them to randomly generated lists of integers.

```
SeedRandom[42];
m = 3; n = 6;
Do[f[i] = RandomInteger[42, n], {i, m}]
```

You can put them into a list and it will look like they are treated as indexed variables bound to lists.

```
a0 = {f[1], f[2], f[3]}
```

> `{{27, 16, 32, 32, 12, 3}, {36, 6, 33, 32, 3, 40}, {35, 25, 34, 24, 11, 4}}`

And indeed you can manipulate them as if they were data.

```
a1 = Table[f[i][[j]], {i, m}, {j, n}];
a1 === a0
```

> `True`

and

```
a1[[1, 3]] == f[1][[3]]
```

> `True`

But you can also treat `f` as if it were a function.

```
f /@ Range[m] === a0
```

> `True`

and

```
Array[f, m] === a0
```

> `True`

It might be said that in Wolfram Language you can have your cake and eat it, too.

#### Update

This update attempts to deal with an issue raised by the OP in a comment to this answer.

It would seem that your confusion arises because you do not have sufficient understanding of how expression evaluation works. It is rather complicated and I recommend you read [tutorial/Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html) and [tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html) as start.

However, right now what you need to know is that, when the WL evaluates expressions, it does so by applying transformation rules. It finds the transformation it needs by matching the expression it is trying to transform with patterns stored in the righthand side of the rules in the set of possible transforms. I can not overemphasize that rule selection is done by **pattern matching** because that is the key to your problem.

In your case, all the transformation rules rules for `f` are stored in a list that is called the down-values of `f`.

```
SeedRandom[42];
m = 3; n = 6;
Clear[f]
Do[f[i] = RandomInteger[42, n], {i, m}]
```

Here are the transformation ruled for `f` at this point.

```
DownValues @ f
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[1]] :> {27, 16, 32, 32, 12, 3}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[2]] :> {36, 6, 33, 32, 3, 40}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[3]] :> {35, 25, 34, 24, 11, 4}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[m_, n_]] :> f[m][[n]]}
> ```

Now let's look at what you tried to do.

```
f[i_] = f[i, #] & /@ Range[3]
```

> `{f[i, 1], f[i, 2], f[i, 3]}`

```
f[1, 3]
```

> `f[1, 3]`

```
DownValues @ f
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[1]] :> {27, 16, 32, 32, 12, 3}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[2]] :> {36, 6, 33, 32, 3, 40}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[3]] :> {35, 25, 34, 24, 11, 4}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[i_]] :> {f[i, 1], f[i, 2], f[i, 3]}}
> ```

`f[1, 3]` doesn't evaluate because there is no pattern matching it. To get a match I need to make a transformation rule for the pattern `f[m_, n_]`.

First, I clear out the rule for `f[i_]`.

```
f[i_] =.
```

Now

```
f[m_, n_] := f[m][[n]]
f[1, 3]
```

> `32`

```
DownValues @ f
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[f[1]] :> {27, 16, 32, 32, 12, 3}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[2]] :> {36, 6, 33, 32, 3, 40}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[3]] :> {35, 25, 34, 24, 11, 4}, 
>  HoldPattern[f[m_, n_]] :> f[m][[n]]}
> ```

Comment: To be honest, I could understand only 70% of what are you trying to say, but I am really thankful for such an elaborative response. Unfortunately, even understanding the 70% of what you said, I am not able to figure out how to solve my problem.  Even defining f[m_] = {f[m, 1}, f[m, 2]...} did not help as Table[f[m, n], {n, 1, 6}].. No clue what to try next !!

Comment: @user49535. I have made an update that may resolve the issue you raise in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

When *Mathematica* evaluates something like

```
f[m_] = Table[f[m, n], {n, 1, 6}]
```

it does the following (roughly speaking)

1. it evaluates the `Table` expression, returning in this case a **list** (not a matrix; you can check that `MatrixQ[<expr>]` returns `False`, where `<expr>` is just my shorthand for the output of the `Table` expression above); in particular, it returns `{f[m, 1], f[m, 2], f[m, 3], f[m, 4], f[m, 5], f[m, 6]}`. Now, assuming that **a.** `m` is not assigned any eg numeric value at a previous evaluation (it is the case that `Symbol === Head[m]` evaluates to `True`) *and* **b.** the symbol `f` is similarly not assigned anything during an earlier evaluation, then
2. after evaluating `Table`, *Mathematica* associates the output with the left-hand side of the `=` (see [Set](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)); that means, `f[m_]`, which is a shorthand for `f[Pattern[m, Blank[]]]`, *becomes* a *rule* to transform `f[<whatever>]` into `{f[<whatever>, 1], f[<whatever>, 2], f[<whatever>, 3], f[<whatever>, 4], f[<whatever>, 5], f[<whatever>, 6]}`.

When '*intermediate*' calculations produce something like `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` after evaluating `f[1]` (see question), that can be interpreted in the present context as:
at some point `f[1]` was evaluated and it returned `{f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[1, 3], f[1, 4], f[1, 5], f[1, 6]}` (as should be expected). In order to get the supposed output (see above) it must have been the case, at some point before evaluating `f[1]` that *Mathematica* encountered *another* transformation rule relating `f[1,n_]` with `n` (simply because in this case, `f[m_,n_]=n` is a plausible definition that matches the working assumption of this exposition namely that `{f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[1, 3], f[1, 4], f[1, 5], f[1, 6]}` evaluates to `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`).

If this intermediate step has not occurred, that is, if there is no rule associated with `f[1,n_]` then `f[1]` cannot possibly return anything but `{f[1, 1], f[1, 2], f[1, 3], f[1, 4], f[1, 5], f[1, 6]}` and, similarly, `f[1,3]` cannot evaluate to `3`, as is reported in the question.

To make a long story short, the initial definition (`f[m_]=Table[<whatever>]`) is insufficient input, if the requested output is something similar to `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` above.

There needs to be an *additional* rule that associates `f[m_,n_]` with that desired output.

In closing, I will address the fact that, as indicated in the question, modifying the initial assignment from `f[m_]` to `f[m_,n_]` doesn't produce any desired results.

This should not come as a surprise, since like it's discussed above, `Table` first evaluates into `{f[m,1],...}` and then it is associated with the left-hand side of the `Set` (the  `f[m_]` in the initial case). Changing `f[m_]` into `f[m_,n_]` should not have been expected to produce something useful in the present context. Furthermore, evaluating `f[m_, n_] = Table[f[m, n], {n, 1, 6}];` returns a `$RecursionLimit::reclim2` message.

Finally, [How to Set parts of indexed lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7214/how-to-set-parts-of-indexed-lists/7229#7229) addresses the last issue reported (having trouble with assigning to `f[m][[n]]`) although I doubt this should be a primary concern since it's more complicated than simply providing a rule for `f[m_,n_]` (see above).