# Do "objects" in Mathematica have to be declared?

Tags: programming, design-patterns, object-oriented

A while ago I learned a trick which allows one to imitate object-oriented programming in MMA using `SubValues`:

```
makeObj[identification_Integer] = Obj[identification];
makeObj[5]
(* Obj[5] *)
```

These can have "instance fields":

```
Obj[_]["field"] = 0 (* Default*);
```

And member functions:

```
Obj[id_Integer]["increase"] := (Obj[id]["field"]++;)
Obj[5]["increase"];
Obj[5]["field"]
(* 1 *)
```

However, in order to make an object, I have to identify it in `makeObj`, otherwise my `"field"` values will go to the default every time.  Is there any implementation which allows me to create objects without explicitly naming the pointers to them?

In other words, can I make the compiler internally assign pointers?  In Java, something like:

```
java.util.ArrayList<myObj> a = new java.util.ArrayList<MyObj>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    a.add(new myObj());
a.get(5).doStuff();
```

can be easily done, but how would I do it in Mathematica? (without `JLink`, of course)

If this is not possible, is there some way to have garbage-handling?  Like:

```
Obj["delete", id_] := 
   DeleteCases[SubValues[Obj], HoldPattern[Obj[id][_]] :> _]
```

(Except this doesn't work)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java.  Could you give an example that is *Mathematica* / English only?

Comment: I can't give an example in MMA - that's the problem.  What I would like to know is if I can add an `Obj` to some list, for instance, with a compiler-assigned `id`.

Comment: And *my* problem is I can't understand you. :^)  "compiler-assigned id" means little to me.  Could you describe the behavior of the conceptual construct?  Is `Unique[]` anything useful?

Comment: Yes-`Unique[]` is something that definitely works.  The only issue is that when I did use `Unique[]` in my actual problem, so many new symbols were created and defined that I can't help but imagine there's a solution which has garbage-handling.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/990/5

Comment: @rm-rf I disagree.  `ReplaceAll` is simply an alternative to using `SubValues` for doing the same thing.  The problem is that I still have to explicitly construct every parameter which the rules handle in the example.

Comment: VF1, did you read *all* the answers, not just the first?  Quite a lot is covered in those answers and ones they link to.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, no I did not.  Thanks for picking that up.  I think that creating `Temporary` symbols is what I want, if that is possible.

Comment: `Module` creates symbols with attribute `Temporary`, and they can persist outside of `Module`, so this may be what you need.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That was a great idea, but unfortunately it didn't work: `Module[{x = 1}, makeObj[x]; Obj[x]["increase"]; Obj[x]["field"]]` still adds `HoldPattern[Obj[1]["field"]] :> 1` to the `SubValues` of `Obj`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know a way with subvalues, but you can use `Module` to create objects without explicit identifier in `makeObj`:

```
makeObj[] := Module[{field = 0},
               Switch[#,
                 "increase", field++; #0,
                 "field", field]&]
```

(Note that I slightly changed your "increase" function to return `#0`, that is, "self", so I can chain calls for illustrative purposes)

Now you can create anonymous objects:

```
makeObj[]["increase"]["field"]
(*
==> 1
*)
```

To see that different calls to `makeObj` create independent objects, you can try the following:

```
foo = makeObj[];
bar = makeObj[];
foo["field"]
(*
==> 0
*)
bar["field"]
(*
==> 0
*)
foo["increase"]["increase"];
foo["field"]
(*
==> 2
*)
bar["field"]
(*
==> 0
*)
```

Since I've noticed that figuring out how to allow method call arguments is not trivial, here's a version which allows to set `field` with an optional second argument to the `"field"` method call (and without returning self from `"increase"`):

```
makeObj[] := Module[{field = 0},
               Switch[#,
                 "increase",
                   field++;,
                 "field",
                   Module[{args = Hold[##]},
                     If[Length@args > 1,
                       field = args[[2]],
                       field]]]&]
```

This e.g. allows

```
foo = makeObj[];
foo["field"]
(*
==> 0
*)
foo["field", 4]
(*
==> 4
*)
foo["field"]
(*
==> 4
*)
```

Also note that to have the variables garbgage-collected, you have to make sure that there are no references to it; especially a colon at the end will not prevent storing in `Out`. For example see the following session:

```
In[2]:= ?Global`*
args    field   makeObj

In[3]:= foo = makeObj[];

In[4]:= ?Global`*
args     args$    field    field$81 foo      makeObj

In[5]:= foo=.

In[6]:= ?Global`*
args     args$    field    field$81 foo      makeObj

In[7]:= Do[bar = makeObj[]]

In[8]:= ?Global`*
args     args$    bar      field    field$81 field$82 foo      makeObj

In[9]:= bar=.

In[10]:= ?Global`*
args     args$    bar      field    field$81 foo      makeObj
```

For `In[2]` you see the symbols generated by the definition of `makeObj` (which I omitted, because it's the same as above). Then I define `foo` using a semicolon at the end; while this prevents printing, it still assigns the generated object to `Out[3]` in addition to `foo`. Therefore the field (`field$81`) is not removed when `foo` is cleared in `In[5]`. On the other hand, the `Do` in `In[7]` causes `Out[7]` to be set to `Null`, so the object is only referenced by `bar`. Therefore the corresponding field (`field$82`) disappears when clearing `bar` in `In[9]`.

Comment: Really interesting.  One question: Why do you need `makeObj[]`?  Shouldn't just `makeObj := ....` work?

Comment: @VF1: That's because every execution gives a different object, and there I prefer the function call syntax. Also, it allows you to more easily pass it around without executing it (e.g. if you have a function which takes an object constructor as argument). And finally, you might want to add arguments (e.g. an optional starting value for `field`), which isn't possible without the function call syntax.