# Experiment with TagSetDelayed involving Part

Tags: list-manipulation, symbols, upvalues, object-oriented

Reading [Associating Definitions With Different Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html), I was intrigued by this:

> You can think of upvalues as a way to implement certain aspects of object-oriented programming. A symbol like `quat` represents a particular type of object. Then the various upvalues for `quat` specify "methods" that define how `quat` objects should behave under certain operations, or on receipt of certain "messages".

To play with this idea, I attempted to implement a variation on `List` called `ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap`: like `List`, but any attempts to *get* an index beyond its length return `Null`; and any attempts to *set* an index beyond its length automatically fill intermediate indices with `Null`. I started,

```
ClearAll[ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap, foo, bar];
SetAttributes[ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap, HoldAll];
ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap /: 
  Part[ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap[expr_], i_] := (
   If[Length@expr < i, expr = PadRight[expr, i, Null]];
   return = expr[[i]];
   expr = ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap@expr;
   return
   );
foo = {100, 200, 300};
bar = ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap@foo;
Print@bar;
Print@bar[[2]];
Print@bar[[5]];

(* ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap[foo] *)
(* 200 *)
(* Null *)
```

This is however, of course, wrong, because I'm mistakenly modifying `foo` instead of `bar` and creating nonsense recursion, *i.e.*

```
foo = ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap[foo];
```

So, the first thing I'm stuck on is, **How can I access the *symbol* passed into `Part`?** Scanning through all Mathematica's available operators, I came across [Pattern (:)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html), which seemed like exactly what I needed, and applied it like so:

```
ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap /: 
  Part[symbol : ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap[expr_], i_] := (
   Print@symbol;

(* ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap[foo] *)
```

But wait, instead of `bar`, I got back `bar`'s OwnValue. Why? Ah, because `Part` evaluates its first argument:

```
Attributes[Part]

(* {NHoldRest, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

So, what's next? Do I find some way to set `HoldFirst` on `Part` only when applying to a `ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap`? (If that's even possible.) Instead, is there a more obvious, idiomatic way to go about this all?

<sup>I have other questions in mind, *e.g. "How do I set a separate UpValue for `Set` given that attempting to `TagSet` `Part[Set[...]]` would push `ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap` a level too deep?"*. However, I end my question here for now, since it's where I'm stuck, and I'll probably need to edit this question a few times as I receive help and make progress.</sup>

Comment: Even if you got the `HoldFirst` working somehow, what would you do for a `ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap` that is not bound to any variable, like one that is returned by a function?

Comment: One way to get around the stateless expressions and value semantics of _Mathematica_ is by relying on function definitions to relate to individual objects. In [my question here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13360/do-objects-in-mathematica-have-to-be-declared), you can create an object which has a `SubValue` or `DownValue` that points to the actual list/data. Then your `TagSet` would copy the "function" - really, the object - by value, and it could alter the down/subvalue accordingly.

Comment: Also, by the time the `UpValue` from the integer map evaluates, `bar` would have already been expanded into its `OwnValue`. All information regarding the symbol would have been lost. I don't think `TagSet` is the solution here, unless the value the equivalent of some kind of pointer to its data as I described above.

Comment: @VF1 - Sorry for the late response; I was AFK. In answer to your first comment, if I understand you correctly: if not bound to any variable, I'd want whatever happens when you try to do, for example, `ConstantArray[0, 10][[2]] = 7`—I'd expect an error, _e.g._ "[...] is not a symbol."

Comment: In any event, see my answer (and the two links I provided) regarding the read part of this question. Regarding the writing - the part-set - that will not be possible, at least using the built-in set, for reasons I have mentioned.

Comment: @VF1 - Got it, thanks—trying out your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you need this functionality. If you *really* need `Part` to write to your object, then again, I suggest you use one of the ways of simulating OOP in MMA (see my linked question in comments). You ask if instead there is a simpler, more obvious approach.

I think that all you really need is the following:

```
ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap /: 
 Part[ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap[expr_], i_] /; 
  Length@expr < i := Null
ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap /: 
 Part[ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap[expr_], i_] := expr[[i]]
map = ContiguousOrderedIntegerMap@{1, 2, 3};
map[[1]]
(* 1 *)
map[[4]] // ToString
(* Null *)
```

There's no need to resize your list when you attempt to read out of range - the results will be the same either way.

When *setting*, however, I can see why one might want to pad your list. However, with setting this problem will not appear since when you set you are guaranteeing that the lhs is a symbol that a value can be bound to. As [described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19897/how-to-achieve-setpart-like-behaviour-in-custom-set-function), you will have to use a custom set function in order to have part-setting like `list[[4]]=4`. However, you can set this custom function's attributes to be `HoldFirst` and avoid the previous issue.

Comment: I'm a little confused that you seem to believe it's not "_really_" necessary for `Part` to write to my object—I'm trying to inherit `Part`'s normal behavior, and normally when you do `a = {1, 2, 3}; a[[2]] = 7; a`, you indeed get `{1, 7, 3}`—so my question is, how do I preserve that behavior? (I'm now testing your answer—thank you!)

Comment: @acheong87 For reading purposes only (that is, using `Part` to access elements of the list without `Set`) you don't need to expand your list, as I mentioned, unless you had some reason to "_really_" need to (which I did not see). However, for making a part-set, which is a very specific built-in construct that applies only to lists and expressions, you cannot define behavior relying only on `UpValues` of `Set`, since the expression of the symbol is nested too deep. Instead you have to rely on your own `MySet` or do what I posted.

Comment: Oh! So it was I who misunderstood you; sorry. That makes complete sense, and it's funny because one of my approaches before even posting this question was creating a `PartSet` function. Thanks, I think this will work!

Comment: @acheong87 No problem. Alternatively, there may be a solution that involves holding your data directly in your function `MyList[a,b,c]`. Then the default part-set _will_ replace accordingly since it will work on expressions; however, I don't see an immediate way of getting this approach to allow for resizing.