# What workarounds are there to TagSetDelayed::tagpos?

Tags: argument-patterns, upvalues

My program creates an object based on an `Association`, with a custom head:

```
g = Gate[<| "key1" -> val1 |>]
```

I have given it an UpValue for `Lookup` to behave nicely with it:

```
Lookup[Gate[assoc_], a___] ^:= Lookup[assoc, a]
```

I would like to be able to use the `Lookup` list syntax to return `{val1, val2}` in both the following lines:

```
Lookup[{ <| "key1" -> val1 |>, <| "key1" -> val2 |> }, "key1"]
Lookup[{Gate[ <| "key1" -> val1 |> ], Gate[ <| "key1" -> val2 |> ]}, "key1"]
```

The obvious thing to try is the following:

```
Gate /: Lookup[{a___, Gate[b_], c___}, d___] := Join[Lookup[{a}, d], {Lookup[b, d]}, Lookup[{c}, d]]
```

I get the `TagSetDelayed::tagpos` error, of course, because I'm trying to assign `Gate` a value from the second level of the expression `Lookup[List[Gate[]]]`. (Ignore for now the fact that `Lookup[{}, key]` returns a `Missing` expression rather than `{}`, and so even if `TagSetDelayed` were clever enough, the assignment above would still fail to do what I wanted. I can deal with that afterwards.)

The "other question in mind" question from [this StackExchange question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41448/experiment-with-tagsetdelayed-involving-part) is basically my question, but I don't think it's answered there.

Is there a workaround that doesn't require me to replace `Lookup` with a special `GateLookup` function I define myself?

More generally, are there any workarounds to `TagSetDelayed::tagpos` which don't involve creating helper functions and going full object-oriented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any good workaround (if you insist on using the same syntax) - the depth-1 limitation for `UpValue` search is pretty restrictive.

You may try something like this:

```
ClearAll[Gate];
Gate /: {a___, Gate[b_], c___} := 
  {a, b, c} /; MatchQ[Stack[_][[-5]], HoldForm[Lookup[_List, _]]]
```

but I can't say how robust this is, and also this would induce additional overhead.

That said, most such issues are syntactic in nature, and often the better way out would've been to give up the standard syntax (`Lookup` etc), but instead define your own data type with all required methods, where you can impose the names and syntax you like.